# Stripping off extra spaces from a string

Tags: code-golf, string

You are given a string. Output the string with one space per words.

## Challenge

Input will be a string (not `null` or empty), surrounded with quotes(`"`) sent via the `stdin`. Remove leading and trailing spaces from it. Also, if there are more than one space between two words (or symbols or whatever), trim it to just one space. Output the modified string with the quotes.

## Rules

- The string will not be longer than 100 characters and will only contain ASCII characters in range (space) to `~`(tilde) (character codes 0x20 to 0x7E, inclusive) except `"`,i.e, the string will not contain quotes(`"`) and other characters outside the range specified above. See [ASCII table](http://c10.ilbe.com/files/attach/new/20150514/377678/1372975772/5819899987/f146bf39e73cde248d508e5e1b534865.gif) for reference.
- You must take input from the `stdin`( or closest alternative ).
- The output must contain quotes(`"`).
- You can write a full program, or a function which takes input (from `stdin`), and outputs the final string

## Test Cases

```
"this  is  a    string   "         --> "this is a string"

"  blah blah    blah "             --> "blah blah blah"

"abcdefg"                          --> "abcdefg"

"           "                      --> ""

"12 34  ~5 6   (7, 8) - 9 -  "     --> "12 34 ~5 6 (7, 8) - 9 -"
```

## Scoring

This is code golf, so the shortest submission (in bytes) wins.

Comment: You say `must take input from stdin`, and later you say `...or a function which takes input, and outputs the final string`. Does this mean the function must take input from `stdin` as well?

Comment: @blutorange , Yes. Edited to clarify it.

Comment: `"   "aa"   "` --> `""aa""` (are quotes valid inside the input string?)

Comment: @edc65 , Good point. The answer to that is no. Edited to clarify it.

Comment: Please see [MickeyT's comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50510/stripping-off-extra-spaces-from-a-string/50524?noredirect=1#comment119390_50524) on my answer. Is what he proposes valid? In R, returned results are implicitly printed, but in my answer I've explicitly printed to stdout.

Comment: @AlexA. , The output needs to be seen in the stdout. It doesn't matter if it is implicitly or explicitly printed.

Comment: Some answers are processing string including the double quotes: `"   this  "`, others process a once double quoted string which reaches the code with the double quotes already stripped off: `   this   `. This way the answers and the languages'/authors' efficiencies are not really comparable. @CoolGuy, could you firmly clarify the requirement on this?

Comment: @manatwork , I don't know. Do many answers take advantage of it? If so, I think it is better to leave both ways permitted.

Comment: @CoolGuy, yeah, now that we already have 20 answers, is indeed a bit late to impose a restriction. Though in my opinion this way the challenge is ruined. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## CJam, 7 bytes

```
q~S%S*p
```

**Code Explanation**

CJam has reserved all capital letters as inbuilt variables. So `S` has a value of a space here.

```
q~          e# Read the input (using q) and evaluate (~) to get the string
  S%        e# Split on running lengths (%) of space
    S*      e# Join (*) the splitted parts by single space
      p     e# Print the stringified form (p) of the string.
```

This removes the trailing and leading spaces as well

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7ES%25S*p&input=%22this%20%20is%20%20a%20%20%20%20string%20%20%20%22)

Answer (score 10):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////): 18 characters

```
/  / //" /"// "/"/
```

Sample run:

(Using [faubiguy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29990/faubiguy)'s interpreter from his [Perl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37105) for [Interpret /// (pronounced 'slashes')](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37014/interpret-pronounced-slashes).)

```
bash-4.3$ ( echo -n '/  / //" /"// "/"/'; echo '"   foo  *  bar   "'; ) | slashes.pl
"foo * bar"
```

Comment: [Haven't I seen this program somewhere before?](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/098/3/4/34411c23adbbeb15e92c33eea14bf7fd-d3di79q.jpg)

Comment: Technically you're not taking input though. ;) There's [this language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Itflabtijtslwi) but reading input is still quite a pain I think.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 22

(20 bytes of code, plus 2 command line switches)

```
s/ +/ /g;s/" | "/"/g
```

Needs to be run with the `-np` switch so that `$_` is automatically filled via stdin and printed to stdout. I'm going to assume this adds 2 to the byte count.

Comment: same solution: `sed -E 's/ +/ /g;s/" | "/"/g'`

Comment: The same thing is 12 bytes in [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina). :)

Comment: `-p` implies `-n`, so you only have to take a +1 penalty here (assuming you don't just switch to a different language, like the other commenters suggest).

Answer (score 5):

## Bash, <s>36</s> 32 bytes

As a function, a program, or just in a pipe:

```
xargs|xargs|xargs -i echo '"{}"'
```

### Explanation

The first `xargs` strips the quotation marks.

The second `xargs` trims the left side and replaces multiple adjacent spaces in the middle of the string with one space by taking each "word" and separating each with a space.

The `xargs -i echo '"{}"'` trims the right side and rewraps the resulting string in double quotes.

Comment: Wow! That is tricky. Unfortunately not handles test case 4, but still impressing.

Comment: Yeah, [this code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50510/stripping-off-extra-spaces-from-a-string/50527#comment119350_50514) meets the fourth test case and is shorter.

Comment: Can you do something like this? `x=xargs;$x|$x|$x -i echo '"{}"'`

Comment: @Cyoce: You could indeed do that to save one byte at the cost of losing pipe functionality.  Still not as short as [this solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50510/stripping-off-extra-spaces-from-a-string/50527#comment119350_50514) and still doesn't satisfy the fourth test case.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>31</s> <s>29</s> <s>25</s> 23 Bytes

```
p$*[0].strip.squeeze' '
```

**Code Explanation:**

- **`p`** outputs string within double quotes to `STDOUT` ([There's more to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255362/1533054) though...)
- **`$*`** is an array of `STDIN` inputs, `$*[0]` takes the first one
- **`strip`** removes starting and ending spaces
- **`squeeze ' '`** replaces >1 space characters with a single space

**Test Cases:**

[image]

Comment: You can replace `ARGV` with `$*` saving two bytes. `gsub /\s+/, ' '` can be replaced with `squeeze ' '` for another 4 bytes

Comment: @DickieBoy, thank you for `$*`, I didn't know that. But we can't replace `gsub /\s+/, ' '` with `squeeze` because [they are not the same](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/squeeze).

Comment: What do you mean by "are not the same"? The outputs are the same.

Comment: Well, they aren't. `gsub /\s+/, ' '` replaces >1 'space characters' with a single space character, on the other hand `squeeze` replaces any character >1 with a single one.

Comment: Example: `"yellow  moon".squeeze #=> "yelow mon"`

Comment: `squeeze ' '` will only squeeze spaces. `"yellow moon".squeeze "l" => "yelow moon"`

Comment: Your inputs are wrong, they should _contain_ the surrounding double quotes: `./codegolf.rb '"this  is  a    string   "'`. The quotes as you have them in your sample run are stripped off by the shell, so they never reach Ruby.

Comment: @DickieBoy Oh nice. Thanks!

Comment: @manatwork Are you sure that's what OP meant? I can update code, it _would_ be shorter for that. The challenge says "Input will be a string (not null or empty), surrounded with quotes(") sent via the stdin." and the first rule says "the string will not contain quotes(")"

Comment: Personally I am. And some of other answerers too. But as I see, neither you are alone with your interpretation…  A clarification from the question owner would be welcome. By the way, both the space between `p` and its parameter and `squeeze` and its parameter are unnecessary.

Comment: @manatwork Fuck! I didn't know that was possible! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>17</s> <s>15</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

(thanks to [Ypnypn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16294/ypnypn) and [FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman))

```
pjd-cQdkNN
```

Could probably be golfed more.

If the output can use `'` instead of `"` then I only need 8 bytes:

```
`jd-cQdk
```

Comment: You can use `N` instead of `\"`

Comment: Welcome to Pyth, Tylio. The second program could be shorterned by the use of `d`.

Comment: @isaacg haven't I already used `d` for everything it can be used for?

Comment: @Tyilo I think you made an edit at about the same time I commented. It's all good now.

Comment: You can use `p` to save a few bytes on string concatenation instead of many `+`es. `pjd-cQdkNN`

Comment: Oh, I also happened upon this: `pjdcQ)NN`. It turns out the no-argument version of `c` (hence closing it with a `)` ) automatically strips out excess spaces.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 49 <s>52 58</s>

**Edit** 6 bytes shorter, thanks to @Optimizer

**Edit 2** -3, thanks to @nderscore

Input/output via popup. Using template string to cut 1 byte in string concatenation.

Run snippet to test in Firefox.

```js
alert(`"${prompt().match(/[^ "]+/g).join(" ")}"`)
```

Comment: `alert(\`"${eval(prompt()).match(/\S+/g).join(" ")}"\`)`   - 52

Comment: @Optimizer thx. Note,  that just works after the last clarification about the quotes: eval('"  "  "') would crash.

Comment: When I tested the fourth test case (using chrome), no popup (which shows the result) is seen. Why?

Comment: @CoolGuy maybe because Chrome does not run ES6? I never test ES6 with Chrome. Anyway I tried it now in my Chrome (42.0.2311.152) and works for me.

Comment: -3: `alert(\`"${prompt().match(/[^ "]+/g).join(" ")}"\`)`

Comment: @CoolGuy If you are using the console with chrome make sure to not have the devtools in a separate window. since chrome blocks all prompts that don't come from the currently active tab.

Comment: `" " " "` - is that a valid input?

Comment: @Qwertiy `the string will not contain quotes(")` so, no, it's not

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>31</s> 25 bytes

```
fmap(unwords.words)readLn
```

`words` splits the string into a list of strings with spaces as delimiters and `unwords` joins the list of strings with a single spaces in-between. The quotes `"` are stripped of and put back by Haskell's `read` and `show` (implicitly via the REPL) functions on strings.

Outputting by the function itself is three bytes longer, i.e. 28 bytes:

```
print.unwords.words=<<readLn
```

Edit: @Mauris pointed to the `readLn` function, which saved some bytes.

Comment: I'm getting `Parse error: naked expression at top level` when I tested both the codes [here](http://rextester.com/runcode)

Comment: @CoolGuy: rextester.com expects whole programs, not functions, so try `main=interact$show.unwords.words.read`. There's an online REPL at the frontage of http://haskell.org (requires cookies enabled) where you can try `fmap(unwords.words.read)getLine`.

Comment: `fmap(unwords.words)readLn` and `print.unwords.words=<<readLn` are a bit shorter.

Comment: @Mauris: thanks for pointing to `readLn`.

Answer (score 2):

### Python2, 37

Reduced by 1 byte thanks to @ygramul.

```py
print'"%s"'%' '.join(input().split())
```

Original version:

```py
print'"'+' '.join(input().split())+'"'
```

Test cases:

[image: Test cases screenshot]

Comment: I really wanted to use `print" ".join(raw_input().split())`, but it would have a trailing space inside the last quotation mark if there were spaces after the last word...

Comment: You can shave off an extra byte using % formatting:
    print'"%s"'%' '.join(input().split())

Answer (score 2):

## R, 45 bytes

```r
cat('"',gsub(" +"," ",readline()),'"',sep="")
```

The `readline()` function reads from STDIN, automatically stripping any leading and trailing whitespace. Excess space between words is removed using `gsub()`. Finally, double quotes are prepended and appended and the result is printed to STDOUT.

Examples:

```r
> cat('"',gsub(" +"," ",readline()),'"',sep="")
    This   is     a   string  
"This is a string"

> cat('"',gsub(" +"," ",readline()),'"',sep="")
12 34  ~5 6   (7, 8) - 9 -  
"12 34 ~5 6 (7, 8) - 9 -"
```

Comment: Not sure if it complies totally with the rules, but the cat may not be totally required, just the gsub.  The output from that is `[1] "This is a string"`

Comment: @MickyT: Thanks for the suggestion. My interpretation based on the OP's comment (first on the post) was that it had to be printed to stdout. I'll ask for clarification.

Comment: Ahhh ... didn't see that comment or requirement

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
#õKðý'".ø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f@fBW78MbDu9VV9I7vOP/fwUgMDRSMDZRUKgzVTAD8jTMdRQsNBV0FSyBWAEA)

---

```
#         | Split on spaces.
 õK       | Remove empty Strings.
   ðý     | Join with spaces.
     '".ø | Surround with quotes.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 40 bytes

```java
s->'"'+s.replaceAll(" +"," ").trim()+'"'
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jY7NTsMwEITvfYqRL7WVxhL/oAokHoBeOCIOG8dtXRwnit1KCIVXD1tiuKFieS2vPd/s7OhAZdvZsKvfRuMpRjyRCx8zwIVk@zUZi9WxBZ5T78IGRuZLVEt@H7h4x0TJGawQcI8xlg9zMS@i7m3n2eLReylQiIWAUJrxRqqCFeNyort95ZnOJofW1Wg4Rp708gpSOcN7TLbR7T7pjr@SDzJoI0XausiRuegoi1NC8LTvkH@DQOVpOx3IzUmIKlPb9eYf5r/rpPbsHBeXwOcVrlklbxa4VShxx/UDD7Nh/AI)

```java
s->                        // Method with String as parameter and return-type
  '"'                      //  Return a leading quote
  +s.replaceAll(" +",      //  + Replace all occurrences of multiple spaces in the input
                     " ")  //    with a single space
    .trim()                //    and remove all leading and trailing spaces
  +'"'                     //  + a trailing quote
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 75 bytes

```
a=" ";b=a...;Print[InputString[]~StringReplace~{b~~"\""~~b->"\"",a..->a}]
```

Answer (score 1):

## KDB(Q), 28 bytes

```
" "sv except[;enlist""]" "vs
```

## Explanation

```
                       " "vs    / cut string by space
      except[;enlist""]         / clear empty strings
" "sv                           / join back with space
```

## Test

```
q)" "sv except[;enlist""]" "vs"12 34  ~5 6   (7, 8) - 9 -  "
"12 34 ~5 6 (7, 8) - 9 -"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-Q`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>10</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¸f ¸
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVE&code=uGYguA&input=InRoaXMgIGlzICBhICAgIHN0cmluZyAgICI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 44 bytes

```matlab
@(x)[34 strjoin(regexp(x,'\S+','match')) 34]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0Iz2thEobikKCs/M0@jKDU9taJAo0JHPSZYW11HPTexJDlDXVNTwdgk9n9KZnGBRpqGUklGZrGCAggnKgABUG9mXjqQoaSpyQVTo6CQlJOYASEUoBxk@cSk5JTUtHRULXCALGxoBLRcQaHOVMEMKKNhrqNgoamgq2AJxCB1/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 69 bytes

```
puts [string map {{ "} \" {" } \"} [regsub -all \ + [gets stdin] \ ]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxLDoJAEET3nuKlVxpl4V/PAiyGjwPJSAgzrAhefWyVWEl1p166OpQuxn4MntSHoe0sT9MzTchMJkzCZ8@kQ239WJAY58jYktpaSz5UbZcryPMYhdC0Hj42qJaPyEqgcKb5DZag2BRlVT/s9@AvTfsDxxO8zlwUrK87bhsS7mrkDQ)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 79 bytes

```
puts \"[string trim [regsub -all \ + [string range [gets stdin] 1 end-1] \ ]]\"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtLDoIwGIT3nuJLVxplgW/PAl0UqIWkNoSWrVevv4pOMpPMK7U@53FOkVpVMU1DcIg@qCbr4txQGO@p2fJrJxOcpXJWPjF1Q9CU2NAVpZad1rXKWaV@iPCmQbBcUSsFjTf9V1iMxKZpO3t3n8Ef4so9hyM8T5wlWF92XDcU3ISoFw)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Fixed. unfortunately, at the expense of many bytes. Tks for telling me.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 42 bytes

```
split(" ")|map(select(length>0))|join(" ")
```

Sample Run

```
$ jq -M 'split(" ")|map(select(length>0))|join(" ")' < data
"this is a string"
"blah blah blah"
"abcdefg"
""
"12 34 ~5 6 (7, 8) - 9 -"

$ echo -n 'split(" ")|map(select(length>0))|join(" ")' | wc -c
  42
```

[Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/0wZCH3DObP)

Comment: I caught the output issue earlier (see edit 5) but didn't notice the input issue.  The command is fixed now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 17 bytes

16 bytes of code + 1 for `-p`

```perl
s/ *("| ) */$1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX0FLQ6lGQVNBS1/FUD/9/38lBQWFpJzEDAgB4yj9yy8oyczPK/6vWwAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 40 bytes

```
"`"$(($args-Replace' +'," ").trim())`""
```

Pretty straight forward and not very impressive.

**Explanation**

Take input parameter via (predfined) args-variable, replace all multiple spaces with one, trim leading and trailing spaces using trim()-method, add quotes. Powershell will print strings to console as default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 15 bytes

```sh
<<<\"${(Qz)1}\"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCoMwEEX3fsVtcKHQLOy71J/oPpvEpCYYFBJBsLS/no59XbjD3DOPOdo0WecNgpEaPMC73lyghyyaEZwjX0Cq61qw/F5c57J6CJb0QJCN1kVgsQQpjsH1LTUsY4Dy0n4KvoGwVI02t/a9ACWbTkThhYzW0BNMQ@hWv/u/KFUbbHfAc48DgeK4xqkEx5lM4xc)

Input string contains embedded quotes. Remove the `Q` for **14 bytes** if the input string does not contain embedded quotes, as is done in some of the other answers here.

Parameter expansion flags: `Q` dequotes, then `z` splits into words as the shell does. The words are then implicitly joined by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 8 bytes

```
' '%' '*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X11BXRWItf7/VyjJyCxWUADhRAUgKC4pysxLVwAA)

## Explanation

The logic is quite simple:

```
' '%     # Split on spaces, remove empty results
    ' '* # Join on spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>21</s> <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
" "/(~#:')_" "\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJw9ikkKgDAUQ/c9RfgubEER5+EsgtShVRAX6tqz+0vFQMJLiOkIlMgn6EI1MPZCmFDSvW4X4KzBuu5zOywDCRAw7nr1ga+4XY/TvBjrL79cTTPkBfCUqHiRdYRGIUbLBinxAvV/HD0=)

- `" "\` split (implicit) input on spaces
- `(~#:')_` drop empty strings
- `" "/` join remaining items with spaces

Answer (score 1):

## [Fortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Fortran), 113 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##JYhLDoIwFEXnruLGSd9TSIP/SjBxDV1BQynWVDC1TN16xTA4N@ceN8YUzVD2bpGc24eJpk1dJKVY17EzljaFoDuL@epGrIWUKfoXGfucPimQZpZyzis7wjdVoVTtHWnyV7@t@CYAwa0JAe49paUz191g7fjfnKsd9gfge8QJAJ0LXBgl1Ax@)

```fortran
character(99)S;read(*,'(A)')S;S='"'//trim(adjustl(S))//'"'
do i=1,99;if(S(i:i+1)>'  ')call fput(S(i:i));enddo;end
```

Per [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/strings), "*It should be remembered that Fortran is designed for scientific computing and is probably not a good choice for writing a new word processor.*"

Fortran doesn't have a regex concept either. This just makes [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185992/15940) [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189152/15940) more [interesting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182522/15940)!

In this solution, we trim the string `S`, then iterate over it. Print each character unless it's a space followed by another space.

Previously: <s>[127 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYlNDsIgFIT3nuLFDe9pW1L/kXThGTgBKWAxSA3SrVfHNl3Ml/lm3Jhy0rF@urWU0g866T7bhEKQkslqg7uK4YPYrKpjW8Z5Tv6N2rymbw6oiDif540ZwXdtJYT0DhX6u9@31ETbMABGebBR9joEcJ8prz@RtNF4t9CMC0tpD3A8AfzOcAEAvFZwI6hBzIE/)</s>, <s>[147 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYxNDsIgFIT3nOKlG3hKS@p/bbrwDJyAFLCYCgmi7rw6osbFfJl8yYwNMUXl67P9lZzHSUU1JhNZ16Hso1GaLThlJ6QoiRxoRYVI0V2Z0pf7Lc1MIgpRNNEB3NDy2fjiemeZZO7oli023jQUgGKajCfP6JL5f3KlH8qPZqh8qPA7QGK8drYv1OHDnNsVrDcAry3sAIDtORwQauhK4A0)</s>

Comment: Other ideas failed! `print*` always prints a leading space and a new line. Writing to a new string (avoiding formatting directives) is annoying because gfortran fills it with garbage! Sigh

Comment: ...but `fput` is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 72 bytes

```
import strutils
echo'"',stdin.readAll[1..^2].splitWhitespace.join" ",'"'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcsxCoAwDEDR3VOELC4S0Bt4CgdRqFpoJLalieevgi4f3vAjX7XylVMxUCu3sWjj95BabDu1gyMV745RZO6J1mEhzcI2BTav2e2ezsQRAbt3qBUBNnHhC/zABw)

Ignoring the IO restrictions as many answers do, **58 bytes**:

```
import strutils
echo stdin.readAll.splitWhitespace.join" "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcfNCYAwDAbQu1OEDtAdnMJzbQP9JP2hifNHQS8PXkdzR5tjGamt2yC6ca7jXUGPi1PZRaJOgR0VxjpT5ngN9EDBneiUVD/ozwM)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 82 bytes

```c
char*s=&s+9;main(t){for(gets(s);*s;s++)*s>32|(s[1]>32&&s[2]&&t)&&putchar(*s,--t);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcw5DsIwEEbhq/xKMZqx4yIOW2TBRaIUkQWBgkWZoWK5ugnFk77q5TDlXEo@j7PTPanv0nW83NjkdbrPPB1NWSU5Teq9OD208c3aN8MCIu3jQGRC9Hja/8FO6xBM0qeUqoloV8B3jQ0A3tbYCQK6JVQ/)

Answer (score 1):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 26 bytes

```lua
join(explode(s,"%S+")," ")
```

`explode` groups by non-spaces, and then `join` re-concatenates them.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z8rPzNPI7WiICc/JVWjWEdJNVhbSVNHSUFJ8////0oKCkk5iRkQQgHKUQIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
OðjṘ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

##### Explanation

```python
OðjṘ  # Implicit input
      # Implicit eval to
      # remove the quotes
O     # Split on spaces
 ðj   # Join on spaces
   Ṙ  # Repr (surround
      # by quotes)
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## golfua, 42 bytes

```lua
L=I.r():g('%s*\"%s*','"'):g('%s+',' ')w(L)
```

Simple pattern matching replacement: find any double quotes (`\"`) surrounded by 0 or more spaces (`%s*`) & return the single quote, then replace all 1 or more spaces (`%s+`) with a single space.

A Lua equivalent would be

```lua
Line = io.read()
NoSpaceQuotes = Line:gsub('%s*\"%s*', '"')
NoExtraSpaces = NoSpaceQuotes:gsub('%s+', ' ')
print(NoExtraSpaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 68

As an anonymous function:

```cobra
do
    print'"[(for s in Console.readLine.split where''<s).join(' ')]"'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C 215**

```
-(NSString*)q:(NSString*)s{NSArray*a=[s componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];NSMutableString*m=[NSMutableString new];for(NSString*w in a){if(w.length){[m appendFormat:@"%@ ",w];}}return[m substringToIndex:m.length-1];}
```

Uncompressed version:

```
-(NSString*)q:(NSString*)s{
    NSArray *a=[s componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSMutableString *m=[NSMutableString new];
    for (NSString *w in a) {
        if (w.length) {
            [m appendFormat:@"%@ ",w];
        }
    }
    return[m substringToIndex:m.length-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash ,14 bytes

```
read f;echo $f       # assume f="this  is  a    string   "
```

Comment: What about assuming “   foo   *   bar   ” or anything else with a wildcard character?

Answer (score 0):

## Python2, 28 Bytes

```py
lambda s:" ".join(s.split())
```

---

### Explanation

```py
lambda s
```

Anonymous function which takes as input s.

```py
s.split()
```

Returns a list of the words (which are separated by arbitrary strings of whitespace characters) of the string s.

```py
" ".join(...)
```

Joins list back into a string, with each word separated by a space (" ").

Comment: [This seems to give incorrect results regarding leading and trailing spaces.](https://tio.run/##XYvLCsIwEEX3fsUlmyagBetb8E/cTKxpImkazGzc@OsxPlDqhTvMcM7EG9shNNkcjtlTr1tC2guI@jK4IFOdoncslcrx6gLDyEqwdQl4llCSuJCuLKJSk58FaE/2PfA5xgbpU3s23f/bN2Mwb7BYAvcV1oXJzRRbhRl2pS8zPwA) Note that the challenge state you should take the input with the double-quotes, and also output them with double-quotes. I also had this wrong at first, until I re-read the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## k4, 23 bytes

```
" "/:x@&~~#:'x:" "\:0:0
```

---

```
                    0:0  / read from stdin
             x:" "\:     / split string on spaces and assign to x
        ~~#:'            / boolean true where string len>0, bool false otherwise
     x@&                 / x at indices where true
" "/:                    / join with spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 56 bytes

Wait. The replace only does it *once*? Now I have to use the split-join combo.

```
Fn.new{|x|x.trim().split(" ").where{|i|i!=""}.join(" ")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcwxDoMwDEDRq6SeksU3YOUCrCxR5AqjYJCTNiDC2UPp/L5@UZL29WreHwmmM60XFCpn3euOWXmxDtMWOVsw4LBMpHRWrvzqAC6cV5a/XG04UqYFi3Im@9ww@Bh/OIL349O4dgM)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{|x|                                             } // New anonymous function with the operand x
          x.trim()                                       // Trim out whitespace from both sides of the string
                  .split(" ")                            // Split the string into space-separated chunks
                             .where{|i|i!=""}            // Keep all of those that aren't the null string (due to two consecutive spaces)
                                             .join(" ")  // Join the replaced list together
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
sJ' w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X@xl7pC@f///6OVSjIyixUUQDhRAQiKS4oy89KBDCUdJQWFpJzEDAihAOUAhROTklNS09LBCuAAyDM0UjA2UVCoM1UwAwpomOsoWGgq6CpYArGCUiwA)

Fully ascii!

### Explanation

```
sJ' w
    w split into words
 J'   join with spaces
s     add quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
print("%r"%' '.join(input().split()))
```

Based of user12205's python2 [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50519/100146). I've replaced the %s with a %r so that single quotes are printed around the string automatically.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYhBCsAgDMC@UgSxvXjZk9xgHdIW7Q57fac5JBD7/FY5ImywOKY8Ui5Q6qMsyGKvI9VpnVeJIgCaaocFt2t7rtHPPX4)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 23 bytes

```
[ [ 32 = ] " "compact ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/JCsIwFLz3K4acFLRg6y6exYsX8VQ8POPrgjGNSQTrwV@vcUEHZpjlXV5O0te23W3Xm9Ucji9X1pLd38V885YcTmw1KxSs2ZKq7uSrWjsYy943xlbaYxFFwpeVA14kBDgfliIYEQngoKj8CL4h1HSQR86L98EPIQ0SpEPgMcI4FJ1JD9Mu@pgFQrQZMqQJlthDQMj6bMIj2LcjaDJGNYgdpGKy7RM)

Factor has a combinator called `compact` that does this. From the [documentation](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-compact,sequences.extras.html):

> Generate a new sequence where all runs of elements for which the predicate returns true are replaced by a single instance of *elt*. Runs at the beginning or end of the sequence for which the predicate returns true are removed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 31 bytes

```
/ot!h';$ !Q'w!/
@Mq!"~K'.% >]]\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/v0QxQ91aRUExUL1cUZ/LwbdQUanOW11PVcEuNjbm////SgpOOYkZCkCQlJORCCFBXCUA)

```
Mt!h~;' %Qw]!]' !.$K'"!qo@  Flattened, without flow characters
M                           Read an argument, push it on the stack
 t!h~;                      Remove the leading and trailing quote, write one of them on the tape
      '                     Adds a space on the stack
        %                   Pop the space, pop the argument, split the argument by space and push all of them words on the stack
         Q                  Reverse the stack
          w      .$K        While the stack is not empty
           ]                Go to the end of the tape
            !]              Pop a word from the stack, write to the tape, go to the end of the tape
              ' !           Add a space on the stack
                    '"!     Write a quote on the tape, overwriting the last space
                       q    Concatenate the content of the tape, word and spaces, push the result on the stack
                        o   Pop, output the concatenated result
                         @  Bye
```