# Undress a string

Tags: code-golf, string

[We already now how to strip a string from its spaces.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50510/71426)

However, as proper gentlemen/ladies, we should rather *undress* it.

---

Undressing a string is the same as stripping it, only more delicate. Instead of removing all leading and trailing spaces at once, we remove them *one by one*. We also *alternate* between leading and trailing, so as not to burn steps.

Example, starting with `"     codegolf     "` (five leading and trailing spaces):

```
     codegolf     
    codegolf     
    codegolf    
   codegolf    
   codegolf   
  codegolf   
  codegolf  
 codegolf  
 codegolf 
codegolf 
codegolf
```

---

1. First output the string unchanged. Then, output every step. Begin by removing a *leading* space (if applicable - see rule #2).
2. The input may have a different number of leading and trailing spaces. If you run out of spaces on one side, keep undressing the other until the string is bare.
3. The input may have no leading nor trailing spaces. If that's the case, output it as-is.
4. Use [PPCG's default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/71426). [PPCG Default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/71426) are forbidden.
5. Undefined behaviour on empty input, or input that only contains spaces, is OK.
6. You can assume that the string will only contain characters from the ASCII printable space (`0x20` to `0x7E`).

---

Examples - spaces are replaced by dots `.` for better readability:

```
4 leading spaces, 5 trailing: "....Yes, Sir!....."
....Yes, Sir!.....
...Yes, Sir!.....
...Yes, Sir!....
..Yes, Sir!....
..Yes, Sir!...
.Yes, Sir!...
.Yes, Sir!..
Yes, Sir!..
Yes, Sir!.
Yes, Sir!

6 leading, 3 trailing: "......Let's go golfing..."
......Let's go golfing...
.....Let's go golfing...
.....Let's go golfing..
....Let's go golfing..
....Let's go golfing.
...Let's go golfing.
...Let's go golfing
..Let's go golfing
.Let's go golfing
Let's go golfing

0 leading, 2 trailing: "Hello.."
Hello..
Hello.
Hello

0 leading, 0 trailing: "World"
World

21 leading, 5 trailing: ".....................a....."
.....................a.....
....................a.....
....................a....
...................a....
...................a...
..................a...
..................a..
.................a..
.................a.
................a.
................a
...............a
..............a
.............a
............a
...........a
..........a
.........a
........a
.......a
......a
.....a
....a
...a
..a
.a
a
```

A gentleman/lady is concise, so *the shortest answer in bytes wins*.

Comment: From Sandbox: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13765/71426

Comment: Can we assume that there will be at least one non-space character?

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes

Comment: Can a test string contain new-lines or tabs? (Or more precisely, will the spaces have the lowest decimal value `32` in the strings?)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You only have to handle ASCII characters in the printable space (`0x20` to `0x7E`). The other ones are Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini Ok, so a test case like `"  \ntest  "` or `"  \t test  "` isn't possible (`\n` being a line-feed; `\t` being a tab)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, there will be no test case like this. There will be no things like `"  test\r "` or `" \v test"` either.

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini LOL! Thank you for this idea :)

Comment: do we need to output as 1 line for each step or can we return a list of strings with all the steps?

Comment: Is this a valid test case `".....................a....."`? If so I suggest to add it since some answers seems to fail this kind of test. (dots are for better readability of course)

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista I thought list of string instead of multiline string was implicitely allowed as part of the standard I/O methods. Now: it is explicitely valid.

Comment: Added @Cinaski 's suggested test case. Thanks!

Comment: After testing the answers with Cinaski's test case, I found that some of them *inconsistently* add a trailing empty line. Since they are already there, and upvoted, I will allow this in order to leave these answers valid.

Comment: Somehow the terminology feels backwards to me. In my mind, undressing is something that happens relatively quickly, usually done by yourself, whereas stripping is often about making it take as long as possible to turn it into a proper show.

Answer (score 11):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 26 bytes

```
{m`^ (.+)\z
$&¶$1
 $
 ¶$%`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qkRAXo6ddA8QqXCp6aipaCv@rcxPiFDT0tDVjqrhU1A5tUzHkUlDhUgAyVBP@a7oncKkC5bVrFGA69LiCE1T@64FAcn5Kanp@ThqYwwUiIlOLdRSCM4sUEUJ6ej6pJerFCun5CiC1mXnpIBmP1JycfCAdnl@UkwIA) (Test suite uses periods for clarity. The footer and header convert them to and from spaces for the main code.)

#### Explanation

It would be nice if we could just alternate between dropping a leading and a trailing space and printing the intermediate result each time. The problem is that currently Retina can't print conditionally, so it would even print this intermediate result if there are no leading or no trailing spaces left, generating duplicates. (Retina 1.0 will get an option that only prints the result if the string was changed by the operation, but we're not there yet...)

So instead, we're building up a single string containing all intermediate results and printing that at the end.

```
{m`^ (.+)\z
$&¶$1
```

The `{` wraps both stages of the program in a loop which repeats until the string stops changing (which means there are no leading/trailing spaces left). The stage itself matches a leading space on the final line of the string, and that final line, and then writes back the match, as well as the stuff after the space on a new line (thereby dropping the leading space in the copy).

```
 $
 ¶$%`
```

Removing the trailing space is a bit easier. If we just match the final space, we can access the stuff in front of it (on the same line) with `` $%` `` which is a line-aware variant of the prefix substitution `` $` ``.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>122</s> <s>107</s> <s>103</s> <s>102</s> <s>98</s> <s>95</s> <s>93</s> <s>91</s> <s>90</s> <s>88</s> 87 bytes

```python
s=input()+' '
a=0
while-a*s!=id:
 if a:id=s
 a=~a
 if'!'>s[a]:s=s[1+a:len(s)+a];print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcjBCsIwDADQe78iO2WzCM5jJfuRsUOw3RYobTEd4sVfrwzf8ZVP3XO6t6YkqRy1HywCGqabee8Sw5Uv2pF4Z0BWYCee1ADTl8/ADiedeXFKOo@WXQyp18Hy8igvSRW0NYTTM/uw5bjCH/4A)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>97</s> <s>95</s> <s>93</s> 90 bytes

```python
s=input()
a=p=print
p(s)
while s!=a:
 a=s
 if'!'>s:s=s[1:];p(s)
 if'!'>s[-1]:s=s[:-1];p(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYo7CoAwEAX7PcVaqYVFsIusFxGL4DcgyeJGxNNHjTjV8ObxFVbv6hiFrOMjFCUYYuLdugBcSAnnarcJJSOjAQ0JoJ3zLG9FC0mndN@k2792lepT0Y@kFCO@DH6cFr/N@HED)

Comment: Using `s=input()` instead of a function would take less bytes.

Comment: Refering to `5. Undefined behaviour on empty input, or input that only contains spaces, is OK.`, [98 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9g2M6@gtERDkyvR1oCroCgzr0ShmKs8IzMnVaFY0TbRiksh0baYSyEzTV1B3da2ONog1qoYSBlaxVrDVCMkdQ0hslZABkz6/391BRSgDgA).

Comment: Python 3 [saves a byte.](https://tio.run/##RYo7CoAwEAX7PcVaRQvBYBfZk4hFUKNBSYIbEU8ff4XTDLx54Yyzd3VKTNaFPeYFaKpgobBZF2HJuYBjtusoREackVaAmhjQGoGCiNuqU3xLqq55338p7@1tqpRfTAkfej@Mk18Nflw)

Comment: @JonathanFrech I hadn't seen that; thanks :)

Comment: [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##NctBCsMgEEDRfU8xHQhqMBCzVOYkTReSmkYIKh1L29NbSujb/NUvn7rlNLXGFFN5Vqmcp9GVR0wV@PTa4h6Az@StJ3bhHRaJcRUgiPjS8dXy0f8xJ@wn1clRo7GoB6PRDgZVawJ@lnwL97yvcBBf).

Comment: You can further golf the Python 2 code by replacing `a` with the built-in function `id` to save having to define it at the start. [-2 bytes.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9g2M6@gtERDk6ugKDOvRKGYqzwjMydVoVjRNjPFikshM8W2GEimqSuo29oWRxvEWhUDKUOrWGuYeoSkriFE1grIgEn//6@uAALJ@Smp6fk5aQoQoA4A)

Comment: [91 bytes](https://tio.run/##NctBCoMwEEDRvacYBRmVCI3LyJykdmViHZAkOJG2p4@I9G3@6sdfWoMfchZiH4/UtGPc2SeQ4rPy5kBKYmvYkozu6@aKFwQkkmctLyN3/8vkq26om4dCbVD1WqHpNbY5I1zmYN07bAvc8AQ).

Comment: I came up with a cute `exec`-free 92B variation… I’m not sure if it can be golfed down more: https://tio.run/##LYxBCgIxEATveUXvKYoKrsdIfIIfkD0Ek7gDy0zYiYivjxGtS0PRVHnXWfjUmnri8qybrSkrcYWa10xLgg6eojOg6NUgy4oAYhz3h7FbULaDvegtTE59n93oAvrpKpym8z/VmsWXu8T0kCXjh/0A

Comment: in your python3, `'!'>s[0]` to `'!'>s`

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Thanks :)

Comment: @Lynn Thanks :)
I got it down to 88 bytes using your slicing

Comment: While it's not required, it's common practice (and courtesy ;)) to credit the users that have helped you golf an answer. That would also let me remove all of these comments.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> 15 bytes

```
=v¬ðQi¦=}¤ðQi¨=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/ftuzQmsMbAjMPLbOtPbQEzFph@/@/Ahj4pJaoFyuk5wNRTlpmXjpQCAA)

**Explanation**^

```
=                 # print input
 v                # for each character in input
  ¬ðQi  }         # if the first char in the current string is a space
      ¦=          # remove it and print without popping
         ¤ðQi     # if the last char in the current string is a space
             ¨=   # remove it and print without popping
```

Comment: Dang, I tried something similar but for some reason I was sure head/tail didn't work on strings, and I was about to raise an issue about it on github. Must have read the debug logs wrong. :-)

Comment: @scottinet: I just found a way to get around the end-check :)

Comment: oh... why didn't we think about that before? since we print conditionally there is no need to loop exactly the right number of times, we only need to loop over enough times. I'm borrowing that idea to improve my answer :-)

Comment: @scottinet: Yeah. It's obvious when you think about it, but sometimes it's easy to miss those things :P

Comment: TFW the clunky redundant answer gets the lead...

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 55 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @nwellnhof.*

```perl6
{($_,{$++%2??S/" "$//!!S/^" "//}...*)[^.comb*2].unique}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYKvwv1pDJV6nWkVbW9XI3j5YX0lBSUVfX1ExWD8OyNTXr9XT09PSjI7TS87PTdIyitUrzcssLE2t/W/NpZKmoaQAAsn5Kanp@TlpCkqaermJBRpaemm5JRrqNarFNeqaesWJlZrW/wE)

**Explanation**: `($_,{$++%2??S/" "$//!!S/^" "//}...*)` is a recursive infinite sequence that starts with the original string (`$_`) and the next element is given by the block called on the previous element.

The block itself gets the string in the `$_` variable. The operator `S/(regex)/(string)/` will search for the first occurence of `(regex)` in `$_`, replaces it with `(string)`, and returns the result. If there is no match, it returns the content of `$_` unchanged. We use the ternary operator `?? !!` with the condition `$++%2`, which alternates between `False` and `True` (`$` is a free variable that conserves its contents across calls to the block.)

In the worst case (all spaces on one side and 1 other character), we remove 1 space every 2 steps. So we can be sure that in 2*(length of the string) steps, all spaces will have been removed. We take that many elements from the recursive sequence with `[^.comb*2]` and finally discard duplicates (which occur whenever a space should have been removed but it isn't there) with `.unique`. This returns the list of strings, progressively stripped of spaces.

Comment: `[^.comb*2]` saves 2 bytes. For some reason this works, but `[^2*.comb]` doesn't. No idea why. Using a ternary `?? !!` to select the regex saves another byte.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `[^2*.comb]` and it didn't work, so I just used `[0..2*.comb]`. And thanks for the ternary, I just thought it's too expensive and it didn't occur to me that I replaced it with something even more expensive...

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>89</s> 84 bytes

Recursive version is shorter ;-)

```c
j;f(char*s){puts(s);*s^32||puts(++s);s[j=strlen(s)-1]<33?s[j]=0,f(s):*s^32||f(s+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/LOk0jOSOxSKtYs7qgtKRYo1jTWqs4ztiopgbM1dYGChRHZ9kWlxTlpOYBpXUNY22Mje2BYrG2BjppQBErqAYgW9tQ07r2f25iZp6GJlc1F5cCEACFS4pSSgs0lEC8yNRiHYXgzCJFEEdBSVPTGosiBQWf1BL1YoX0fCDKScvMS8eu1iM1Jycfq0x4flFOCk7T0UAiwi21/wE)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>107</s> <s>102</s> <s>101</s> <s>100</s> 99 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Jonathan Frech using spaces and ~

```c
i,j,k;f(char*s){for(i=~++k,puts(s);i^k;k=s[j=strlen(s)-1]<33?s[j]=0,puts(s):0)*s^32?i=0:puts(++s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xD4IwEIV3fkVlsaUlQdnAhtXBzcEYAwmBgqUVSAsTwb9ei4kxMfhyy/vu3csVfl0UxnDSEBFXsLjnytNoqjoFOX1iLEg/DhpqFPNMxILqW0P1oCRrLfN36SEME8tSGnyCUYA8nYX7hNMgejOM7flsHjlvIXImxwFWFbQ15dhDd3FXpgk4c7VZDHARildCAJzYsNWg7uzIirf1evbIpOxWN5dOyfJv@4/y7y@zeQE)

Comment: I think the question really wants you to remove spaces rather than dots. There is even an advantage to using spaces; you can replace `==46` with `<33` as the space is the smallest printable character and you only have to handle those.

Comment: What does the `++k+` do?

Comment: @JonathanFrech It pre-increments `k` and adds one, which is equivalent to `k = k + 1; i = k + 1;` or `i = k + 2; k = k + 1`.

Comment: Technically `i=k+++2` works too which I would have used because the `+++` looks weird :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yeah, I know what the pre-increment operator does; though I do not get how [the code works without it](https://tio.run/##bYs9C4MwFEV3f0Xq0kQjaN1Mg2uHbh1KKQriV6OpkTydxN@eRqGbj7fcc88tg7YsjRG0oz1rcPkptAdkaZTGgkd0nCfAQJjIe@ZBHl9SwcNkp74PhPYc3h2HSct6sF4QZdc4Ti3LePgfJyFhq/kWYsDEWRwH2Wuw3VTziN0tvWqg6CH0aQvIJYQdSAjd6@kMqFX2ZSOG9ti91VKqw@aptKx2vpof). So really I was asking what role it plays, rather than how it is defined.

Comment: @JonathanFrech That's really odd... I'd have to take a better look at that. Good observation though.

Comment: @JonathanFrech k is true if there are leading spaces and i is true if there are trailing spaces.  I needed them to have different values so I could use ^ in the loop condition.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. If so, I would propose `++k+1` -> `~++k`.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6) 92

@Upvoters: have a look at the other JS answer down below that is **76** bytes long

```
(s,q,l=2,p=0)=>{for(alert(s);l--;p=!p)s[+p&&s.length-p]<'!'&&alert(s=s.slice(!p,-p||q,l=2))}
```

A loop looking for a space at front or at end. If found, remove space and output string. If no space found 2 times, stop.

```js
F=
(s,q,l=2,p=0)=>{for(alert(s);l--;p=!p)s[+p&&s.length-p]<'!'&&alert(s=s.slice(!p,-p||q,l=2))}

// some trick to show dots instead of spaces, for test
alert=x=>console.log(x
  .replace(/^ +/g,z=>'.'.repeat(z.length))
  .replace(/ +$/g,z=>'.'.repeat(z.length))
)

function go() {F(I.value.replace(/\./g,' '))}

go()
```

```html
<input ID=I value='....yes Sir!....'> (use dot instead of space)
<button onclick='go()'>Go</button>
```

Comment: You could save a byte by checking for space with `<'!'`. To make your snippet still work you can `replace` periods with spaces before passing to your function.

Comment: @JustinMariner ok now, because OP stated no char expected less than ' '. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

## Perl 5, 32 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes due to [@Abigail](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/351789?noredirect=1).*

```perl
1while s/^ /!say/e+s/ $/!say/e
```

Requires `-pl` counted as 2, invoked with `-E`.

**Sample Usage**

```perl
$ echo '   test   ' | perl -plE'1while s/^ /!say/e+s/ $/!say/e'
   test   
  test   
  test  
 test  
 test 
test 
test
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfkFqUo6BbkOOq/t@wPCMzJ1WhWD9OQV@xOLFSP1W7WF9BBcr@r/5fAQgiU4t1FIIzixRBHC4FMPBJLVEvVkjPB6KctMy8dJCMR2pOTj6QDs8vykmBqkMDiWASAA)

Comment: Doesn't work correctly for strings without trailing spaces.

Comment: `print;s/^ //&&print,s/ $//&&print while/^ | $/` works with `-n` flag, also `-l` is not needed

Comment: @nwellnhof fixed.

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>192</s> <s>183</s> <s>182</s> <s>181</s> <s>179</s> 178 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen</sup>

```cs
n=>{var o=n+"\n";for(var e=1;n.Trim()!=n;){if(1>(e^=1))if(n[0]<33)n=n.Remove(0,1);else continue;else if(n.TrimEnd()!=n)n=n.Remove(n.Length-1);else continue;o+=n+"\n";};return o;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY89a8MwEIZ3/4qrJ4kkJiajIi@l7ZJQaAsd0gSMfLYF9gkk2TQY/3ZXcSgEOjS33NfzHvcqt1LG4qSa3Dn4jobI@dxrBb3RBexzTcCct5qqwxFyWzkeEAjxfnYe2@S5I7W9Aku45gxKkBPJbOhzC0bSIv6iWJTGsssAZSoo@bC6ZfxBkuCDLlmaMTzJlPNQ02F93G42nCQlb9iaHtl6mXKBjUNQhrymDq/dhZ5PPVExX7sVUbJDqny9@qM1i9@nRmHRd5bAiHESt8YeDTnTYPJptcedJmQli8P6xTRlMBmqmPP/Fa81uFr7e/H9OXxZBGMOGkPVXRqYY0bHaJx@AA)

Comment: Some things to golf: `var e=1;while(n.Trim()!=n)` -> `for(var e=1;n.Trim()!=n;)`; `if(n[0]==' ')` -> `if(n[0]<33)`

Comment: I've thought about second one, but what if the test string contains newlines?

Comment: Ok, `<33` is possible due to OP's newly added rule: "_You can assume that the string will only contain characters from the ASCII printable space (`0x20` to `0x7E`)._"

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>150</s> <s>146</s> <s>145</s> 137 bytes

```java
s->{String r=s;for(int f=0;s!=s.trim();f^=1)r+="\n"+(s=f+s.charAt(0)<33|!s.endsWith(" ")?s.substring(1):s.replaceAll(" $",""));return r;}
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@Nevay* changing `(f<1&s.charAt(0)<33)` to `f+s.charAt(0)<33`.
-1 byte by using the `!s.trim().equals(s)` trick from [*@someone*'s C# .NET answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143380/52210) instead of `s.matches(" .*|.* ")`.
-8 bytes thanks to *@Nevay* again by changing `!s.trim().equals(s)` to `s!=s.trim()`, because [`String#trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) will return "*A copy of this string with leading and trailing white space removed, or **this string if it has no leading or trailing white space***", thus the reference stays the same and `!=` can be used to check if they are the same reference, instead of `.equals` to check the same value.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here](https://tio.run/##rZBNSwMxEIbv/RXTIJjQNrR4c43SmwftpUIRPyDNZtvUNFky2YLU/e1rtiwiQk/rHEImM/PkfWcnD3LiS@12@UejrESER2nccQBgXNShkErDok0BljEYtwFFuwuyLL3Xg3RglNEoWIADAQ1Obo9dTxCYFT7QBINCTDMcCuSptKcsK97FjIWRIK@OjCiKYoRcbWWYRzplN1dXX0Pk2uW4MnFLCRB2hxyrNZ7IdMaukQdd2qRwbm1quCBjQhjLgo5VcBCyuslacWW1tklcp/HgTQ775LGz8fIGknUGPzHqPfdV5GUqReuo4yqR21A@1xtvi1PSfnNu5HzlB/ascQxLE4b/AQN40PESYeOh1dduvRfzXlvre6p60hh7AFY@2Lz3Wv6E/L3selA33w) (or try a more visual version [here](https://tio.run/##rZBNa8MwDIbv/RWqM1jcD9My2GFZNnrbYeulgzL2Aa7jtO5cO1hOYbT57ZlTwhiDnjIfjGVJr55XW77nY1tIs80@a6E5IjxxZQ49AGW8dDkXEuZNCLDwTpk1iLh9IE3Cf9ULF3rulYA5GEihxvHdoa1xKSa5dXEQgzydJMh23IuNxJhEbHBkg4jQJP9Ip9QNU/JmyDDGNB8iExvuZj6e0Nur62MfmTQZLpXfhD5C75FhucLTiHhKb5A5WeiAOtM6FFyQESGUJk760hlwSVUnDWVRrnSgbGH3VmWwC2ZbP6/vwGnr9Au93DFbelaElNcmNkwE5eYIm8m11fkpaMacazmf@RF7kTiChXL9/xCLokfpLxHWFhq@YKmb5oPU2nakepboOwgsrdNZ57X8Ofz3sqteVX8D) with `#` instead of spaces).

```java
s->{                               // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  String r=s;                      //  Result-String (starting at the input)
  for(int f=0;                     //  Flag-integer (starting at 0)
      s!=s.trim();                 //  Loop as long as `s` contains leading/trailing spaces
      f^=1)                        //    And XOR(1) `f` after every iteration (0->1; 1->0)
    r+="\n"                        //   Append the result with a new-line
       +(                          //    Followed by:
         s=f+                      //     If `f` is 0,
             s.charAt(0)<33        //     and `s` starts with a space
           |!s.endsWith(" ")?      //     Or doesn't end with a space
            s.substring(1)         //      Remove the first leading space
           :                       //     Else:
            s.replaceAll(" $",""));//      Remove the last trailing space
                                   //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;                        //  Return the result-String
}                                  // End of method
```

Comment: You can use `s=f+s.charAt(0)<33` instead of `(f<1&s.charAt(0)<33)` (-4 bytes).

Comment: You can use `s!=s.trim()` instead of `!s.trim().equals(s);` (-8 bytes).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
Ḋ=⁶Ḣ$¡UµÐĿ¹Ṛƭ€QY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hji7bR43bHu5YpHJoYeihrYcnHNl/aOfDnbOOrX3UtCYw8v///wpgkAFUn69Qnl@UkwLkAQA)

-2 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer
-1 byte thanks to miles

## Explanation

```
Ḋ=⁶Ḣ$¡UµÐĿ¹Ṛƭ€QY  Main link
       µÐĿ        While the results are unique (collecting intermediate results), apply the last link (`µ` creates a new monadic link):
Ḋ=⁶Ḣ$¡            Remove a space from the beginning if there is one
 =⁶Ḣ$             If the first character is a space, then 1, else 0
 =                Compare each character to
  ⁶               ' '
   Ḣ              Get the first comparison
Ḋ                 Then Dequeue the string (s -> s[1:])
    ¡             That many times
     U            And reverse the string (the next time this is called, it will remove spaces from the end instead)
             €    For each string
            ƭ     Alternate between two commands:
          ¹       Identity (do nothing), and
           Ṛ      Reverse
          ¹Ṛƭ€    Correct all strings that are reversed to remove the trailing space
              Q   Remove duplicates (where there was no space to remove)
               Y  Join on newlines
```

Comment: `ḣ1Ḣ=⁶` -> `=⁶Ḣ`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks, edit coming.

Comment: Cool idea with the alternating commands of reverse/identity!

Comment: @Emigna Thanks! :D I mostly just wanted an excuse to use the new quick... heh :P

Comment: `ƭ` only needs a nilad if the chain is longer than two. `¹Ṛƭ` works fine here.

Comment: @miles Oh cool! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```
i,l;f(char*s){for(i=puts(s);i;i=(s[l=strlen(s)-1]*=s[l]>32)?i:puts(s))i=*s<33&&puts(++s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4/D4IwEMV3PkVlwJY/g7JZq6uDm4MxhoEUipfUlrRlInz2WoyJicGXW97v3r0cLzrOvYdcUoH5ozapJaPQBgPrB2exJRQoMGzvkllnZKsCKjZVygKpDuWWHGH3SRJgqd2XZZK8QZaF48mDcuhZg8IkGiMUJHAoaoYex7O7tTZHFzCr2aCYELoQQujcurVFnQ4jBahuOXtqpdSLm6s2svnb/qP6@8vkXw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>161 147</s> 146 bytes

```java
x->{for(int l=0,r=x.length(),k=-1,u,v;((u=32-x.charAt(l)>>k)*(v=32-x.charAt(r-1)>>-1))<1;x+="\n"+x.substring(l-=k&~u|v,r+=(k=~k)&~v|u));return x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBNTwIxEIbv/oqRA9vKbiN6XErizYPigRhj1ENZylK2tJt2ulmi8NexfKghIU6aJvPOR9@nC9GIzNbSLKbVtg4TrQootPAeHoUy8HlxATE8CoyFmTJCwyKOsIBKs1kwBSpr2LMRbvVUSyfQusEYnTLlEEbAt202/JxZR5RB0Pw6dbxlWpoS54SmFc/6aUibnJDAb2@ylhVz4e6QaDocVvSKNCeqy/pRjxcd9PO2xzvvptNrmQ8Tv3@R6IxX3U34alLX46Tim4p2N81XoDR3EoMz0Obr7Q4oP3AdgY94jVVTWEZscgA9cLx9gHClp/Ev4BgoPZIOi/EqfQpj5S53CevQ/EwPYw8SEw@ljUfH1eXZ1nuptT1XeLFOT3/k9dG4U41AeeJ8333wDCd2xyuPcslsQBbnDGpDRkzUtV4Rz5ystSgkSViSQgIJpX8S7CQWpfy/Xb/O1ttv)

-1 byte thanks to *@Kevin Cruijssen*!

```java
x -> {
    /*
     * l: left index (inclusive)
     * r: right index (exclusive)
     * k: side to remove from, -1:=left, 0:=right
     * u: left character   0:=space, <0:=no space (-1 if k is left side)
     * v: right character  0:=space, -1:=no space
     */
    for (int l = 0, r = x.length(), k = -1, u, v;
            ((u = 32 - x.charAt(l) >> k)
           * (v = 32 - x.charAt(r - 1) >> -1)) < 1; // loop while left or right has space(s)
            x += "\n" + x.substring(                // append newline and substring
                    l -= k & ~u | v,                // inc. left  if k is left side
                                                    //               and left has space
                                                    //            or right has no space
                    r += (k = ~k) & ~v | u));       // dec. right if k is right side
                                                    //               and right has space
                                                    //            or left has no space
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Hehe, I saw your deleted answer and was wondering when you were below my 150 bytes and would undelete it. ;)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you can golf a byte by changing `(u=32-x.charAt(l)>>-1)` to `(u=32-x.charAt(l)>>k)`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Won't work, `k` is `0` every second iteration.

Comment: Yes, but the weird part is that the [TIO](https://tinyurl.com/ydgvm3z8) works and gives the correct result for all test cases with this change for `u`. It doesn't when I also change `-1` to `k` for `v`. I'm confused why it works though, since `k` will indeed become `0` after `k=~k`.. :S

Comment: @KevinCruijssen For the `k=0` scenario: If left has spaces left, then `u` has the same value as before (`0`); if left has no spaces left, then `(k=~k)&~v|u` evaluates to `-1|u` (`~0&-1|u`), thus the undefined (negative) value of `u` does not matter (`-1|x==-1`).

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>25</s> 17 bytes

*-8 bytes by borrowing the [no-need-for-an-end-check idea from Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143382/73296)*

```
,v2F¬ðQi¦DNiR},}R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fp8zI7dCawxsCMw8tc/HLDKrVqQ36/18BG0gEkwA)

I'm pretty sure a less straightforward approach can beat that solution easily. For now...

**Explanations:**

```
,v2F¬ðQi¦DNiR},}R           Full Programm
,                           Print the input string
 v                          For each char of the string
                               (we don't really care, we only need to loop
                                enough times to accomplish our task, since
                                we print conditionally we can loop more
                                times than necessary)
  2F...........}            Two times...
    ¬õQi                       Is 1st item a space?
        ¦D                        Remove 1st item + duplicate
          NiR}                    If on the second pass: reverse the list
              ,                   Pop & print with newline
               }               End If
                 R          Reverse the list
```

Comment: I like your approach with the loop :) I've been trying to figure out a way to do everything in one pass without multiple ifs, but I haven't figured it out yet. Also, your explanation seem to have an empty string instead of a space.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the explanation, I forgot to edit the "is empty" part when I golfed my code, using `S` instead of `#` (-1 byte). The loop... well... it saves a whopping 1 byte compared to a straightforward approach. I'm currently looking for a shorter way to detect the end of the task (5 bytes for this is a lot), and I'm also considering a different approach altogether. I do think there is a more clever way to solve this challenge.

Comment: If you try and do everything in one pass (as I'm currently looking into), the best check I have for exiting the loop is 8 bytes...

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```ruby
->s{*x=s;(s=~/^ /&&x<<s=$';s=~/ $/&&x<<s=$`)while s=~/^ | $/;x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664WqvCtthao9i2Tj9OQV9NrcLGpthWRd0aJKCgAhdI0CzPyMxJVYCoqwHKWFfU/i8oLSlWSItWVwCB5PyU1PT8nDQFCFCP/Q8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>145</s> <s>133</s> 111 bytes

*-12 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe, by storing the result of `sub` in a new variable and testing for whether it has changed*

*-22 bytes by returning a vector of strings rather than a string with newlines*

```r
function(s){L=s
while(grepl("^ | $",s)){if((x=sub("^ ","",s))!=s)L=c(L,x)
if((s=sub(" $","",x))!=x)L=c(L,s)}
L}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcsxDoMwDAXQPacIFoMt5Qq@QTYmlg5FSYmEKIqLGoly9jQu/Zu/3881co37Or3Sc0Whw7OY95yWgI8ctgXhZj@2BydER4qIhWW/awsOfm3HQp4n9K6QUSGX0FETRUX5C6HT@LPG9m0Zgzg7pNzpYYHqFw)

Explanation on a partially ungolfed version:

```r
function(s){
  L=s                          # Initialise a vector with the original string
  while(grepl("^ | $",s)){     # While there are leading or trailing spaces...
    if((x=sub("^ ","",s))!=s){ # Check whether we can remove a leading space
      L=c(L,x)                 # If so, add the shortened string to the vector
    }
    if((s=sub(" $","",x))!=x){ # Check whether we can remove a trailing space
      L=c(L,x)                 # If so, add the shortened string to the vector
    }
  }
  L                            # Return the vector
}
```

Comment: can't you use `C(s<-sub(),\n)` instead of a separate print statement? Ah, no, because of `sep=" "`

Comment: @Giuseppe Yes, I think it works out slightly longer to include it all in a single statement because of the need to add `sep=""`. In most challenges the extra trailing space would not matter, but here unfortunately it does!

Comment: [133 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jWLPa2TY5sYTLGcgEEkpcSppc5RmZOaka6UWpBTkaSnEKNQoqSjrFmprVmWkaGhW2xaVJIFElHSWwqKItyAyNCpjuWi6QsmKIMpBOoLIKkLIKkDK4JbW1tf/TgAqAIDK1WEchOLNIEcRRUNL8DwA "R – Try It Online") -- something about your using `sub` just suggested this, IDK why

Comment: @Giuseppe Very elegant!

Comment: Could you just set `L=s` and return a vector of strings?

Comment: @Giuseppe I guess so!

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
u§↑L`G`I¢e₁ȯ↔₁↔
?tI<"!
```

Thanks to Leo for -1 byte.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxDsIwDEX3nuI3c8UBEBIjVGJjYmtUuTSipFXsssPQHYkTsDByh06coxcJIYCH5y/5fdc9H7zvx8c0XDfFqsjHO02X8@s5DbewA5Ol5AuVeoT5RmBNTUcOVW9LMa2dw9GxPRGMNWJ0A@50SbMkVoBYySs0xAyptQ0gsDhj91CpyqIIify/qoxjQVlrp0sh93OQR1LDFETpnYVmGJ55rz6HHXGGrXFp1NQb)

### Explanation

The function `` `G`I `` should really be a built-in...

```
?tI<"!  Helper function: remove initial space.
?  <"!  If less than the string "!",
 t      remove first character,
  I     else return as is.
u§↑L`G`I¢e₁ȯ↔₁↔  Main function.
         e       List containing
          ₁      the helper function
           ȯ↔₁↔  and the composition reverse-helper-reverse.
        ¢        Repeat it cyclically.
    `G`I         Cumulative reduce from left by function application
                 using input string as initial value.
 §↑L             Take first length(input) values.
u                Remove duplicates.
```

Comment: Nice! Indeed we would need more builtins for applying functions cyclically... btw I've found a sligthly shorter way to remove the first space: https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v/TQ8kdtE30S3BM8Dy1KfdTUeGL9o7YpQBpIctmXeNooKf7//19JAQgiU4t1FIIzixRBHAUlAA

Comment: @Leo Thanks! Using `?` seems obvious in hindsight...

Answer (score 3):

### C++, <s>196</s> <s>193</s> <s>189</s> <s>186</s> 183 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech 
-3 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#define D std::cout<<s<<'\n'
#define R ~-s.size()
auto u=[](auto s){D;while(s[0]<33||s[R]<33){if(s[0]<33)s.erase(0,1),D;if(s[R]<33)s.erase(R),D;}};
```

Compilation with MSVC requires the un-activation of SDL checks

Comment: You may be able to replace `==32` with `<33`.

Comment: I am no C++ master, though is `#include<string>` [really necessary](https://tio.run/##RY3BDoJADETvfkWjB3cTMRj0AhtOfAFX9UB2izbBhVDQRFh/HZEEmdN0XtvRVeXdtB6GDVldtAYVldzUmD3i1cZgThYhAW5MGOqybZRipbYXu/3DFPj88XjP9EYhryoIVs@SDLRiOhp/kb0Byy6JXncqUPDZ/231fSo7yudRdrzHOmMU/u4goyRyI0uXdKmYoHPDIyMrZNeKNYxSHhyBq0wjQw@n2XrxD8JaRm74Ag)?

Comment: `if(...){...;D;}` -> `if(...)...,D;`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech What you did there was compiler specific, not guarranted by the standard. VC++ can't find a definition of the << operators without the explicit inclusion of string.

Comment: `#define R ...<33`, `||R){` and `if(R){` -> `#define R ...<33)`, `||R{` and `if(R{`.

Comment: [184 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYzBCoJAEIbvPsVQB3dBw7AuunjyCfZaHWSdakBXabQgtVc3LRKa0/9/38@YuvYvxozjmqwp2hwVVdzcMCuThUyd7CVx1jmeySKkwE0eRaZqG6VYKfdo3UXql88bpicK6dwryqEVn/X3CbDs0vhxpQIFH4KTCsO@54Oeg@zo/IOSN3jLGEXgbaWXxh@j/4ye@TCMZUZWyK4VK5hO@bADrjODDD3sf9FPZgkrGQ/jGw).

Comment: `void` -> `int`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech 1.) C++11 requires whitespace after the macro name. ( and i compile with C++17 norm ) 2.) Sticking 2 includes each other on the same lines cause the second token to be ignored. 3.) Declaring a return value in a function that doesn't return a value is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9936084/6784509)

Comment: Would using C++14 and `auto` instead of `std::string`, and have `u` be called like `u(std::string("  SOMETHING "))` work?

Comment: @Zacharý No, since it's not a lambda. But i can replace it by a lambda and save a few bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>137</s> <s>125</s> <s>121</s> <s>120</s> 124 bytes

```java
s->{int i=1;do System.out.println(s);while(s!=(s=s.substring(s.charAt(0)<33?i:(i=0),s.length()-(s.endsWith(" ")?i^=1:0))));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BasMwEER/RfVJKrVwyC2KEko/IYcQSguqJNvryJLwrlOKybe7Ir10bjO8GWYwN1On7OPgriuMOU3EhpLJmSDIdo6WIEX5rCCSn1pjPbssbyniPPppf6IJYndgmWm2Yn1YCsVAb5RL7PSD5EeZZpK5UBQiR6G@ewie45PmqFHi/IWPCY7S9mZ6Jd6I/XZ7hB0H3YgXlMHHjnou6oL46PAMxVWsEkf41JtdI4rUfVVIhsCyWwLHRgOR/317/zBiydJY6zOV3j/Z5HyXQvswVRm5r78)

Comment: Nice answer! Just as short as [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143387/52210) of 137 bytes, but you can still golf 12 bytes like this: [`s->{for(int i=0;s!=s.trim();)System.out.println(s=s.substring(s.charAt(0)<33?1-i%2:0,s.length()-(s.endsWith(" ")?i++%2:0)));}`](https://tio.run/##JY7RTsMwDEV/JVRCShiNCnsj6ybEJ@wBIcRDSNPOpXGi2J2Eqn17yYbfrn2OdUd7tnVMHsfuZ4WQYmYxlp2eGSbdz@gYIuoHA8g@99Z58bG8RaQ5@Lw7cgYc9iKJVqxU75c@ZllIAW1j6K4lXYAglVHHX2IfdJxZp@LwhJLKmeZvuv2QpN3J5leWjdptt4enGu6fX5pH0pPHgU9S1QXx2NE7lFSJSh1gs7kySilzWQ2xZXDiHKETwQLK/3KfX1YtSVvnfOLiXcfFzg9x6m@hKvZl/QM)

Comment: This currently does not "... output the string unchanged" and fails for input with leading spaces and no trailing spaces.

Comment: Maybe you can use `s->{int i=1;do System.out.println(s);while(s!=(s=s.substring(s.charAt(0)<33?i:(i=0),s.length()-(s.endsWith(" ")?i^=1:0))));}` (124 bytes) (seems to be correct but didn't test much).

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>21</s> 16 bytes

```
tnE:"t@o&)w46-?x
```

This uses dots instead of spaces for greater clarity. For spaces replace `46` by `32`.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyTP1UqpxCFfTbPcxEzXvuL/f3U9bCARTKoDAA)

#### Explanation

```
tn      % Input (implicit). Duplicate and push length, say L
E       % Multiply by 2
:       % Push range [1 2 ... 2*L]
"       % For each k in that array
  t     %   Duplicate the string at the top of the stack
  @     %   Push k
  o     %   Parity: gives 1 or 0
  &)    %   Two-ouput indexing. Pushes the k-th entry of the string and then
        %   the rest of the string. The 1-st output is the first, the 0-th
        %   is the last (indexing is 1-based dand modular)
  w     %   Swap
  46-   %   Subtract 46, which ias ACII for '.'
  ?     %   If non-zero
    x   %     Delete sub-string that was obained by removing that entry
        %   End (implicit)
        % End (implicit)
        % Display stack (implicit)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>176</strike> 170 bytes

```cs
using System;s=>{Action o=()=>Console.WriteLine(s);o();Func<int>l=()=>s.Length-1;while(s!=s.Trim()){if(s[0]<33){s=s.Remove(0,1);o();}if(s[l()]<33){s=s.Remove(l());o();}}}
```

[*Try it online!*](https://tio.run/##bZDLasNADEX3/golm85AYhKy9ANKoXThbppCKCELMx47gvEIRpO0xfjbXT9KwU20Ebr36IEUrxU53V0YbQX7b/a6jgJlcmb4CpqAfe5RwZWwgNccLQj2rkePJ8hdxbJHoI9H5ZFsPHkplJB0nKTNJAMlQibpE1kmo8ODQ68ztFqwjEjI6PliVYzWp2bkOMy0rfx5vY0@z2h6bJFw@O6wFlI2WAo@bk7xbicb7vU3XdNVi81qOw1rR8AIeYP02i/Stl00nl2K5ZBAUaErMuVYLOXM/NC8gj26xT0TINP@gaEiGPqHH86YF20MzZQDOVPcTPkX@d@uNmi7Hw)

This is an alternative to [@someone's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143380/61283), and just outputs the strings directly.

Comment: Your program doesn't output the string unmodified before removing spaces.

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini I corrected that mistake and golfed a few bytes to reduce the byte count anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 76 bytes

```js
f=(s,r,n,l=s.length)=>s[r?--l:0]<"!"?s+`
`+f(s.slice(!r,l),!r):n?s:f(s,!r,1)
```

Outputs as a multiline string.

### Test Cases

Using dots instead of spaces, as most answers are doing.

```js
f=(s,r,n,l=s.length)=>s[r?--l:0]<"!"?s+`
`+f(s.slice(!r,l),!r):n?s:f(s,!r,1)

// converting to and from dots and spaces
let dots=s=>s.replace(/^\.+|\.+$/gm,x=>" ".repeat(x.length));
let spaces=s=>s.replace(/^ +| +$/gm,x=>".".repeat(x.length));

["....Yes, Sir!.....", "......Let's go golfing...", "Hello..", "World", ".....................a....."]
.forEach(test=>O.innerHTML+=spaces( f(dots(test)) ) + "\n\n");
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Sed, 24 bytes

```
p;:s s/ //p;s/ $//p;ts;D
```

[Try It Online !](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v8DaqlihWF9BX7/AGkipgOiSYmuX//8VFEpSi0sUFAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>88</s> 83 bytes

*5 bytes off thanks to [Stewie Griffin!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)*

```matlab
x=[input('') 0];for p=mod(1:sum(x),2)if x(~p+end*p)<33,disp(x=x(2-p:end-p)),end,end
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/wjY6M6@gtERDXV1TwSDWOi2/SKHANjc/RcPQqrg0V6NCU8dIMzNNoUKjrkA7NS9Fq0DTxthYJyWzuECjwrZCw0i3wAoorFugqakDpEH4/38lBRBIzk9JTc/PSQNzlAA)

Comment: Very nice. _"Anyway, see if you can [remove a couple of bytes](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/wjY6M6@gtERDXV1TwSDWOi2/SKHANjc/RcPQqrg0V6NCU8dIMzNNoUKjrkA7NS9Fq0DTxthYJyWzuECjwrZCw0i3wAoorFugqakDpEH4/38lBRBIzk9JTc/PSQNzlAA)"_ :-P

Comment: @StewieGriffin I meant in your answer... :-D Good idea, thanks!

Comment: I might delete mine... It's so uninspired compared to this...

Comment: @StewieGriffin Here's an idea to [remove two bytes](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/2DYzr6C0RENdXdO6PCMzJ1UhMa9So1ijxDbaUCE1LyVW08bYWDMtv0gh27ZEJzNNoVgjxzY3M08jWwcoqwmS1QEKadpGx4IEYPj/fyUFGPBJLVEvVkjPB6KctMy8dKCQEgA). Pity that `min` is needed because of `s` being dynamically shrunk

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code for Linux, 60 bytes

```
e8 1f 00 00 00 31 c0 80 3f 20 75 09 47 4d 74 10
e8 0f 00 00 00 80 7c 2f ff 20 74 05 84 c0 75 e5
c3 4d eb dc 6a 04 58 50 31 db 43 89 f9 89 ea cd
80 58 6a 0a 89 e1 89 da cd 80 58 c3
```

This is a function for Linux x86. It takes as input pointer to the string in `edi` and string length in `ebp`.

Ungolfed, with some infrastructure to test (compile with FASM, run with the string as program argument; look for `undress:` label for actual function code):

```
format ELF executable
segment executable
SYS_WRITE = 4
    jmp     callUndress
; -------------------- the function itself --------------------------------
; Input:
;   edi=string
;   ebp=length
undress:
undressLoopPrint:
    call    print
undressLoop:
    xor     eax, eax    ; flag of having printed anything on this iteration
    cmp     byte [edi], ' '
    jne     startsWithoutSpace
    inc     edi
    dec     ebp
    jz      quit
    call    print
startsWithoutSpace:
    cmp     byte [edi+ebp-1], ' '
    je      endsWithSpace
    test    al, al      ; if print has been called, then we have 0x0a in eax
    jnz     undressLoop
quit:
    ret
endsWithSpace:
    dec     ebp
    jmp     undressLoopPrint
print:
    push    SYS_WRITE
    pop     eax
    push    eax
    xor     ebx, ebx
    inc     ebx ; STDOUT
    mov     ecx, edi
    mov     edx, ebp
    int     0x80
    pop     eax
    push    0x0a    ; will print newline
    mov     ecx, esp
    mov     edx, ebx ; STDOUT=1, which coincides with the length of newline
    int     0x80
    pop     eax
    ret
; --------------------- end undress ---------------------------------------
SYS_EXIT = 1
STDERR = 2
callUndress:
    pop     eax     ; argc
    cmp     eax, 2
    jne     badArgc
    pop     eax     ; argv[0]
    pop     edi
    mov     al, 0
    cld
    mov     ecx, -1
    repne   scasb
    lea     edi, [edi+ecx+1] ; argv[1]
    neg     ecx
    sub     ecx, 2
    mov     ebp, ecx     ; strlen(argv[1])
    call    undress
    xor     ebx, ebx
exit:
    mov     eax, SYS_EXIT
    int     0x80
    ud2
badArgc:
    mov     esi, eax
    mov     eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov     ebx, STDERR
    mov     ecx, badArgcMsg
    mov     edx, badArgcMsgLen
    int     0x80
    mov     ebx, esi
    neg     ebx
    jmp     exit
badArgcMsg:
    db      "Usage: undress YourString",0x0a,0
badArgcMsgLen = $-badArgcMsg
segment readable writable
string:
    db      100 dup(0)
    stringLen = $-string
```

Comment: `sys_write()` makes `eax` non-zero  (specifically `1`, the number of characters written, assuming it's not `-errno`),  So will `print` if you don't `pop eax` at the end.  You could just `xor eax,eax` before the `cmp byte [edi], ' '` and save the `mov al,1`, and maybe some `eax` save/restore.  Although you don't actually save it until after clobbering with `SYS_WRITE`.  Hmm, instead of `0`, you could use `SYS_WRITE` vs. `1`, since `cmp al, imm8` is the same size as `test al,al`.

Comment: Can you put a `'\n'` into the array with `mov byte [ecx + edx], '\n'` instead of doing the 2nd `write()`?  (And decrement the length after printing?)  Might save you a few instructions.

Comment: Actually, `print()` currently leaves `'\n'` in `eax`, which is different from `SYS_WRITE`, so you could still check that.  I thought you were saving/restoring `eax`, but that was just saving bytes copying a constant around.  For long strings, `sys_write()` can leave the high bytes of eax non-zero, so that unfortunately rules out just using `mov al, SYS_WRITE`.

Comment: @PeterCordes actually yes, `mov al, 1` was extraneous. -2 bytes now, thanks.

Comment: A register calling convention would save you the load instructions.  In code-golf, a custom calling convention is normally fair game for asm.  OTOH, if you'd rather golf the standard stack-args calling convention, that's interesting too.

Comment: @PeterCordes I supposed one has to use a standard convention. Will take this into account for the future.

Comment: You're writing in asm, presumably for a caller written in asm.  In asm, every function can have its own calling convention if you want.  I try not to bend the rules too far, so I still always return in eax (or dx:ax for 16-bit addler32).  Using a calling convention similar to an existing one (like MS `_fastcall` but with different regs), or with some dummy args to get the args in the regs you want, seems fine.  Treating more regs as call-clobbered is probably also ok.  Saving/restoring regs is kind of boilerplate and not the interesting part of a machine-code answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes agreed. Here goes the 10 bytes smaller version with custom calling convention.

Comment: If you used `esi` as your 2nd arg, you'd have a 32-bit version of the x86-64 System V calling convention.  Not that it really matters.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 117 bytes

I add an extra space at the start so it will take the space out and show the original without any extra code.

Kinda new to this... would the <?php and the space at the start of the PHP file add 6 extra bytes or do I get that for free?

```php
$s=" $argn";while($r!=$s){$r=$s;if($s[0]==" ")echo($s=substr($s,1))."
";if($s[-1]==" ")echo($s=substr($s,0,-1))."
";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcrBCsIwDAbge5@ilh5WWGXT4yzefAnxMGddB6UpTWUH8dWtKejRQP7khy@6WA7HSCnRCC7HNAcxrG7xtpFpYySqp0x0huXeSDx3F0NMKDs5oG7wccWc6Gt7pbaCia/T/V/YtfpnX6XwOs56D3yF5G/UGG22mHes5r4CFoBPbgyzfUPMCwQs@vQB)

Comment: Using your method 6 bytes can be reduced: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fczBCsIwDAbge5@iljAstLLpcRZvvoR4mFq3QWlKUvHtrS14NpAf/vCRtKRyPKWaT6QtsFMSJpqjGoE2DngEvvRXV8@q6xKtMTfErxvnxs2g9U4JZSqzwx/XG/ujGqj9LUW2WXwIKN9I4VGbqJs9571oeWhARJT3ZYqz/2DKK0Yu9vwF "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: You can omit the PHP's opening tag since you can run it with a command like this: `php -r "echo 1;"` But if you want to use something like `<?=1;` you have to include the tag in bytes count.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 89 bytes

```matlab
s=input('');while any(s([1,end])<33)if s(1)<33,s(1)=[],end,if s(end)<33,s(end)=[],end,end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/2DYzr6C0RENdXdO6PCMzJ1UhMa9So1gj2lAnNS8lVtPG2FgzM02hWMMQxNQB0bbRsSA5HbAwkAGVALFgUkD8/7@SAgz4pJaoFyuk5wNRTlpmXjpQSAkA)

I'll add an explanation later, when I have the time. I might be able to golf off some bytes if I change the approach completely, but I can't see how unfortunately.

The last letters here spell out: "sendsendendend". I wish there was a way to store `end` as a variable and use that, but guess what ...

Comment: Is it valid to output with `s = ...`? (The usual question, I know)

Comment: Anyway, see if you can [remove a couple of bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143462/36398) :-P

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 79 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @JonathanFrech

```python
f=lambda s,i=1:[s]+(s>i*'!'and'!'>s[-1]and f(s[:-1])or'!'>s and f(s[1:],0)or[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYwxT8QwDIXn9le4U9qjRBxjpd52iAGJARZUVSi0ac9SSCInp@N@fXEqVbcgPNjPz9@zv8aTs4/LMrVGfX@NCkKN7b7pQn9XhgPuRCGUHbkfQne/71nDVIauYV05Wn3YzH3T1w/sdn21RLo2eXY5odHwTmfNS4bQAqnLJ1p/jmUlSXujBl0KKWoQICpmJkfgAC0/xCqFMk9oI7gbDYmWK61C0MRHaFtAGSKhL5O/ZnL9M2gf4fj6dCRyxN88Bxb5V6m150nkaUkqX2eRNNfgRj07M22glB861PCGVNwsKV90FAFmB4lFO/9/edbGuG3@Ag)

The test suit replaces `"."` with `" "` before calling the function and replaces `" "` back to `"."` before printing the results for clarity.

Comment: `'!'*i and` -> `i*'!'and`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 28 bytes

```
QW<lrKQ6lQ=hZ?&%Z2qdhQ=tQ=PQ
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=QW%3ClrKQ6lQ%3DhZ%3F%26%25Z2qdhQ%3DtQ%3DPQ&input=%22+++++codegolf+++++%22&test_suite_input=%22+++++codegolf+++++%22%0A%22world%22%0A%22++++Yes%2C+Sir%21+++++%22%0A%22Hello++%22&debug=0)** or **[Verify all test cases!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=QW%3ClrKQ6lQ%3DhZ%3F%26%25Z2qdhQ%3DtQ%3DPQ&input=%22+++++codegolf+++++%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22+++++codegolf+++++%22%0A%22world%22%0A%22++++Yes%2C+Sir%21+++++%22%0A%22Hello++%22&debug=0)**

## Explanation

```
QW<lrKQ6lQ=hZ?&%Z2qdhQ=tQ=PQ   ~ Full program. Q is autoinitialized to input.

Q                              ~ Output the input.
 W<lrKQ6lQ                     ~ Loop while the condition is met.
  <                            ~ Is smaller?
   lrKQ6                       ~ The length of the original input, stripped on both sides.
        lQ                     ~ The length of the current Q.
          =hZ                  ~ Increment a variable Z, initially 0
             ?&%Z2qdhQ         ~ If Z % 2 == 1 and Q[0] == " ", then:
                      =tQ      ~ Make Q equal to Q[1:] and output, else:
                         =PQ   ~ Make Q equal to Q[:-1] and output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>98</s> 94 bytes

Saved 4 bytes using subshell instead of sequences (poor performances)

```
r()(s=$1;[[ $s = $b ]]||([[ $s = $a ]]||echo "$s"
b=$a a=$s;((i=!i))&&r "${s# }"||r "${s% }"))
```

First answer

```
r(){ s=$1;[[ $s = $b ]]||{ [[ $s = $a ]]||echo "$s"
b=$a a=$s;((i=!i))&&r "${s# }"||r "${s% }";};}
```

Note the `!` must be escaped in interactive mode

Answer (score 1):

## C# - yet again, 125 bytes

```cs
while(s.Trim()!=s){if(s[0]==' '){yield return s=s.Substring(1);}if(s.Last()==' '){yield return s=s.Substring(0,s.Length-1);}}
```

Cheers!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDRasIwFH3vV9z5YoIzuOeuexEZgttgDvYw9hDTVANp6nJTNyn9dpdYq3YKO5Byc3vPuTlH4FCg2JWozBLmW3Qyj6PzG5sp8xVHQnNE@IEqiuCAtVUb7iSg406JdnxcaC2FU4VB9iiNtEqw6cSUubR8oeU9OuvFHyAjTQVIj4rV7nultCTI3qzKCb1JkFbKT36MPpOkD31abZXUKVjpSmsAE2TzctEIkTsa12GYzTg6Qv8njG79rDRLtxoGbr2rT97KhfaeDtY2hUrhiStDzt56rAJaL3Gnu3cD5Kb5y6b4XGr9Yif52m0JQgJjn1KhJXuVPPU5S0Ip7Sh0twRkhZVcrIBsuIUClAlJ/mFdZwa0C9@tcnK/sTfswcALDcBXNL5g1VH3Fl2TO72/K9DEHqI9JRU@UVvsEeHFVt/gmGbhHGg8axpZCr8)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 109 bytes

```hs
(b%e)
t=last
b(' ':s)=s
b l=l
e l|t l>' '=l|1>0=init l
(g%h)l=l:t((h%g$g l):[t$(h%g$h l):[[]|h l==l]|g l==l])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@xCsIwEIb3PMWvtDQBBV0L19lBJwcRdUg1TYNnW5qMfXZj1LnHwd3/3bdcq/3TMMeGrlHWuVEiEGsfRC0LFKVX5EUNJhYGPAVwlTDxtK025DqXgJA2b1UyyiBlm9vMglV5CdkvtL9wuU1pIeLbZP9TxZd2HQiPHgKpXno4YBhdF5ChwfLLzsavcHTj4hsSmhWBvQmFh@1Tc@M6O@/v0rv97PXUj/xYIr7vDWvr4/o@DB8)

`b` removes leading space if there is a leading space

`e` removes trailing space if there is a trailing space

`%` switches between `b` and `e`

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 86 bytes

```hs
(f#g)
r=reverse
f(' ':s)=s
f s=g s
g=r.f.r
(a#b)s=s:[x|last s<'!'||s<"!",x<-(b#a)$a s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc0xDoIwFIDhvad4FBLaBDwAoTfQicmowwPbSiykeQ8MA2e36uC/fdP/QH7aENI638kyg7km5XKvBRmyL0tshVMllA1rw8IBGw8svKGDO5BQmPeaDTeXbQ/IC3BbZuW@cyszWW1trfocdYHAtzThOIOBCeMJ4rp0Cx1nKOA/lvDtbLmCbqTsB5DpPbiAnlM9xPgB) Usage: `(f#g) "    test     "` yields a list of strings.

#### Explanation

- Function `f` removes a leading space from a given string. If there is no leading space, it calls function `g`.
- Function `g` reverses the string, calls `f` and reverses back. This removes a trailing space if there is one, and an leading space otherwise.
- If a string has neither leading nor trailing spaces, then `f` and `g` diverge, so this needs to be checked before.
- The main function `#` is initialized with `f` as first and `g` as second argument. The third argument `s` is the input string, which is appended to the recursively computed list of results:

  - If `s` has no leading or trailing spaces, then `last s<'!'||s<"!"` is false and the list of results empty.
  - Otherwise the function given as first argument is applied to `s` and `#` is applied recursively with `f` and `g` exchanged.

Answer (score 1):

## D, <s>142</s> 140 bytes

```d
import std.stdio;void u(T)(s){s.writeln;while(s[0]<33||s[$-1]<33){if(s[0]<33){s=s[1..$];s.writeln;}if(s[$-1]<33){s=s[0..$-1];s.writeln;}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S/n/PzO3IL@oRKG4JEUPiDPzrcvyM1MUSjVCNDVCFIo1q4v1yosyS1Jz8qzLMzJzUjWKow1ibYyNa2qKo1V0DUFMzerMNJgwUL1tcbShnp5KrDVCZy1YAVw5SIkBUAmQj6yotvY/2O7cxMw8Dc1qJQWFEA9PP3cFJb1S69r/AA)

This is a port of [HatsuPointerKun's C++ answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143410/55550).

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 138 bytes

```
a(s)=' ' in s?s[1]==' '?(println(s);z(s[2:end])):z(s[1:end]):print(s)
z(s)=' ' in s?s[end]==' '?(println(s);a(s[1:end-1])):a(s[1:end]):print(s)
```

Not sure if there is a way to substitute another character for `end`, but if there was that would probably save some bytes.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>149</s> 116 bytes

```
def G(p):if p==[]then. else sub(p[0];"")as$n|if.!=$n then.,($n|G(p|reverse))else($n|G(p[1:]))end end;G(["^ "," $"])
```

Expanded

```
def G(p):
  if p==[] then .                  # stop when no patterns remain
  else
     sub(p[0];"") as $n            # use first pattern
   | if .!=$n                      # if we removed something
     then ., ($n|G(p|reverse))     #   return result and switch patterns
     else ($n|G(p[1:]))            # otherwise remove failed pattern
     end 
  end 
;
G(["^ "," $"])
```

Sample Run

```
$ jq -MRr 'def G(p):if p==[]then. else sub(p[0];"")as$n|if.!=$n then.,($n|G(p|reverse))else($n|G(p[1:]))end end;G(["^ "," $"])' <<<'     codegolf     '
     codegolf     
    codegolf     
    codegolf    
   codegolf    
   codegolf   
  codegolf   
  codegolf  
 codegolf  
 codegolf 
codegolf 
codegolf

$ wc -c <<<'def G(p):if p==[]then. else sub(p[0];"")as$n|if.!=$n then.,($n|G(p|reverse))else($n|G(p[1:]))end end;G(["^ "," $"])'
 116
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>151</s> 150 bytes

```kotlin
{var v=it
var c={println(v)}
while(0<((if(v[0]<'!'){c()
v=v.substring(1)
1}else 0)+if(v.endsWith(' ')){c()
v=v.slice(0..v.length-2)
1}else 0
)){}
c()}
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
{
    var v = it
    var c={println(v)}
    while ( 0 <(
            (if (v[0] < '!') {
                c()
                v = v.substring(1)
                1
            } else 0)
                    +
                    if (v.endsWith(' ')) {
                        c()
                        v = v.slice(0..v.length-2)
                        1
                    } else 0
            )){}
    c()
}
```

### Test

```kotlin
/** Shows spaces, just helps viewing answer. */
fun println(i: String) {
    for (c in i) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            print('~')
        } else {
            print(c)
        }
    }
    print('\n')
}
var u: (String) -> Unit =
{var v=it
var c={println(v)}
while(0<((if(v[0]<'!'){c()
v=v.substring(1)
1}else 0)+if(v.endsWith(' ')){c()
v=v.slice(0..v.length-2)
1}else 0
)){}
c()}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    u("      Let's go golfing   ")
}
```

## Edits

-1 -> `x == ' '` => `x < '!'` [Jonathan French](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech)

Comment: [150 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVGxTsMwEN39FUcXnwNNW8aqqcTOViEGYAjBSQ6MU9mOIxSFXw92SmgHnizr9Pzu6d75o3GK9LhKEjjUTWfBHvNC2ht4b62DWqqjBU@yI11Brm0nTQrJipWthqMh7ZRG2sLBhboS0DMIKBsDWABpoJmKoDKyWQYc@CUfMXkh/@bijx5AKiv/1RUXKna@f02edXAZGPO5gXYLOA@33MODJgfZ2Mcnn5GbNEXWz1G8GFhXk5K43iFSif5p/bLjV1z0BQrmM5/a9tVOhrgRbDNMM67FddSmUr/ZR3I1xoQXLYqK4JimPlVSV65e3p5bWRAOLEiHMS71MyeNuansFu6Myb92p@n388JaXJyC30vHLVRNOKqMvwOwCLHHHw).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a successful contender, because it works only for len(left whitespace) between [len(right whitespace), len(right whitespace)+1]. Anyway, just for the fun of it:

Python 3, 56 bytes:

```
def f(a,e=0):print(a);a[e]<'!'and f(a[e+1:e or None],~e)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X51LXbtaT8PYyLZaz7C22lrPoDYzLUbTWhMkApKMAYmCBGtqU/L//1dQUChJLS5RUAAA) - 46 bytes

```
'
'+{.(32={.1}{;.0}if\);)32={'
'+\1}{;0}if|}do
```

#### Explanation

```
'\n'+    Adds endline to the argument
{.       Starts do loop and duplicates the top of the stack
(32=     Is the first character a ' '?
{.1}     It is, duplicate result and push 1
{;.0}if  It isn't, remove cut string, duplicate and push 0
\        The number (0 or 1) we pushed before sinks one position
);)      Obtains the last character of the string
32=      Is it a space?    
{'\n'+\1} Add a new line, make the number we pushed before rise
          one position, and push another 1
{;0}if   Same as before
|        'Or' between the two numbers we pushed before
}do      If at least one of them was 1, repeat!
```

#### Test

It works with dots by replacing 32 with 46.

```
Input: ...test..

Output:

...test..
..test..
..test.
.test.
.test
test
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 18 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÈrYg"^  $"ò}hUÊN â
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=yHJZZyJeICAkIvJ9aFXKTiDi&input=IiAgICAgY29kZWdvbGYgICAgICI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ùG⌐♦ò⌡╩d♪º"╪8·`;
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9747a90495f5ca640da722d838fa603b&i=%22+++++codegolf+++++%22%0A%22++++++Let%27s+go+golfing+++%22&a=1&m=2)

#### Procedure:

- Alternate replacing regexes `"^ "` and `" $"` with `""`.  Do this `n` times where `n` is the length of the input.
- Remove duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 33 bytes

```perl
(s/^ //&&say)|(s/ $//&&say)&&redo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@jWD9OQV9fTa04sVKzBshTUIHx1NSKUlPy//9XAILk/JRUhfT8nDQFMPiXX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv24eAA)