# Dad jokes are fun

Tags: code-golf, natural-language

We all know the classic dad joke that goes something like this:

1. Somebody says a sentence to describe their self (e.g. `I'm tired` or `I'm confused`).
2. A dad-joke enthusiast comes along and replies `Hi <adjective>, I'm Dad!`, because introductions follow the same format (`I'm Peter` follows the same format as `I'm hungry`).

Your job is to take in an input in the form of a self-descriptor, and output the appropriate dad-joke form, but instead of using the word "Dad", you'll use the name of the programming language you're programming in.

Test cases (assume that they are being parsed by Python):

```
I'm amazing                  Hi amazing, I'm Python!
I'm tired                    Hi tired, I'm Python!
I'm hungry                   Hi hungry, I'm Python!
I'm fat                      Hi fat, I'm Python!
```

Now assume that these test cases are being parsed by Golfscript:

```
I'm a programmer             Hi a programmer, I'm Golfscript!
I'm a question-writer        Hi a question-writer, I'm Golfscript!
I'm a Stack-Overflow-er      Hi a Stack-Overflow-er, I'm Golfscript!
```

The exact challenge:

1. Take in a string in the self-descriptor format (`I'm <adjective>` or `I'm a(n) <noun>`) using standard input or through a function.

- Assume there is no ending punctuation.
- Assume the word `I'm` is used and not `I am`.

2. Convert it to a dad-joke format - see the above examples for exactly how that should look.

Other stuff:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest byte count wins.
- Follow the [standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) rules - none of those, please.
- Have fun!

Comment: One of the ways I considered telling my family that my wife was expecting was by telling as many dad jokes as possible and seeing who caught on!

Comment: Some example outputs end with exclamation and some do not.  What is the significance?

Comment: @recursive Whoops! That's a mistake on my part. All inputs should end in exclamation marks.

Comment: Usual practice is to give it much longer before accepting an answer, if you do so at all: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2035/66252

Comment: And the tie-breaker isn't votes, it's who reached the lowest score first.

Comment: In the interest of 100% fairness, I think every contestant should be required to rename his language to a 100-byte name (in such a way that both the external and internal representation are 100 bytes) .  Then see how long the codes are.

Comment: I think the examples including `a` or `an` don't make sense (grammatically)

Comment: Does the "or" in "I'm <adjective> or I'm a(n) <noun>" mean both have to be parsed correctly by an answer, or can I choose which one?

Comment: You should probably require that the Language's Name appears verbatim in the source code, but allow it to be subtracted from the byte count for the answer.

Comment: Now waiting for the next golfing language that's name is an empty string.

Comment: @dzaima Both have to be parsed, but it should be the same procedure for both - you're just taking everything after `I'm`.

Comment: @connectyourcharger ah okay, I just wanted to see if splitting on spaces & taking the 2nd element was a valid algorithm.

Comment: I pity the people who program in this language: https://esolangs.org/wiki/A_programming_language_is_a_formal_language,_which_comprises_a_set_of_instructions_that_produce_various_kinds_of_output.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft And then, a language which has a built-in for its name wins.

Comment: No requirements on behavior if the input does not start with `"I'm "`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 13 bytes

```
cEHi<esc>A, <C-r>" V!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9nVI1PaUUdBSEkhTPH/f0/1XIWS1OIShdzU4uLE9FQA)

Inspired by [tsh's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185891)

This takes advantage of the fact that `I'm` is yanked from the start of the string when deleting the text from the start, and pastes it to the end with `<C-r>"` while in insert mode.

Comment: I just edited `I'm` to `<C-O>p` and then notice your answer...

Comment: A golfing language using Vim and `escape` takes 5 characters???

Comment: @mowwwalker Nope. It's really the byte `0x1B`, but it's easier and more obvious what it means if you write it as `<esc>`. The same for `<C-r>`, which is really `0x12`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, ah that makes much more sense

Answer (score 21):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>59</s> <s>42</s> 33 bytes

-17 bytes thanks to @Conor O'Brien noticing that the import wasn't necessary

-9 bytes thanks to @tsh pointing out a shorter, UB way of writing the function

```c
a(x){printf("Hi%s, I'm C!",x+3);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvLCsIwEADPzVesATGpCQgec/SiJw9@wbIkMdiHbGtbKP11o7nNMAzZSJQzqkWvb07dGJS8pv1g4HZo4bKTZjmetdvyP0GLqVMFkCMZoCdyXReZNKyiQiXLhPAYkV72PnkOTT9bz1I7UbEfP9zByYktfyk0GIds5x8)

Chops off the first 3 characters of the input (removes `I'm`) and surrounds it with the desired text.

Comment: The program compiles without the import, so you can drop it for 42 bytes.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien nice catch!

Comment: And the `int ` is also optional.

Comment: (?) And also the `char*`, maybe...; so `a(x){printf("Hi%s, I'm C!",x+3);}` should work

Comment: @tsh: yes, in practice that will work on most 32-bit C implementations (where an `int` can hold a `char*` without truncating it), despite the undefined behaviour.  On x86-64 gcc on Linux, it will always fail in a PIE executable (typically no pointers are in the low 32 bits of virtual address space, and gcc won't happen to copy the high 32 bits while calculating `x+3` from the function arg in the RDI register).  But in a non-PIE executable, static addresses are in the low 31 bits of virtual address space, so if the caller passed a string literal or a static buffer, it would happen to work.

Comment: Yes, but, you know, 42 - 33 = 9 not 11.

Comment: @tsh: haha, I totally missed that.

Answer (score 19):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 13 bytes

```
cEHi<Esc>A, <C-O>p V!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9nVI1PaUUeBv0AhTPH/f0/1XIWSzKLUFAA)

New to `V`. Just knew it about 30 minutes ago. Anyway, this language is chosen just because its name only cost 1 byte. I'm not sure how to send `<End>` key in V. Most vim environment would accept `<End>` as a replacement of `<Esc>A` in this example. But, you know, V is 2 characters shorter than vim. :)

Thanks to [@Candy Gumdrop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55514/candy-gumdrop), saves 1 byte.

Comment: Could save one byte by changing `c3l` to `cE`.

Comment: @CandyGumdrop Wow, I didn't know the upper case `E` before.

Comment: You could also do `cW` (which seems different, but is actually identical to `cE`) or `3s`. Nice job! I was just about to post almost this exact answer when I saw that there were 2 V answers already, which was a nice surprise. I've tried several different approaches, but I'm not sure if it'll be possible to get <13 bytes.

Answer (score 13):

## Excel, <s>36</s> 34 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Johan du Toit.

Input goes into A1.

```
="Hi "&MID(A1,4,99)&", I'm Excel!"
```

First attempt:

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,3,"Hi")&", I'm Excel!"
```

Comment: `="Hi "&MID(B13,4,99)&", I'm Excel"` 34 bytes

Comment: Thank you @JohanduToit.  `A1` instead of `B13` so actually 33 bytes.

Comment: Missing the `!` at the end of the output.

Answer (score 12):

## brainfuck, 164

```
,-.+>,>,----.++++>,.>,[.,]<<<+++++.----->>.[<]>[.>]<[->+++<]>++.[--->+<]>----.+++[->+++<]>++.++++++++.+++++.--------.-[--->+<]>--.+[->+++<]>+.++++++++.+[++>---<]>-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xDsJQDEOvwsbwE58g8t4zRH8oUESFYAAqcftPIlEpnpI828rpNa/P63a@jyGKRqFoCC1EAcUh3cxyb0ikJNw6HezmyrjHFtCT5bwXVNj@QilKm5YUSqIEPD4JU1owxnR8HJbvbd7en@XyAw)

The "brainfuck!" part of the string is generated with [this](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/text.html) tool, can probably be golfed further by hand.

Comment: Try [BF Crunch](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/primo-ppcg/BF-Crunch&ved=2ahUKEwjyq7eY0KviAhVTfisKHb_HDK8QFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2K-0MwjokHMSQYLmju47r3)

Answer (score 11):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
â∞¿φ‼0▲(─ƒSqÄ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83eca8ed13301e28c49f53718e&i=I%27m+amazing%0AI%27m+tired%0AI%27m+hungry%0AI%27m+fat%0AI%27m+a+programmer%0AI%27m+a+question-writer%0AI%27m+a+Stack-Overflow-er&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
.Hip        print "Hi" with no newline
3tp         trim 3 characters from start of input and print with no newline
            final line is to print the unterminated compressed literal ", I'm stax!"
`dYgAwg_
```

I moved the final comment up one line since nothing may follow an unterminated string literal.

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=.Hip++++%09print+%22Hi%22+with+no+newline%0A3tp+++++%09trim+3+characters+from+start+of+input+and+print+with+no+newline%0A++++++++%09final+line+is+to+print+the+unterminated+compressed+literal+%22,+I%27m+stax%21%22%0A%60dYgAwg_&i=I%27m+amazing%0AI%27m+tired%0AI%27m+hungry%0AI%27m+fat%0AI%27m+a+programmer%0AI%27m+a+question-writer%0AI%27m+a+Stack-Overflow-er&m=2)

Comment: I'm going to declare you the winner because your post had more votes, but you technically were tied with one other person. Congratulations!

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```python
lambda s:"Hi%s, I'm Python!"%s[3:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSskjU7VYR8FTPVchACyvqKRaHG1sFfu/oCgzr0QjTUMJJJeokJibWJWZl66kqfkfAA)

-1 byte thanks to Embodiment of Ignorance

Also 34 bytes, using the newer formatted strings, thanks to Gábor Fekete:

```python
lambda s:f"Hi{s[3:]}, I'm Python!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKk3JI7O6ONrYKrZWR8FTPVchAKxKUel/QVFmXolGmoYSSDRRITE3sSozL11JU/M/AA)

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSskjU7VYR8FTPVchACyvqKRaHG1sFfu/oCgzr0QjTUMJJJeokJibWJWZl66kqfkfAA)

Comment: What about losing `lambda s:` and replacing `%s[3:]` with `%input()[3:]`? (-4 bytes)

Comment: @niko if I understand what you are saying, that will not print anything. Default rules on this site are either a full program that prints output or a function that returns output. Usually what you are suggesting is called a snippet, and would not be a complete solution, it would need to be wrapped with `print()` for 7 more bytes, which is why Python answers usually use lambdas.

Comment: But how is that different from your (and actually most) answer(s) here? I mean both by themselves do not print anything, and both return the same output right? (Fairly new here - still getting used to CG)

Comment: @niko It's OK! With `lambda s`, I have defined an (anonymous) function. If you look at the header and the footer in the TIO link, I name that function `f`, and then called it with `f("I'm whatever")`. Then the function returns the expected output. With your snippet, you neither print nor return from a function - you just have a bit of code that evaluates to the correct result, but does not do anything with it. You can run programs multiple times, you can call functions multiple times, but a snippet is just a snippet.

Comment: See [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) for where the decision was made.

Comment: alternative, but still 34-byte solution: `lambda s:f"Hi{s[3:]}, I'm Python!"`

Comment: @GáborFekete that was the first thing I tried, and I swear it gave me an error. No idea what I did differently.

Answer (score 9):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, <s>32</s> <s>27</s> 26 bytes

-5 bytes by leveraging [Nick Kennedy's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185874/52194).

-1 byte from splitting on a different point in the string. Also realized my old bytecount was wrong.

```ruby
~/m/;$_="Hi#$', I'm Ruby!"
```

#### Explanation

```ruby
                            # -p gets line of input and saves to $_
~/m/;                       # Find first 'm' in $_ using regex
     $_="Hi#$', I'm Ruby!"  # Save modified string to $_
                            # ($' is the string AFTER the most recent regex match)
                            # -p outputs $_ to screen
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v05fQd9aJd5WySNTQVlFXUfBUz1XIQgopaj0/z@InZibWJWZl/4vv6AkMz@v@L9uAQA)

Comment: Cool! Where's your input?

Comment: @connectyourcharger added an explanation. Input is STDIN.

Comment: Gotcha. Good answer!

Answer (score 9):

## x86, <del>37</del> 36 bytes

```
00000000: d1ee ac8a d8c6 0024 adc7 0448 698b d6b4  .......$...Hi...
00000010: 09cd 21ba 1901 cd21 c32c 2049 276d 2078  ..!....!., I'm x
00000020: 3836 2124                                86!$
```

Unassembled:

```
D1 EE       SHR  SI, 1                  ; point SI to DOS PSP (80H)
AC          LODSB                       ; load string length into AL, advance SI
8A D8       MOV  BL, AL                 ; put string length into BL
C6 40 24    MOV  BYTE PTR[BX][SI], '$'  ; add string terminator to end of string
AD          LODSW                       ; advance SI two chars
C7 04 6948  MOV  WORD PTR[SI], 'iH'     ; replace second and third char with 'Hi'
8B D6       MOV  DX, SI                 ; load offset for INT 21H string function
B4 09       MOV  AH, 9                  ; display a '$'-terminated string function
CD 21       INT  21H                    ; call DOS API
BA 0119     MOV  DX, OFFSET S           ; load offset for second part of string
CD 21       INT  21H                    ; call DOS API
C3          RET                         ; return to DOS
S  DB ", I'm x86!$"
```

A standalone executable DOS program.  Input from command line, output to screen.

[image]

* The exact "language" name here is a little ambiguous as CPU machine code isn't really a language in a formal sense. Going with "x86" as a generally understood and accepted name for the target platform.

Comment: [moving comment down from main thread] I'd say "x86" is the architecture, while "MA SM" would be one of the available languages on that architecture (note it does have a space in it though).

Comment: I think "x86" is probably fine really, it is golf after all :)

Answer (score 8):

## R <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 39 bytes

@Giuseppe Edit

```
sub("I'm(.*)","Hi\\1, I'm R",scan(,""))
```

---

@AaronHayman Edit

```
function(s)sub("I'm (.*)","Hi \\1, I'm R",s)
```

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcuxCsIwEIDh/Z7iOAdzEgPdXQVdnbukIU0D7SlJAxbx2WOLOLh@P3@qPZ6O2Bdxc7yLyvzKzsqfGWM411w6Rdf9pMyBSdMltm2jcQW8kd4epYmY6xt2eH7a6TF6bKBXTsG2ocWhSEgLhrKQ/loqIlHC2ro442hn/yuDT56AGQDqBw)

Comment: can save one byte replacing `"(I'm )` with `"(.* )`

Comment: @AaronHayman, doesn't work for `I'm a programmer` (many spaces) because of greediness

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Right, I wasn't sure if the first or last white space would be considere.

Comment: lazy quantifier`(.*? )` could be used but it's the same length as `(I'm )`

Comment: Okay, I saved a byte, and I think this one works properly [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nco9C8IwEIDh/X7FcQ5eJArdXQW7OndJS5IG2lOSHNhfH79wfZ83t4DnI7agMtV0Fy6m6MjU71fk08GQpWvCYegsftKNbDENdnh5uvWxeOwg8MTw/R3OKjFvGHUj@2tZRZLEt42p4uKq/8vssycwBgDaCw "R – Try It Online")

Comment: 2 bytes by changing the `sub` to `"I'm(.*)" and "Hi\\1, I'm R"` and 3 bytes by taking input from stdin using `scan`: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##VcuxCsIwEIDh/Z7iOAdzEgPdXQVdnbukIU0D7SlJAxbx2WOLOLh@P3@qPZ6O2Bdxc7yLyvzKzsqfGWM411w6Rdf9pMyBSdMltm2jcQW8kd4epYmY6xt2eH7a6TF6bKBXTsG2ocWhSEgLhrKQ/loqIlHC2ro442hn/yuDT56AGQDqBw)

Comment: Note that the TIO link does some messing with aliases to make it work for multiple strings.

Comment: @Giuseppe Smooth circumventing `function`

Comment: @niko that's a [classic R golf trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4051/67312)! You should check out the other  tips there, too!

Answer (score 7):

## Java, 36 bytes

```java
s->"Hi"+s.substring(3)+", I'm Java!"
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZGxbsIwEIb3PMXVC4nAWTqidoZKpQNj1eFw3GCI7eA7B0GVZ08dFHWsspzs8/fdb@lO2KE8VedBNUgE72jcTwZgHOvwjUrDbrwC7DkYV4PKpwMV69Tvs1SIkY2CHTh4gYHkq9gYsaSS4oEecP5cLMUKtgsLbynuSQzr0WvjoUnepHfeVGBT/JTw@QVYTNk3Ym1LH7ls0xM3LnelysU4EC3eEy2Kx3/@Z9kEXc0ij9HV4TYLRWiDrwNaq8NM4RI1sfFOXoPh2daeUZ3lR5f20vir/PP6rB9@AQ)

Answer (score 7):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 267 bytes

```
[S S S T    S S T   S S S N
_Push_72_H][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][S S S T    T   S T S S T   N
_Push_105_i][T  N
S S _Print_as_character][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][N
S S N
_Create_Label_INPUT_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve][S N
S _Duplicate_input][S S S T S T S N
_Push_10][T S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_TRAILING][T N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_INPUT_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_TRAILING][S N
N
_Discard_top][S S T T   S S S T S T N
_Push_-69_!][S S T  T   N
_Push_-1_e][S S T   T   T   N
_Push_-3_c][S S T   T   S T N
_Push_-5_a][S S S T S T S N
_Push_10_p][S S S T T   S T N
_Push_13_s][S S T   T   N
_Push_-1_e][S S S T T   T   S N
_Push_14_t][S S S T T   N
_Push_3_i][S S S T  S N
_Push_2_h][S S T    T   T   T   T   N
_Push_-15_W][S S T  T   S S S T T   S N
_Push_-70_space][S S S T    T   T   N
_Push_7_m][S S T    T   T   T   T   T   T   N
_Push_-63_'][S S T  T   T   T   S T N
_Push_-29_I][S T    S S T   T   N
_Copy_0-based_3rd_-70_space][S S T  T   T   T   S T S N
_Push_-58_,][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_PRINT_TRAILING_LOOP][S S S T  T   S S T   T   S N
_Push_102][T    S S S _Add][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
T   N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT_TRAILING_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Since Whitespace inputs one character at a time, the input should contain a trailing newline so it knows when to stop reading characters and the input is done.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##RU5BDsMwCDubV3Dbqa/YYdozqpZpk1p1Wiv1@SkxJEsIAmObnO/PYft3nKwUVQVDBaL1AERaK349vO@PQEwIgVB18SK0aecUSarQmSSWTJGJhFp7jwDRwKCEqumYktYmvaou@G@ifS1zB6W0iH9CSnneVh31vs02PLblNdhPLg) (with raw spaces, tabs, and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Print "Hi"
Read three characters from STDIN, and do nothing with them
Start INPUT_LOOP:
  Character c = STDIN as character
  If(c == '\n'):
    Call function PRINT_TRAILING
  Print c as character
  Go to next iteration of INPUT_LOOP

function PRINT_TRAILING:
  Discard the top of the stack (the c='\n' that was still on the stack)
  Push "!ecapsetihW m'I ," one character at a time
  Start PRINT_TRAILING_LOOP:
    Print as character
    Go to next iteration of PRINT_TRAILING_LOOP
```

The characters of `", I'm Whitespace!"` are pushed in reversed order, and then printed in a loop. All values of these characters are also lowered by 102, which are added in the loop before printing to save bytes. This constant 102 to lower each character with is [generated with this Java program](https://tio.run/##bVJba8IwFH73V5zlZQnR4mAyZg2isIfC3MO6GzgZaY0aV2vXHAUZ/vYutdbWbS8tPd81J13KrWwtp59ZFkbSGBhJHX83AJJNEOkQDEq0r@1aT2FlIepjquP5eAKS5TSAYgCpMpsIQYActyfuAdExglnJKFImB7wY1Vylzmjw9vEyuH@@a4Inbjpu3aWkP5ZuhBT4bJ3S3E8Lz9W9q07b1ZwfG1QdBCFNbCaiVBW6YIcKgm7R0JkrHNqBoewkB0BBfJ9wGrR0r90nT6RLfMLcE17Gh93yFLge6limuyKa5igbSVw4MjC5DWP/J9ksLsLe9W3fJnRtUhWyb9Qo5OE9rmGpoOior42MDE2Y1VrY6pHxtCIlAsuP0kvPaOpEKp7jgjLonRZca/Rn5zXH2vVVNhXs2bk@jyye/s6gWjnrDTqJ3Q9GMSWFXBBemnLi2vsk3OPEnvVo@1tJz@sdWPvGPssy@/tcruB1oe2KExmqix8). Also, instead of pushing the value `-70` for both spaces twice, the second space in `"!ecapsetihW m'I ,"` is copied from the first with the Copy builtin to save a few bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>34</del> 32 bytes

```php
Hi<?=substr($argn,3)?>, I'm PHP!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcrBCgIhFIXhfU9hEFQwrtpO4y5mVg30BLdyVEq9XbWhHj5DiVbn4@egxpx704p9SOcQabMCUq7ZbUXXsGFt2diPy9wK1MhEl0sBC2/j1KI4GpLXKp2colflBLEuMCSvCKyV9AuPJEM03vGZTPzXU4TLjR@fkqa7n7mkj8fyCpkfvg)

Input via `STDIN`, call with -F.

```php
$ echo I'm a Stack-Overflow-er|php -F dad.php
Hi a Stack-Overflow-er, I'm PHP!

$ echo I'm hungry|php -F dad.php
Hi hungry, I'm PHP!
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>31</s> 24 bytes

*Cut down based on clarifications from OP and a suggestion from @NahuelFouilleul.*

```perl
/ /;$_="Hi $', $` Perl!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQd9aJd5WySNTQUVdR0ElQSEAKKGo9P@/p3quQklmUWrKv/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBv91CwA)

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQd9aJd5WySNTQUVdR0ElQSEAKKFgqqBboKj0/7@neq5CSWZRasq//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYG/3ULAA)

Comment: also maybe `$^X $]` special variables could be used, however 5 is shorter than `$]`

Comment: Do you *need* to include the `5` as part of the name of the language?  i.e. could you argue that Perl 5 "thinks of itself" as "Perl"?  That was the case before Perl 6 existed, and codegolf answers only need to work on at least one implementation of the language, so pick an old one?

Comment: [OP confirms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185872/dad-jokes-are-fun/185910?noredirect=1#comment445577_185910) that `Perl` is sufficient.  And that the use of the `-p` option doesn't have to be considered part of the language name.

Answer (score 6):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula Language, <s>61</s> 62 bytes

+1 because I hadn't noticed the `!` at the end of the output.

```
"Hi"+@Right(i;"I'm")+", I'm IBM/Lotus Notes Formula Language!"
```

Computed field formula that takes it's input from an editable field `i`. It would fail for "I'm an I'm" but since that wouldn't make any sense at all I'm assuming that it won't happen.

Shame that at 32 bytes, the name of the language is more than half the total length of the formula!

Screenshot below showing an example input and output:

[image]

Comment: It looks like your language would be good for the job if the name wasn't so long :)

Comment: if I was being serious I would probably just call it `Formula` which is how it is referred to in the Notes/Domino developer community :-)

Comment: @connectyourcharger: How strict is the requirement to introduce yourself with your *full* formal name in a dad joke?  Wouldn't Lotus Notes introduce itself with "I'm Lotus Notes"?  Some other answers are things like "I'm Perl 5 -p", as if the `-p` option was really part of the language name.  Easy to argue that Perl5 could introduce itself as "Perl".

Comment: @PeterCordes - Possible but Lotus Notes/Domino also has LotusScript as an inbuilt language so we probably need to be a little more specific ;-)

Comment: "Hi @ElPedro, I'm a Lotus Notes Formula"?

Comment: Could actually go a little better than that since IBM rebranded it to IBM Notes but then they rebranded again to IBM Domino so I guess that to be strictly correct it should be "Hi @PeterCordes, I'm IBM Domino Formula" :)

Comment: @PeterCordes Only the essential parts of the language name are required - I'm accepting `Perl` as a substitution for `Perl 5` or `Perl 5 -p`.

Comment: But I think that in this case, the formal name should be used (there's no version numbers - the whole language name is what it should be referred to as).

Comment: I'm not even sure if this is the official name but it's the name that I use when I am posting answers so I'll stick with it here.  In the light of this question I maybe should have used a shorter name in the beginning :)

Answer (score 6):

## sed (`-r`), <s>31</s> <s>28</s> 25 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Shaggy
-3 bytes because `-r` not needed in output

```
s/I'm(.*)/Hi\1, I'm sed!/
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WN9TPVdDT0tT3yMzxlBHAchTKE5NUdAtUtT//x/ES1QoLE0tLsnMz9MtL8osSS36l18A4hX/1y0CAA)

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WN9TPVdDT0tT3yMzxlBHAchTKE5NUdAtUtT//x/ES1QoLE0tLsnMz9MtL8osSS36l18A4hX/1y0CAA)?

Comment: Hmm ... Our way around counting flags was to declare them as different languages so I think you *may* need the `-r` but it would be worth getting Meta to weigh in on it.

Comment: i removed because of perl 5 answer and comments

Answer (score 6):

#### TeX, <s>48</s> <s>43</s> 30 bytes

Yes I *could* save a byte by writing `TeX` instead of `\TeX`, but it seems a shame.

```
\def\s[#1]#2#3#4{}\def~[#1]{Hi\s[]#1, I'm \TeX!}
```

**Update:** saved <s>3</s> 5 bytes thanks to [fixed pattern matching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123916/9174).

```
\def\s[]I'm{}\def~[#1]{Hi\s[]#1, I'm \TeX!}
```

**Update:** -13 bytes (thanks, Jairo A. del Rio).

```
\def~I'm #1~{Hi #1, I'm \TeX!}
```

Test file

```
\def~I'm #1~{Hi #1, I'm \TeX!}
~I'm amazing~
~I'm hungry~
~I'm tired~
~I'm fat~
~I'm a programmer~
~I'm a question-writer~
~I'm a Stack-Overflow-er~
\bye
```

Output:
[image: Hi amazing, I'm TeX! Hi hungry, I'm TeX! Hi tired, I'm TeX! Hi fat, I'm TeX! Hi a programmer, I'm TeX! Hi a question-writer, I'm TeX! Hi a Stack-Overflow-er, I'm TeX!]

[Try it online!](http://tpcg.io/lu4hxRhY)

Comment: [-12 bytes](http://tpcg.io/j39LvzXB)

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately, it does not work for all the test cases, which can be either one or two words.

Comment: In such a case, [-7 bytes](http://tpcg.io/UGuGrpxv) (and yes, it includes an end-of-line dirty trick). You could make it -8, but it will consume the space after the command and it result in ugly spacing. -9 with `TeX` instead of `\TEX`

Comment: How about [-12 bytes](http://tpcg.io/Zx3vWrp4)? The question says 'using standard input or through a function', so it's difficult to know what counts.

Comment: Wow, that's much better

Comment: [-13 bytes](http://tpcg.io/lFemldHN) if this syntax is allowed.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 bytes

```
`Hi{s3}, I'm Japt!
```

When Japt's string compression library achieves a 0% compress rate...

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=YEhpe3MzfSwgSSdtIEphcHQh&input=WyJJJ20gYW1hemluZyIsCiJJJ20gdGlyZWQiLAoiSSdtIGh1bmdyeSIsCiJJJ20gZmF0IiwKIkknbSBhIHByb2dyYW1tZXIiLAoiSSdtIGEgcXVlc3Rpb24td3JpdGVyIiwKIkknbSBhIFN0YWNrLU92ZXJmbG93LWVyIl0)

Another 18-byte alternative:

```
`Hi{Å¤}, {¯4}Japt!
```

Comment: ... but still beats Jelly and 05AB1E :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 35 bytes

```matlab
@(s)["Hi" s(4:end) ", I'm Octave!"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo1gzWskjU0mhWMPEKjUvRVNBSUfBUz1XwR@sTFEp9n@ahhJIIDE3sSozL11JkwsmoFBQlJ9elJibm1qkpPkfAA)

```matlab
@(s)                                 % Anonymous function taking a string input
    [                             ]  % Concatenate everything inside the brackets
     "Hi"          ", I'm Octave!"]  % The fixed parts of the output string
          s(4:end)                   % The input, except "I'm"

                                     % Returns the concatenated string
```

#### 42 bytes:

I tried retrieving "Octave" somehow, without writing it out, since 6 chars is quite a lot compared to some of the other language names here. Unfortunately, I could only find `ver`, which outputs a struct with comma separated fields. [Takes way more than 6 bytes. :(](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JbO4QEO9LLXISl2TC8wBsjW5uAqKMvNK0jTUY/KAfD2/xNxUq5i8mDygIi6YALKimLxqmHBttWGtFVglitD//wA)

```matlab
@(s)["Hi" s(4:end) ", I'm " {ver.Name}{1}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo1gzWskjU0mhWMPEKjUvRVNBSUfBUz1XQUmhuiy1SM8vMTe1ttqwNvZ/moYSSDwxN7EqMy9dSZMLJqBQUJSfXpSYm5tapKT5HwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 24477 bytes

Mors sum, Dominus Pestifer Mundi

*Hi, Dominus Pestifer Mundi, I'm dad!*

```
bP&A@?>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$T"!~}|;]yxwvutslUSRQ.yx+i)J9edFb4`_^]\yxwRQ)(TSRQ]m!G0KJIyxFvDa%_@?"=<5:98765.-2+*/.-,+*)('&%$#"!~}|utyrqvutsrqjonmPkjihgfedc\DDYAA\>>Y;;V886L5322G//D,,G))>&&A##!7~5:{y7xvuu,10/.-,+*)('&%$#"yb}|{zyxwvutmVqSohmOOjihafeHcEa`YAA\[ZYRW:U7SLKP3NMLK-I,GFED&%%@?>=6;|9y70/4u210/o-n+k)"!gg$#"!x}`{zyxZvYtsrqSoRmlkjLhKfedcEaD_^]\>Z=XWVU7S6QPON0LKDI,GFEDCBA#?"=};438y6543s1r/o-&%*k('&%e#d!~}|^z]xwvuWsVqponPlOjihgIeHcba`B^A\[ZY;W:UTSR4PI2MLKJ,,AFE(&B;:?"~<}{zz165v3s+*/pn,mk)jh&ge#db~a_{^\xwvoXsrqpRnmfkjMKg`_GG\aDB^A?[><X;9U86R53ONM0KJC,+FEDC&A@?!!6||3876w4-tr*/.-&+*)('&%$e"!~}|utyxwvutWlkponmlOjchg`edGba`_XW\?ZYRQVOT7RQPINML/JIHAFEDC&A@?>!<;{98yw5.-ss*/pn,+lj(!~ff{"ca}`^z][wZXtWUqTRnQOkNLhgfIdcFaZ_^A\[Z<XW:U8SRQPOHML/JIHG*ED=%%:?>=~;:{876w43210/(-,+*)('h%$d"ca}|_z\rqYYnsVTpoRPledLLafIGcbE`BXW??TY<:V97S64P31M0.J-+G*(DCB%@?"=<;|98765.3210p.-n+$)i'h%${"!~}|{zyxwvuXVlkpSQmlOjLbafIGcbE`BXW??TY<:V97S64P31M0.J-+G*(D'%A@?"=<}:98y6543,1r/.o,+*)j'&%eez!~a|^tsx[YutWUqjinQOkjMhJ`_dGEaDB^A?[><X;9U86R53O20LKJ-HG*ED'BA@?>7~;:{y7x5.3210q.-n+*)jh&%$#"c~}`{z]rwvutWrkpohmPkjihafI^cba`_^A\[>YXW:UTS5QP3NM0KJ-HGF?D'BA:?>=~;:z8765v32s0/.-nl$#(ig%fd"ca}|_]yrqvYWsVTpSQmPNjMKgJHdGEa`_B]\?ZY<WVUTMR5PO20LK.IHA))>CB%#?87}}49zx6wu3tr0qo-nl*ki'hf$ec!~}`{^yxwvotsrUponQlkMihKIe^]EEZ_B@\?=Y<:V97S64P31M0.J-+GFE(C&A@?8=<;:{876w43s10qo-&%kk"'hf$ec!b`|_]y\ZvYWsVTpSQmlkNiLgf_dcba`C^]\?ZY;WV97SLK33HM0.J-+G*(D'%A$">!};|z8yw543t1r/(-,+*)(i&%fd"!~}|_t]xwvutslqTonmPNdchKIeHFbaD_AWV[><X;9U86R53ON1L.DCH+)EDC&;@#>=<;|98x6wu32s0p(',mk)(i&f|{"ca}`^z][wZXtWUqTRnmPNjcbJJ_dcbEDYB@@?ZSX;VUTS6QPO11F..CHGF)(C<A$?>=<}:98xx/uu,10/po,+$kiih%$#z!b}|{z]xwvXXmUUjonmPOjihafIdcbaD_^]??T<<QVUT76QPONG0..-HGFED=B%@?>=~|438yw5vt21r/o'&+lj(ig%fd"ca}`^z][wZXtWUqpoRQlkjihafIdcbaD_^]??T<<QVUT76QPONMLE.,,+FEDCBA@9>!<;:9zx0/uu,10/po,+*)('&}$e"!~}`{zy[[pXXmrqpSRmlkjihgf_Hcba`_AW\[ZY;Q:OTSRKPIN1//.CH+FEDC&A@?>=~|:327xv43tr0)(-nl*ki'hf$ec!b`|_]y\ZvYWsVTponQPejMhgfeHcbaCCX@@UZYX;:UN7554ONGL/JIHG*ED&BA$?!76;|zyy054us1*).om+lj(ig%fd"ca}`^z][wZXWWlqpoRQlkdiLgfedGba`BBW??TYXW:9TSRK4221LKJIBG*EDCB%@?>~~5{{2765vu210/(-n+*)(i&%$ddyaav{zy\[vutsrkTRRQlkjihg`eHcba`C^]\>>S;;PUTS65PONMLKDI,GFED'%;:?"~<}{9zx6wu3tr0qo-nl*ki'hfeez!~}`_zyxwvutmVTTSnmlkjihg`eHcba`C^]?>>SXW:8TMLQPO21LKJIHGFE>C&A@?>=}5:987w/v-210).',m*)('h%$#ccx``uzyx[ZoXVVUpinQlkjiLgfeGG\DDY^]\?>YRW:UTSR5PON00E--BGFE('BA:#!!~;:927x5432s0/.nn%kk"'&%fe"!~w|_zyxwZutsUUjRRglkjMLgfed]FDDC^]\[ZSX;VUTS6QPO11FKJ-H*@?D'%A$">!}||387xv4-,1rp.om+lj(ig%fd"ca}`^zyx[ZutsrqjoRmlkjMhgfHH]EEZ_^]@?ZYXWVUN7554ONMLKJIBG*EDCB%@?>~~5{{2765vu210/.-,%*k('&%f#"b~a_{^\x[YutWUqjinQOkNLhKIeHFbEC_B@\?=<<QVUT76QPONMLKJC,GFEDC%;@?>=}5|381654-2sqqp',m*)('h%$#ccx``uzyx[ZotWrqpoRmlkMMbJJ_dcbED_XA??>YXQV9TSRQ4ON0L/-IH+F(>=B%#?>!<|438yw5vt2sq/pn,mk)jh&%fd"yx``uzyx[ZutmrUponmPkjiKK`HH]ba`CB]\[T=;;:UTSRKP3NMLK.IHG))>&&;@?>!~;:9816w4321r/.-mm$jj!&%$ed!~}|{t][[ZutsrqpinQlkjiLgfeGG\DDY^]\?>YXWVUTMR5PONM0KJI++@((=BA@#"=<;:9870wuut10/.-,+*#(i&%$#d!~}__t\\qvutWVqponmlkjchKfedcbDZ_^]\>T=RWVUNSLQ4ONML/-CBG*(D'%A$">=~|:327xv43tr0)(-nl*ki'hf$ec!b`|_]\\qvutWVkTRRQlejMhgfeHcbD`_B]?UTY<:99NSR5P2HGL/-IH+F(>=B%#""7<;|9y105vt2sq/pn,mk)jh&%$ed!x}`{z]xwYuXVrUSoRPlkNLha`eHFbEC_B@??TYX;V8NMR53ON1L.DCH+)ED'B$:9>!};|z876wv32+r/.-n+*j(ig%$ec!xw|_]yx[YunmrUSonQOkdchKIeHFbEC_B@\?=Y<:99NSRQ43NMLKD-++*EDCBA:?"=<;|z21ww.321rq.-,+*#(i&%$e"!~``uzy\ZvonsrqTSnmlkjibKIIHcba`_^]V[>YXW:UTS55JON1L.DCH+)E(&BA$?!76;|z8ywvv-21r/o'&+lj(ig%fd"ca}`^z][ZZotsrUTonmlkjibgJedcFa`_^]@>ZSRW:877LQP31MFEJ-+GF)'C<;@#!=~|:{y76wu3,+0qo-nl*ki'hf$ecbbw|{z]\wvutsrqpiRmlkjiKafedcE[DY^]\UZSX;998MR5PON1LK-,,AFE(C%;:?"~<;|9y105vt2sq/pn,+l)i!~%fd"ca}`^z][wZXtsrUTinQlkNihgII^FF[`_^A@[T=XWV9TSR44INM0K-CBG*(D'%$$9>=~|:327xv4usrr).-nl*#"'hf$ec!b`|_]y\ZvYWsrqTSnmleNLLKfedc\aD_^]@[ZYXW:8TMLQ42NM0K-CBG*(DC&A#98=~|:9z7w/.3tr0/p-m%$)jh&ge#db~a_{^\x[YXXmrqpSRmlkjchKfedGbaC_^A\>TSX;9UT75QJIN1/KJ-+G@?D'%A@#!=65:{y7xv4us1rp.om+lj('&gf#"!~}v_]]\wvutsrkpSnmlOjihJJ_dcFaCYX]@>Z=;WV9T6LKP31M0.--BGF)D&<;@#!=~|:{y7xv4us1rpoo&+*)ji&%$#"!x}`{zy\ZpotWUTTinmPNjcbgJHdGEaDB^A?>>SXW:8TMLQ42N1/K.,H+)E(&%%:?>=~}:987654-trrq.-,+*)('~%f#"!b}|{]]rwvYWslkpSQPPejiLgI_^cFD`CA]@>Z=;::OTS6Q3IHM0.J-+G*(D'%A$">=<}|98765432+0q.-,+*j"'&%$dzcx}|uzyrwZutsrUponPPeMMbgfeHGbaZCAA@[ZYRW:UTSR5PONML/-IBAF)'C&$##8=<}{9216wu3tr0qo-nl*ki'hf$ec!b`__tyxwZYtsrkpSnmlkNihgII^cbE`BXW\?=Y<:VU8S5KJO20L/-I,*F)'C&$@#!=~|:9z7w/.321rq.-,+$kiih%$#"!x}`{zyx[vuWsVTSShmlOMibafIGFF[`_B@\UTY<:VU8S5KJO20L/-I,*F)'C&$@#!~~5:98yx54321*/p-,+*k('&ff{ccx}|{^]xwvutsrqjSnmlkjLbgfedF\EZ_^]V[TY<::9NS6QPON1LK-I,*FE(C%;:?"~}}498y6v.-2sq/pn,mk)jh&ge#db~a_^^sxwvYXmrUponmPkjLhKIHH]baDB^WV[><X;9U86R53O20L/-I,*FED'&A:#!!~;:38y65vt,+qq(-,+lk('~%f#"cawv{^\x[YuXVrUSoRPOOdihKfH^]bEC_B@\?=<<QVU86RKJO20LKJ-,GFE>'%%$?>=<5:{87x54t21r/o'&+lj('h%e{z!b`|{^\xqpuXVrUSoRPlOMiLJfIGcFDCCX]\[>=XWVUNS6443NMLKJC,GFE(CB$@#!=~|{{276w4t,+0qo-nl*)j'g}|#db~a_{^\xwZuWmlqpoRQlkjihaJHHGba`_^]V[>YXW:UTSRQ42NGFK.,HG*E'=<A$">!};:{y70/4us10qo-&%*ki'hf$ec!b`|_]y\ZvutWVqponmlejMhgJedcEEZ_^A\>TSX;9UT7R4JIN1/KJ-H*@?D'%$$9>=~;{327xv4us1rp.om+lj(ig%fd"!~a`{zyxwvunWUUTonmlkjihafIdcbE`_A]\?=YRQV9766KPO2M/EDI,*F)'C&$@#!=~|:{y7xv4usrr).-,ml)('&%$#"y~a|{zyxZputsrTjShmlkdibgJedcbE`_^@@U==RWVU87L5332MFK.IHGF)DC%A$">=~;{327xv4us10q.n&%*ki'hf$ec!b`|_]y\ZvutWVqjoRmlkjMhgIHH]baDB^WV[><;;PUT75QJIN1/K.,H+)E(&B%#?"~<}{987xw43,sqqp-,+$)j'&%f#"!aav{z]xZpotWUqTRnmPkMcbgJHdGEaDB^A?[><X;9U86R5322GLKJ-,GFE>C&A@#>=<;:{y70/4us10qo-&%*ki'hf$ec!~a|^tsx[YuXVUUjonQOkdchgfIHcba`YB]\[>YX:99NSR5P2HGL/-IH+)E>=B%#?"~<}{9zx6wu3tr0qo-nlkk"'&%fe"!~}|{t][[ZutsrqpohmPkjiLgfHdGEa`C^@VUZ=;WV9T6LKP31ML/J,BAF)'C&$@#!=~|:{y7xvuu,10/po,+*)('&}$e"!~a|{zyx[YunmrUSoRPlkNLha`eHFbaDB^WV[><XW:8TMLQ42N1/K.,H+)E(&B%#?>=~}:9876543,s0/.-,l$)('&f|ez!~w|{ty\ZZYnsVqpoRmlkMMbgfIdF\[`CA]@>ZY<W9ONS64P3100EJI,G)?>C&$@#!=~|:{y7xv4usrr).-,ml#(i&%$e"!a}`^z][wZXtWUqpSQmfejMKgJHdGEaDB^A?>>SXWV98SL5332MLEJ-HGF)DCBA@#!=65:{y7xv4us1rp.om+*k(h~}$ec!b`|_]y\ZvYWsrqTSnmfkNLLKfed]Fa`_B]\>ZY<:VONS64P31M0.J-+G*(D'%A$">!};|zyy0543ts0/.'nllk('&%|#d!~}`{zy[[putWrTjinQONNchgJeG]\aDBAAV[Z=;WPOT75Q42N1/KJ-H*@?D'%A$">!};:{8x0/432sr/.-,%*kiih%$#"!xa|{z]xwvutWUqjinQOkNLKK`edGEaZY^A?[Z=X:POT7544INM0K-CBG*(DC&A#98=~|:{y7xv4usrr).-,ml)('&%|eccb}|{zyxqvYtsrUpoQmPNMMbgfIGc\[`CA@@UZY<W9ONS64P31M0.--BGF)'C<;@#!=~|:{y7xv4us10/po,+*)('~%fddc~}|{zyxqZutsVqpRnmPkMcbgJHdGEa`C^@VUZ=;WV9T6LKP31M0.J-+G*(D'%A$"!!6;:9zy6543210)pnnm*)('&%$#z!b}|{^yxZvuXsUkjoRPlkNiKa`eHFbECBBW\[><XQPU86RQ4O1GFK.,H+)E(&B%#""7<;:{z76543210).o,+*)(h~%$#"bxav{zyrwpuXsrqTonPlkNiKa`eHFbEC_B@\?=Y<:V97S64P31M0.--BGFE('<%##"=6;|987x54t2sq/pn,mk)(ig%|{"ca}|_z\rqvYWsVTSShmlOMibafIGcFD`CA]@>Z=;WVU87RKP3NML/JI+GF)D&<;@#!=~|:9z7w/.3tr0qo-nl*ki'hf$ec!b`|{z]\wvoXVVUponglOjiLgfHdcFaCYX]@>Z=;WV9T6LKP31M0.J-+G*(D'%A$">!};:9zy654-2s0/p-,+kk"'&g$dzy~}|_^yxwvoXVVUponmlejMhgfIG]\aDB^A?[><XW:U7MLQ42N1/..CHG*E'=<A$">!};|z8yw5vt210qp-,+*)"'h%$#d!~`|{^\xqpuXVrUSoRPlkNLha`eHFbaDB^WV[><XW:U7MLQ42N1/K.,H+)E(&BA@#"=<;:981xvvu210/.-,%*k('h%$d"!b}_uty\ZvYWsrUpRhglOMLLafeHcE[Z_B@??TYX;V8NMR53O20LK.I+A@E(&B%#?>!<|43876wv3210/.-&+l)('hf|{ccx}|{^]xwvutsrqjSnmlkjLbgfedF\EZ_^]V[TY<::9NS6QP3NMLKJ-+G@?D'%A$">=~;{327xvuu,10qo-&%*ki'hf$ec!~a|^tsx[YXXmrqTRngfkNLKK`edGEaZY^]\?>SX;998SRKP3NM0.DC++@EDC&%@?8=~;:9z765uu,10qo-&%*)(ih%$#zcaa`{zyxqvYtsVTjinQOkjMhJ`_dGEa`C^@VUZ=;W:8T75Q42N1/KJ-H*@?D'%A$"!!6;:{8x0/4us10/po,+*)"'h%$#dbxw__tyxwZYtsrqpiRPPOjihgfe^cFa`C^]\[Z=;WPOT75QP3N0FEJ-+**?DC&$@98=~|:{y7xv4us1rp.-n+k#"'hf$ecbbw|{^\xqpuXVUUjonmPOjihgfe^cFDDC^]\[ZYXWPU8SR53IH00EJIH+*EDCBA@?>7<}:9876v.3210p(o&+$)('~%f#"c~}|^^sxwZXtmlqTRnQONNchgJeG]\aDB^]@[=SRW:877LQP31MFEJ-+G*(D'%A$">!};|zyy0543ts*q.-nl$#ii~%$#dc~}v_]]\wvunsVqpSnmlNNchgJHd]\a`_BA\[ZSX;998SRQPOHM0KJ-+A@((=BA@#"=<;:927x54u210pp',+lj(!~%$#dc~}|{zyr[vuXVlkSShmlkNMhgfedcbaZC^]\[Z<RWVUT6L5JONMFKDI,**)>C&A@#!76;|z8yw54u2r*).om+lj(ig%fd"ca}`^z][wZXtsrUTinQOONibKfedGE[Z_B@\?=Y<:99NSR5P2HGL/-IH+F(>=B%#?>!<|438yw5vt2sq/pnmm$)('hg${dbba|{ty\wvYtsrqpSQmfeMMbgfeHGbaZ_B]\[>YX:VU86RKJO20L/-I,*FE(&B;:?"~<;|z8105vt21r/o'&+lj(ig%fd"ca}`^zyx[ZutslUSSRmlkjchKfedGE[ZBBW\[Z=<WVUTSL5332MLKJIHAF)DCB%@?!=~|:{y7xv4us10qo-&%*ki'&g$dzy~a_{^\x[YuXVrUSonmPOjihgfe^cFa`C^]\>>SXW:U7MLQPO21LKJIHGF?(&&%@?>=<;:927x543tr*).om+lj(ig%$e"bxw|_]y\ZvYWsVTpSQmPNjMKgfeHGba`_^]\[TY<WVUTS5KPONM/E.CHGF?D=B%@?"=<;:9zx6/.3tr0/pn,%$)jh&ge#db~}`{]srwZXtWUqpoRQfOMMLg`eHcbECYX]@>Z=;W:8T75Q4211FKJ-H*@?D'%A$">!}||387xv4-,1rp.-,ml)"'h%$e"!a}|_z\rqvYWsrUpRhglOMihKIe^]bEC_B@\?=Y<:V97S64P3100EJIH+*ED=&$$#>=<5:{876wu-,1rp.-n+k#"'hf$ec!~a_{tsx[YuXVrUSoRPlOMiLJfIGFF[`_^A@[ZYRW:UTS6QPONM0.JCBG*(DC&A#98=~|:{y7xv4us1rp.om+lj(ig%fd"!~a`{zyxqZXXWrqponglOjiLgfeGG\a`C^@VUZ=;WV9T6LKP31ML/J,BAF)'&&;@?"=}549zx6wu3tr0qo-nl*ki'hf$#"cb}|{zyrwZutsVqpRnQOkjMhJ`_dGEa`C^@VUZ=;W:8T75Q42N1/K.,H+)EDC&%@?>=<;4{yyx543210/(-n+*k('&%$ec!xw|_]yx[YunmrUSoRPlOMihKfH^]bEC_B@\[Z=<WVUTSRQJO2ML/-CBG*(D'%A$">!};|zyy054u2r*).om+lj(igff{"!b`|uty\ZvutWVqponmlkjcLgfedcE[`_^]?U>SXWPUTMR5332GL/JI,GF(DC&A#98=~|:9z7w/.3tr0/pn,%$)jh&ge#db~a_{^\x[YuXVUUjonmPOdiLJJId]Fa`_B]\>ZY<:VONS64P31M0.--BGF)D&<;@#!=~|:{y7xv4us1rpoo&+*)ji&}fddc~}v{^yxwZutVUUjonQlNdchKIHH]baDB^WV[><XW:8TMLQ42NM0.JCBG*(D'%A$">!};|z8yw543ts0/(-n+*k('&ff{"!b}_uty\ZvuXsUkjoRPlkNiKa`eHFEEZ_^A\>TSX;9U86R53O20L/-I,*F)'CBA$#>=<5|zzy6543,1r/.-n+*)ii~%$e"bxw|_]yx[vXnmrUSRRglkNiKa`eHFbECBBW\[>Y;QPU86R53O20L/-I,*F)'&&;@?>!~;:9816w43t10/.-nl*#"'hf$#db~wv{^\x[YuXVrqToQgfkNLhKIedcFE`_^]\U><<;VUTSRQJO2ML/-CBG*(D'%A$">!};|zyy054u2r*).om+lj(igff{"!b`|uty\ZvutWVqponmlejMhgJedFbaD_AWV[><XW:U7MLQ42NM0.JCBG*(D'%A$">!};|z8yw5vtss*/.-nm*)('&%${dbba|{zyxwvunsVqpoRPfejMKgfIdF\[`CA]\?Z<RQV97S64P31M0.J-+G*(D'%A$"!!6;:9zy6543210/(-n+*)('g}$#"!aw`uzyxqvotWrqTonPlkNiKa`eHFbEC_^A\>TSX;9U86R53O20L/-I,*F)'CBA$#8!<;|z21ww.321rq.-&mkkj'&%|#d!~}`{zy[[putWUqjinQOkNLhgJeG]\aDB^A?[><X;9U86R53O20L/-,,AFED'&A@?8=~;:{y105vt2sq/.o,l$#(ig%fd"ca}`^z][wZXtWUqTRnmlONihgf_HFFE`_^]\UZ=XWV97MLQ42N1/KJ-+G@?D'%$$9>=~;{327xvuu,10qo-&%*ki'hf$ec!b`|_]y\ZvutWVqponmfkNihgfIdcbDDYAAV[ZY<;VUTSRQPOH1LKJIH*@EDCB$:#8=<;4927xvvu,1r/.-,m*)i'hf$ec!~a|^tsx[YuXVrqToQgfkNLhKIeHFbEC_B@\?=Y<:VUT76KP3NMLK.IH*FE(C%;:?"~<}{98yw5.-2sq/pn,mk)jh&ge#db~a_{zy\[voXsrqpSnmlNNcKK`edcFE`_^W@>>=XWVUNS6QPON1/EDI,*F)'&&;@?"=}549zxww.32s0p(',mk)jh&ge#db~a_{^\x[YXXmrqpSRmlkjchKfedcFa`B^A?>>SXW:8TMLQ42N1/K.,H+)E(&B%#?"~<;:{z76543,sqqp-,+*)(!&g$#d!~}|{^\xqpuXVrqTRngfkNLhKIeHFbaD_AWV[><X;988MRQ42NGFKJI,+FEDCBA:?"~~}:9876543,1r/.-n+*j(igff{"!b}_uty\ZvYWsrUpRhglOMiLJfeHcE[Z_B@\?=Y<:V97S64PON10KJIHGFED=B%@?>=<|49876v.u,10).-&+l)('h%$d"ca}|_]yrqvYWsrUpRhglOMihKIe^]bEC_B@\?=Y<:V97S6433HMLK.-B+))(C<A$?>=~;:987xv4-,1rp.omll#('h%e{z!b`|_]yx[vXnmrUSonQlNdchKIeHFbEC_B@??TYXW:9TMR5PO2ML.JI,*F?>C&$@#!=~|:{y7xv4us1rp.om+ljii~%$#dc~}v_]]\wvunsVqponQlkMiLJfeHcE[Z_B@\?=YX;9UNMR53O20L/-I,*F)'C&$@?>!~;:927xvvu210/.',m*)('h%$d"ca``uzy\ZvonsVTSShmlOjLbafIGcFD`CA]@>Z=;W:8T75QPO21LKJIHAF)''&A@?>=<;49z76w432rr).-n+k#"'hf$#d!awv{^\x[YutWrTjinQONNchgJeG]\aDBAAV[Z=X:POT75Q42NM0K-CBG*(''<A@?"!<;:9876/4u210/.n&+*)(h~g|#"!x}v{^yxwvYtsUqTRnQOkjMKg`_dGEaDB^A?[><X;9U86R5322GLKJ-,AF)DC&A@">!};|z8ywvv-21rp.'&+lj('hf${z!b`|_]y\ZvYWsVTSShmlkNMhg`eHFFE`_^]V[>YXWV9TS5Q42N1/..CHG*E'=<A$">!};|z8yw5vt2sq/pn,+*kj'&%${"caa`{zyxwvotWrqTonPlOMiLJfIGcFD`_B]?UTY<:VU8S5KJO20L/-I,*F)'C&$##8=<}:z216wu321rq.-,+*)"'hffe"!~}|{zyrwZutWrqponQOkdchKIeHFbEC_^A\>TSX;988MRQ42NGFK.,H+)E(&B%#?"~<;:{z76543210).o,+*)(h~%$#"bxav{zyrwpuXsrUponmlOMibafIGcFD`CA]\?Z<RQV97S6433HML/J,BAF)'CBA$#>7<}{{z765.3t10q.-m+lj('h%e{z!b`|{^y[qpuXVrUSRRglkNiKa`eHFEEZ_^A?[TSX;9U86R53O20L/-IHG*)DCB;@#>=~;:z8yw5vt2sq/pn,mk)(ig%|{"ca}`^z][wZXtWUTTinmlONihgfe^cFa`C^]?[><;;PUT7R4JIN1/K.,H+)E(&B%#?"~<}{9zx654ut10/.-,+$)j'&%$#cy~}|{]s\qputsrkpSQQPejMhgJedcEEZ_^A?[TSX;988MRQ42NGFK.,HG*E'=<A$">!};|z87x5u-,1rp.om+lj(ig%$#dcx}`^^]xwpuXsrUpoQmlOjLbafIGcbE`BXW\?=Y<:V97S64P31M0.J-+G*(DCB%$?>7<}{{z7654-2s0/.-n+*j('h%e{z!b`__tyx[vXnmrUSoRPlOMiLJfIGcFD`CA]@>==RWVU87RQPOHM0KJIH+FE'C&$##8=<}{9216wu3tr0qo-nl*ki'hf$ec!b`|_]yxwZYtsrqpohmPkjMKa`eHFbaDB^WV[><XW:8TMLQ42N1/K.,++@ED'B$:9>!}||387xv4-,1rpoo&+*ki'~}$#"cb}|{zyxwpYWWVqponmlkjchKfeHcbaCCX]\?Z<RQVUT76QPONMLKJCH+FEDCB$:?>=<|4{2765.3,1rppo&m*)(ig}|#db~a_{^\xwZuWmlqTRnQOkNLKK`edcFEZCAA@[TY<WVU8SR4P31ML/-IBAF)'&&;@?"~<549zx65vt2+*/pnmm$)(i&f|{"ca}`^z][wZXtWUqpoRQlejMKKJed]Fa`_B]\[ZY<:VONS64P31M0.--BGF)D&<;@#!=<}:z216wu32s0p(',mk)jh&ge#dbaav{zy\[vunWUUTonmfkNihgJedFbEC_B@\?=<<QVU86RKJO20LK.,HA@E(&BA$?!76;|z8yw5vt2sq/pn,+*kj'&%|#dbba|{zyr[vutWrqpRRglkNiKa`eHFbEC_^A\>TSX;9U8655JON1L.DCH+)E(&B%#?"~<}{9zxww.321rq.-,+$kiih%$#"!x}`{zy\wvXtsVTpihmPNjiLgI_^cFD`CA]@>Z=;::OTS64PIHM0.J-+G*(D'%A@#>~65:{yxx/432sr/.-,+$)jhhg$#"!~}v_zyx[vutVVkpoRmOediLJfeHcE[Z_B@\?=Y<:V9766KPO2M/EDI,*F)'C&$@#!=<}{921654ut10/.-,%ljji&%$#"!~w|_zyx[vuWsrUSohglOMiLJfIGcFD`CA]@>Z=;W:8T7544INML/.IHGFEDC<A$?>=~|438yw54u2r*).om+lj('h%e{z!b`|_]\\qvuXVrkjoRPlOMiLJfIGcFDCCX]\[>=XWVUTSRQJ3NMLKJ,BGFED&<%:?>=6;49zxxw.3t10/p-,l*)jh&}|#db~a_{z][wpotWUqTRQQfkjMhJ`_dGEaDB^A?[><X;9UTS65JO2MLK.IH*F)'&&;@?"~<549zxww.32s0p(',mk)jh&geddy~}`^zsrwZXtWUqTRnQOkNLhgfIHc\ECCB]\UZ=XWV9TS5Q42N1/KJ-H*@?D'%A$">=~;{327xvuu,10qo-&%kk"'&%fe"!x}`{zy\wvXtWUqpSnPfejMKgJHdGEDDY^]@[=SRW:8T75Q42N1/..CHGF)(CBA:#!!~;:9816w432s0/o-,m*j"!&ge#db~a_{^\x[YuXVrUSoRPlOMLLafedGFa`_^W\?ZYX;VU7S64P3100EJI,*F?>C&$@#!=~|{{276wu3,+0qo-nl*ki'hf$ec!~}`_zyxwvoXVVUponmlkdiLgfeHF\[`CA]@>Z=;WV9T6LKP3100EJI,G)?>C&$@#!=~|:{y7xv4us10/po,+*)('~%f#"!b`vuz][wvYtVlkpSQmPNjMKgfIGc\[`CA]@>Z=;W:8T75Q4211FKJI,+FEDCBA@9"~~}:9876543,1r/.-n+*)ii~%$ec!xw|_]yx[vXnmrUSRRglkNiKa`eHFbaD_AWV[><X;9U86R53O20L/-I,*FED'&A@?>=<;:38y65432r*/.-,l$k"'&}$#z!b}|{^yxwYYnsrUpRhglOMiLJfIGcbE`BXW\?=Y<:V97S64P31M0.J-+**?DCB%$9"~~}:38y654u21q/.om+$#(ig%fd"ca}`^z][wZXtWUqTRnQONNchgfIHc\aD_^]@[Z<X;988MRQ42NGFK.,++@ED'%A:9>!};|z87x5u-,1rp.om+lj(igff{"!~a`{zs\ZZYtsrkpSnmlOjihJJ_dcFD`YX]@>ZY<:VONS6433HML/J,BAF)'&&;@?"=}549zx6wu3tr0qo-nl*ki'hfeez!~}`_zyxqvYtsrUpoQPPejiLgI_^cFD`_B]?UTY<:V9766KPO2M/EDI,*))>CB%@"87<}{9zx6wu3tr0/p-m%$)('hg$#"!xa__^yxwvunsVqpoRmlNjiLgI_^cFDCCX]\?=YRQV9766KPO20LEDI,*FE(&B;:?"~<}{9zx6wu3trqq(-,mk)"!&%$ed!~}|{ty\wvuXsrTpSQmlOjLbafIGcbE`BXW\?=YX;V8NMR5322GLK.I+A@E(&B%#?"~<}{98yw5.-210qp-,+*)(!hffe"!~}|{zsx[vutWrqSonQlNdchKIeHFbEC_B@\?=Y<:V97S64P3100EJIH+*EDCBA@?8=~;:9z76v4us1rp.-nl*#"'hf$ec!b`|{^\xqpuXVUUjonQOkdchKIeHFbEC_^A\>TSX;9U8655JONM0/JIHGFEDC<%@?>=<|49876v.u,10/(-&+ljji~%f#"!b}|^]]rwvYtVlkpSQmPNjMKgfIdF\[`CA@@UZY<W9ONS64P31M0.--BGFE('<A$?>=~;:9yy054us1*).om+lj('hf${z!b`|_]\\qvuXVrkjoRPlOMiLJfIGcFD`CA@@UZYX;:UN7554ONGL/JIH+FE'C&$@?"=}549zxww.32sq/(',mk)jh&ge#db~a_{^\[[putsVUpohmPkjiLgfHdcFaCYX]@>Z=;WV97SLKP3100EJI,G)?>C&$@#!=~|:{y7xv4us1rp.-,ml)('~geed!~}|uz]xwZutsrqTRngfkNLhgJHd]\aDB^A?[><XW:U7MLQ42N1/KJI,+FEDC<A$?>!}549zx6wu3tr0qo-nlkk"'&g$dzy~a_{^\x[YXXmrqTRngfkNLhgfIHcba`_XA??>YXWVUTMR5PON1LK-I,*F)'C&$@?"=}549zx65vt2+*/pn,mk)(i&f|{"ca}`^z][wZXtWUTTinmlONihgfed]bE`_B]\[==RWV9T6LKPON10KJIHGFE>'%%$?>=<;:9816w432s0/o-,mk)"!&ge#db~a_{z][wpotWUqTRnQOkNLhKIeHFba`CB]\[ZYXWVOT7RQPON0FKJIH*@)>CBA:?8=~;:{87654us1*).om+*ki'~}$ec!b`|_]yx[vXnmrUSoRPlkjMLaJHHGb[`C^]@>TSX;9U86R53O20L/-,,AFE(C%;:?"~<}{9zxww.32sq/(',mk)('hg${"caa`{zs\wvuXsrTSShmlOjLbafIGcFD`CA]\?Z<RQV97S64P31M0.J-+G*(''<A@?"!<;4{yyx543,1r/.o,+*jj!&%f#cyx}|{^]xwvotWrqpSnmOkNLhKIHH]baD_AWV[><;;PUT75QJIN1/K.,H+)E(&B%#?"~<;:{z7654-trrq.-,+*#(i&%f#"!~}`^zsrwZXtsVTpihmPNjMKgJHdcFaCYX]@>Z=;WVU87RQPONGL/JI,*@?D'%A$">!};|z8ywvv-21r/o'&+lj(ig%fdccx}|_]yrqvYWsrqTSnmlkjibKIIHcba`_^]V[>YXW:UT6R53O20LK.,HA@E(&%%:?>!<|438yw5vt2sq/pn,mk)jhgg|#"!ba|{zyxwvotWrqTonmOOdihKfH^]ba`CB]\[ZYXWVO8SRQPO1GLKJI+A*?DC<A@9>!}}|38y654u210pp',+l)i!~%fd"!b}_uty\ZvYWsVTpSQmPNjMKgJHdGEaDBAAV[ZY<;PU8SRQP3NM/KJ-H*@?D'%A$">!};|z8yw5vt2sq/pnmm$)('hg$#"yb``_zyxwpuXsrqpSnmOkjMKg`_dGEaDBAAV[Z=;WPOT7544INM0K-CBG*(D'%A$">!};|z8yw5vtss*/.-nm*)('~%f#"!~a|{]yx[vXnmrUSoRPlkNLha`eHFbEC_B@\?=Y<:V97S64PON10KJIHG@)DCBA$?>=}}4zz1654ut10/.-,+$kiih%$#"!~}|uz]xwvuXVlkpSQmPNMMbgfIdF\[`CA@@UZY<W9ONS64P31M0.J-+G*(D'%A$"!!6;:9zy6543210/(-n+*)('g}$#"!aw`uzyxqvotWrqpoRmlNjMKJJ_dcFD`YX]@>Z=;W:8T75Q42N1/K.,HGF)(=&$$#>7<}:9z76543tr0)(-nl*)jh&}|#db~a_{^\xwZuWmlqTRnQOkjiLKf_dGbaDBXW\?=Y<:V97S64P3100EJI,G)?>C&$@#!=~|{{276wu3,+0qo-,+lk('~geed!~}v{^yx[vutVVkSShmlkNMhgf_dGbaD_^]??T<<QVUT76QPONG0..-HGFED=B%@?>!<;:98yw5.-2sq/.om+$#(ig%$e"bxw|_]y\ZvuXVrkjoRPlOMiLJfIGcFD`CA]\[>=XWVUTMR5332MLKJIHA*(('BA@?>=<5:{876wu-,rr).-,ml)('&%$#z!b``_zyxwvutslUponQlkMiLJfeHcE[Z_B@\?=<<QVU8S5KJO20L/-I,*F)'C&$@#!~~5:98yx543210/.'n+*)('g}$#"!aw`uzyxqvotWUUTinQlkNihgII^cbE`BXW\[Z=<QV9776QJ3NML/-CBG*(''<A@#>~65:{y7xv4us1rp.om+lj(ig%fd"ca``uzyx[ZunWUUTonglOjiLgfedcFD`YX]@>ZY<:VONS64P31M0.JI,G)?>C&$@#!=<;|{8705v32sq)(-nl*ki'hf$ec!b`__tyx[vXnmrUSoRPlOMLLafeHFb[Z_B@\[Z=<WVUN7554ONMLEJ-HGF)DCBA@#!=65:{y76wu3,+0qo-,m*j"!&ge#db~}`^zsrwZXtWUqTRnQOkNLhKIedcFE`_^]V[><<;VUTSRK4ON1LKJ,HG*)DCBA@9"~~}:98765.3t10/pn&%kk"'&%fe"!~}|{ty\wvuXsrTpSQmPNjiLgI_^cFD`_B]?UTY<:VU86RKJO20L/-I,*F)'C&$##8=<;|{8765432+rppo,+*)('&%|#d!~a|{z\\qvuXsUkjonmPOjihgfedc\aD_^]\[=SXWVU7M6KPINMLEJ-++*?(CBA$?>~<}{9zx6wu32s0p(',mk)jh&ge#"c~`vuz][wZXtWUqTRnmPkMcbgJHGG\a`_BAV?==<WPU8SR5PONML/-IBAF)'CB%#?87<}{9zx6wu32s0p(',mk)jh&%$ed!x}`{z][qpuXVrUSoRPlOMiLJII^cbE`BXW\?=Y<:V9766KPO20LEDI,*FED'&A@9"~~}:9816w432sq)(-nl*)jh&}|#db~a_{^\x[YuXVrUSoRPlOMiLJfedGFa`_X]@[Z=XWV88MRQ4O1GFKJI,+FEDC<%##"=<;:927x543tr*).om+lj(ig%fd"!b`|uty\ZvYWsVTpSQmPNjMKgfeHGba`_^W\?ZYX;9ONS64P31ML/J,BAF)'C&$@#!=~|:{y7xv4us1rp.-,ml)('&%${dbba|{zyxwvotWrqTonmlkNLha`HH]ba`CB]\[ZYXWPU8SRQ4ON0//DIH+F(>=B%#?"~<}{98y6v.-2sq/pn,+lj(!~%fd"ca}`^z][wZXtsrUTonmlkjihaJedcbaCY^]\[=S<QVUTMRKP3110EJ-HG*EDC%%:?>!<|43876wv-2sqqp-&m*)(ig}|#db~}`{]srwZXtWUqTRnQOkjMhJ`_dGEaDB^A?[><XW:U7MLQPO21LE.,,+FE>C&A@#>=<;:{y70/4us10qo-&%*ki'hf$ec!~a|^tsx[YuXVrqpSRmlejMhgJH^]bEC_B@\?=Y<:V9766KPO2M/EDI,*F)'C&$##8=<}{9216wu321rq.-,%ljji&%$#z!b}|{^yxwvuXVrkjoRPlkNLha`eHFbaD_AWV[><X;9UT75QJIN1/K.,H+)E(&B%#?"~<;:{z7654-2sqqp-,+*)"iggf#"!~}|uz]xwvYWmlTTinmlONihgfed]bE`_^A\[=<<QVU8S5KJO20L/-I,*F)'C&$@?"=}549zx65v3s+*/pn,+l)i!~%fd"!~a`{zyxwvunWUUTonmlkjihafIdcFa`_AAV[Z=X:POTSR54ONMLKJIHAF)DCBA@"8=<;:z2y0543,1*/pnnm$k('&g$#c!b`|_]y\ZvYWsrUpRhglOMihKfH^]bEC_B@\?=Y<:VU8S5KJO20//DIHG*)>'%%$?8=~;:{87654us1*).om+*ki'~}$ec!b`|_]yx[vXnmrUSoRPlkjMLg`eHcbECYX]@>Z=;W:8T75Q4211FKJ-H*@?D'%A$">!}||387xv4-,1rp.-,ml)(!hffe"!~w|_zyx[vutsrUSohglOMihKfH^]bEC_B@\?=<<QVU86RKJO20L/-I,*F)'C&$@#!=<;|{876/4u210q.-m+*k(h~}$ec!b`|{^y[qpuXVrUSonQOkdchKIeHFbEC_B@\?=<<QVUT76QPONG0..-HGFED=B%@?"=<;{{276w4t,+0/.on+*)('~%f#"!b}|^]]rwvYWslkpSQmPNjMKgJHdcFaCYX]@>Z=;W:8T75QP31MFEJIH+*EDCBA@9"~~}:987654-2s0/.o,+*jj!&%f#cyx}`^]]rwvYtVlkpSQmPNjMKgfIdF\[`CA@@UZY<W9ONS64P31M0.J-+**?DCB%$?>=<;:927x543t10p.om+lj(igff{"!b`|uty\ZYYnsrUSohglOMiLJfIGcFD`CA]\[>=XWVUTSRQJ3NMLKJ,BGFED&<%:?>7<;49zxxw.3t10q.-,ll#ii~%$#dcx}`{zy\wvXtWUqTRnQOkNLhKIeHFbECBBW\[><XQPU86R53O20LK.I+A@E(&BA$?!76;|z876wv3,sqqp-,%*k('&g$#c!b`__tyx[vXnmrUSRRglkNLha`eHFEEZ_^A?[TSX;988MRQ4O1GFK.,H+)E(&B%#?"~<;:{z76/4u21rp.-,+*kj'&%|eccb}|{zsx[vutWUkjRRglkjMLgfed]bE`_B]\[ZY<:VONS64PO20LEDI,*F)'C&$@?"=}549zx6wutt+0/pn,%$)('hg$#"!~w`^^]xwvutslqTonQOejihgJIdcba`_X]@[Z=;QP88MRQP32MLKJIHG@)''&A@?>=<;:38y654u210pp',+lj(!~%fd"ca}|_z\rqvYWVVkpoRmOediLJfIGFF[`_B@\UTY<:V97S64P31M0.--BGFE('BA@?>=<;49z76543s+0/.-m%l#('&}${"c~}`^tsx[YutWrTjinQOkNLKK`edGbDZY^A?[><X;9U86R53O20L/-IHG*)>'%%$?8=~;:9z76v43t1q)(-nl*)j'g}|#db~a_{z]xZpotWUTTinmPkMcbgJHdGEa`C^@VUZYX;:UNS6QP3NMLKJ-+G@?D'%A@#!=65:{y7xv4us10q.n&%*ki'hf$#"cb}|u^\\[vutmrUpoRPfejMKgJHdGEaDB^A?>>SXW:U7MLQ42N1/K.,++@ED'%A:9>!};:9zy654-2s0/.o,+*)(ig%|{"ca}|_]yrqvYWsrUpRhglOMiLJfeHFb[Z_B@\?=Y<:V97S64P31MLK.-HGFE>'BA$">=<;:{z76543,1r/.-nl$#ii~%$#dc~}|{zyr[YYXsrqponmfkNihgJedFbEC_^A?[TSX;9UT7R4JIN1/..CHG*E'=<A$">!};|z8yw5vt2sq/pn,+*kj'&%$#"!x}`{z]xwvXXmrqToQgfkjiLKfedcba`_XA\[ZYX:PUTSR4J3HMLKDIBG*(('<A$?>=~;:z87x5u-,1rp.om+*k(h~}$ec!~a|^tsx[YuXVrUSonQlNdchgfIH]bE`_B]\[ZY<:VONS64PO20LEDI,*F)'C&$@?"=}549zx6wu321rq.'nllk('~%f#"cawv{^\x[YuXVrUSoRPOOdihKfH^]bEC_B@\?=<<QVU86RKJO20LKJ-,GF?D'BA@#>=<;:{y70/4us10qo-&%*ki'&g$dzy~a_{^\xwZXtmlqTRnQOkNLhKIeHFbEC_^]@?ZYXQ:UT75QPONM0/JIHG@E(CBA$"87}}4987xw43210)pnnm*)('&%|#d!~a|{]\\qvuXVrkjoRPlOMiLJfeHcE[Z_B@\?=<<QVU86RKJONM0/JIHGFE>C&$$#>=<;:981x54us+0/.-nm*)('&%${dbba|{zyxwvunsVqpSQgfNNchgfIHcba`_^]\UZ=XWVUT6LQPON0F/DIHAFE>C&A@?"=<|{{276w4t,+0qo-nlkk"'&g$dzy~a_{z]xZpotWUqpSnPfejMKgJHdGEaDB^]\?>S<::9TMR5PO20FEJ-+GF)D&<;@#!=~|{{276w4t,+0qo-nl*ki'hf$ec!b`|_]yxwZYtmrUSSRmleNihgJedFbEC_^A?[TSX;9UT7R4JIN1/K.,H+)E(&B%#?"~<;|9y10vv-210qp-,%ljji&%${"c~}`{zyxwZXtmlqTRnmPNjcbgJHdGEaDB^]@[=SRW:8T75QPO21LKJCH+FE(&<;@#!=~|:{y7xv4usrr).-n+k#"'hf$ec!b`__tyx[YunmrUSonmPOjihg`IGGFa`_^]V[>YXW:UTSRQ42NGFK.,HG*(D=<A$">=~;{327xv4us10qo-&%*ki'hf$ec!b`|_]y\ZvutWVqponmfkNLLKfedcbaZCAA@[ZYXWVUNS6QPO20FE--BGFE('BA@?>=<5:{87x54tss*/.om+$#(ig%fd"ca}|_z\rqvYWsVTSShmlOMibafedGFa`_^]\[ZS<WVUTS5KPONM/E.CHGF?D=B%##"7<}:987x54t21r/o'&+lj(ig%$e"bxw|_]yxwZYnsVqpSQgfNNchgfIHc\ECCB]\UZ=XWV9TS5Q42N1/K.,HG*E'=<A$">=~;{327xv4us1rp.om+*)ji&%|#d!~a_uty\ZvuXsUkjoRPlOMLLafeHcE[Z_B@\?=Y<:V97S64P31M0.JIH+*EDC<%##"=<;:38y654u21q/pn,mk)(i&f|{"ca}|_z\rqvYWsVTpSQmPNjMKgfIdF\[CCX]\[>=XWVUNS6QPON1LK-I,*FE(&B;:?"~<}{9zx6wu3tr0qo-nlkk"'&%fe"!~}|{zs\ZZYtsrqponmfkNihgfIdcba`CA]VUZ=;W:877LQP31MFEJ-+**?DC&A#98=~|:{y7xv4us1rp.om+ljii~%$#dc~}|{zyxwpuXsrqpoQglkjiKaJ_dcb[`Y^A\[ZY<WV8TS6Q3IHM0.J-+GF)'C<;@#!=~|:{y7xv4us1rp.om+*)ji~g$#"!b}|{]]rZZotsrUTongPNNMhgf_dGba`_B@VUZ=;W:877LQP3N0FEJ-+**?DC&A#98=~|:{y7xv4us1rp.om+ljii~%$#dc~}|uz]xwvuXsrTpSQPPejiLJf_^cFD`CA]@>Z=;W:8T75Q42NML/.IHGF?(&&%@?>=<5:{87x54321rp.'&+lj('hf${z!b`|_]y\ZvuXsUkjoRPlOMihgJIdcba`Y^A\[><RQV97S64P31M0.J-+**?DC&A#98=~|:{y7xvuu,10qo-&%*ki'&%fe"!~}|{t][[ZutsrqpohmPkjMhgfHH]baD_AWV[ZY<;VUTSRQPIN1//.IHGFEDCB;$?>=~;:987xv4-,rr).-,ml)('&%$#"yb}|{zy[qvutsUkTinglkjchKIIH]bE`_B]\[ZY<:VON66KPON10EJ-HGF)DC%$$9>=~|:327xv43t1q)(-nl*ki'&ge#zy~a_{^\x[YuXVrUSoRPlkjMLg`IGGFa`Y^A\[>YXW9UT76QPIN1LKJ-+A@((=BA@#"=<;4{yyx5432+0q.-,m*)i'hf$ec!~a|^tsx[YutWrTjinQOkjMKg`_dGEaDB^A?[><X;988MRQP32MLKJCH+FE(CBA##8=<}:z21654ut10/.-&mkkj'&%$#"y~a|{z]xwYuXVrqTRngfkNLhKIHH]baDB^WV[><X;9UT7R4JIN1/K.,H+)E(&B%#?>=~}:98765.3t10q.-,+*ki'~}$ec!~a_{tsx[YuXVrUSonQlNdchKIeHFba`CB]\[ZYXWP9776QPONMLKJCH+FE(&<;@#!=~|:{y7xv4usrr).-n+k#"'hf$ec!b`__tyx[YunmrUSonmPOjihgfedc\aD_^]\[=SXWVU7M6KPONGLEJ-HGF)DC%A$">=~;{327xv4us1rp.om+lj(ig%fd"ca``uzyx[ZoXVVUpinQlkNihgIedGFaZ_B]\[><RQ99NSRQ43NMF/--,GFE>C&A@?"=<|{{276w4t,+0qo-nl*ki'&g$dzy~a_{^\xwZXtmlqTRnQOkNLhKIeHFba`CB]\[TY<WV9TSR44INM0K-CBGFE('BA@?8!}}|98765.3t10/p-,l*)jh&}|#db~a_{^\[[putWUqjinQOkNLhgJeG]\aDB^A?[><X;9UT7R4JIN1/..CHGF)(CBA@?8=~;:{87654us1*).om+*ki'~}$ec!b`|_]yx[vXnmrUSoRPlkjMLgfedcb[DBBA\[ZYXWVOT7RQ42HGL/-I,*F)'C&$@#!~~5:9z7w/.3tr0qo-nlkk"'&ge#zy~a_{zy\[vutsrqpinQlkNihJfIGFF[`_B@\UTY<:VU8S5KJO20LK.I+A@E(&B%#?"~<}{9zx6wu321rq.-,+*)('~g$#"!~`v{zyxZpYnsrqjohmPkjMKa`HH]ba`CB]V?==<WVOT7RQ42HGL/-I,*))>CB%@"87<}{98y6v.-2sq/.om+$#(ig%fd"ca}`^z][wZXWWlqpoRQlkdiLgfeHcbD`CA]@>Z=;::OTS6Q3IHM0.JI,G)?>C&$@#!=~|:{y76w4t,+0/.on+*)"i&%fd"!~}|_t]xwvutslqTonmPkjLKK`edGbDZY^A?>>SXW:U7MLQ42NM0K-CBG*(DC&A#98=~|{{2765v-2s0/.-n+*)ii~ff{"!~a`u^\\[votWrqpoRmlNMMbgfIGc\[`CA]\?Z<RQV97S64P31M0.J-+G*(D'%A$">!}||3876wv3,1r/.-,m*)i'&g$dzy~a_{^\xwZXtmlqTRnQOkNLhKIeHFbEC_B@\[Z=<WVO8SRQP3NML..C++@EDC&%@?>=6}{{z76543,1r/.-,mk#"'hf$ecbbw|{^y[qpuXVUUjonQlNdchKIeHFbEC_B@\?=Y<:V9766KPON10KJIHG@E(CBA@#>=};|zyy054us1*).om+lj(ig%fd"ca}`^z][wvuXWrqponmfOjiLJfedcbEZC^]\[ZYRW:UTS6QP2N1/KJ-H*@?D'%$$9>=~|:327xv4us10qo-&%*ki'hf$ec!b`|_]y\ZvutWlqTonmlOjihJJ_GG\a`_BAV?==<WPU8SRQP3NM/..CHG*(D=<A$">=~;{327xv4us1rp.om+lj(ig%fd"ca}`^]]rwvuXWrkpSnmlkNihJfeHcE[Z_B@\?=YX;9UNMR53O20L/-I,*F)'C&$@#!=<;|{870w4321r/.-mm$jj!&%$ed!~}|u^\\[vutsrkpSnmlkNLbafIGcFDCCX]\?Z<RQV9766KPO2M/EDI,*F)'C&$@#!=~|:{y7xvuu,10/po,+*)(!&g$#"!b}|^z][ZZotsVTpihmPNjMKgJHdGEaDB^A?[><XWV98SRQPONG0KJ-+GFEDC&;$?>=<;:38y654u21qpp',+lj(!~%fdccx}|_z\rqvYWsVTpSQmPNjMKgJHdGEaDB^]@[=SRW:877LQPO2GL/JIHG*EDC%%:""7<;:{z1xvvu2+0q.-,+l)(hgg|#"ca}vuz][wvYtVlkpSQmPNjMKgJHdGEaDB^A?[><X;988MRQP32MFK.IHGF)DC%A@#>~65:{y7xv43tr0)(-nl*ki'hf$ec!b`|_]y\ZvutWVqpiRmlOMihgfeH]Fa`_^]\UZ=;W:UNSRQP3HM0KJIH+FE'CB%@"87<}{9zxww.32s0p(',mk)jh&ge#db~a_{^\x[YXXmrqpSRgPNNchKIIH]bE`_^]\?ZYX::O77LQPO21FK.IHG*(DCBA@#8!<;:98705v321r/.n,+l)i!~%fdccx}|_]yrqvYWsrUpRhglOMiLJfIGcFD`CA]\?Z<RQ99NSRQ4I2MLKJIH+dd'&s_@?"![|k9EUC54tPPq)(Ln%I)"h3g1B@y~>O;M\[87o#WE2pSh.?,=iu:s&Gc\"~~XjzUgfwd:ss7L533!1}KhIH+@d>P<$$?![6}X9yUCBvQ,1=Mo',I*6"iDVfA@.?`<_M\r8IHXV31So/.lkjvLt`H%F#!DC1|?>gSXuPb'6p4n2mGFEi-yTFcD=%_#"8J<}{Fyx05SRPPa/L-,lH)F43fCAc!aaOu;:xZpH533TCBQzlOMvKgfe$]"D!C^j/>-w+u)O'6%$J\mM}E{,fx@E'=<_$po!6lkjz7wvAR,1a/.^&l$#Yig}|d/yx}=NM:9w%u5m3D0|.@-ewcKgsI7G#n`BA0/.yxeWtb'6pK43lkkEW-,Gdcb&&r_pK7~5|W2UgTR-sba/_^Jl$6F!hV1TAcQP<;;9977uWmEDS0.gfxdv;gsHH6\!`B|0i.xYvvPU7&_5]2ll}ihgHfeRQC&A#^!!}|Y9iVCSuQQPN<L^JJHGFF&V$AcyQw_{t\\J6H5sU1}Bhg?+*L(aJ%dGF!32|j{zT<w*P8'S%oJm[0k.i,g*e(c&a$_"]~[|YzWxUvStQrOpM:JJljFF&V1{@RQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVxpVyq90v0rL4ooDiiKIyiCgIKgoKIgKiAIDoADijjgX39uDUk6aRrPee59P/daWVnVlV27du2kXW1dP7aaN//8c531RLbDW5uh4Mb62urKcmBp0b8w75ubnZn2Tk16JtwnY66fwXfw8qP/3nt77bbyx0c530d/5s6bWr@pJ64DlfLV5QV8Pcp5p07g42Xbtbuwn0p@9BO9WHWivB0e2wwt8@q@ucWZaX31cVr97fXj5RlXf3m@f@y0sw/3d7fNxk29dhGLFSORi62tYjB4ura2kl5eWlzcnZ@Pzc7uer1bHk9kfNy1@rO88fWx2u@9vc2aex8f@7gefH998t7bp8/Hj7ftw0NYvdq42avFqxVcvXRePDrbyK8ep/ezSweZ9P5ccnY3EY95JiYwMivB7/WP1YX5wBtG5nGuM/PgHXM1m7j3/qCCq5/3irj348ejduvhPn27j3uPV2MYma3zzcLZKay@ksseHiyk92O8@k40Mg6RGQQDS2sfGPeu/wVW90xMP@Deb8brGJmrz0vc@1n39PnpsZNt4d6bSdj7dbUSvaK9B2HvEPdANrkIe0/NzkYS8SlPNLgRHvsJDb4@P/0ry72lLsT9qTPbfvDe33qasPr1T7X8dXUBqz8WYO9PR5124@E@s9@slHd3L6oxWD1c2goVguv5tZWj5aXDgwz81Z3ZGdw75ozLtfL9vQR/9T0w9/qCf9Uj434j/yrF/az1AHtvw95rt83KTX0X9l4unF2EIe6508OT1aNcNglxn08l9yJy9S1XKPi1vvbxDjnT7dLeZ1r3U66fRuNrrFYdVCAypffzwutZ/vnkqJM7fDhIQ84k67VE9bxMkQkVIDJrkJHZwz1efXc6HtucmNiAv/oT3PiivVO@T4mcuZ1w13H17/Lnxctzsdjpnp48PR5lWzf1dLraSO7WruOVaOEsHD4phjZO1@GvBrJL/syCLzU3szs9BX91gvIdcobyHVd/8kHOuL13uPoXRUZkZOEUInOcw8ikr/9m9cmJCK0@gNNEOTMLOeN7xL3fY87cfLp@qt9Xr91@qfiGkbm/w8jcZ25TlXJ9N@7wVxchI1NzFJnJKMZ9FSMDp4n3/ox7n8acwdNU@8F8v3yhv/oCf/WWzyrs/QozkuK@VSxQRi7n8DQt0OqJMK4u4v6JkektLXbxrHZa7vGpu@ZEQ8T9EpGgeIZxh8hkDzAjU3u490o5eok5E4LTdJI5Ws7S3n2QM4AEEPfx8NrqYBBY/@yvvL8tvb4sPMNZbU0/QNwb7puaC/d@hXF/hLOah4zMtR4yd7f7yZury3j8vBzdvghvOsQdThNl5BpipMiZrh9X90w8PIyJ1a8ruPeLc2vvrYeDu3SzUa5jZHauaO/BM1w9vb@0tGf8VffYlmsQ/P7EfA8svcJfFRl558HIYM6UXy8FAj@fIEYe1Gu4973ENeBM5OzUPKv@tC@2szfjxdMU3B7f4oykyEDcn6YmEQlg9ca302nCuNeuUyncezxWjG5vh8@PC0GIO6GY35/w@Xbgr3qndkIRN1YPzMh@f54R@Aky0v1wdwf5Pv7pIgTGvRcK7Xye8J0ROImRQYyEfA@FcrD6KmHk7oLPhzkDZzVKCPzzjRj5vtx7XUSMnPQgEqic0fcOZxX@6q@rZ9Jx3yyjGOT7OuLMBuTMgrZ3QrEBoxjie6n0BHsHjDwmfMfaVCYEhrgTAuc2DgGB9wHF/PPzEBmFkbj3jaVFqE0BzEjvlJGRtpyBjMzewFltNgjfd3YK29v582IhuJE/WF1eDkBkFIp5ohB31yrUps@Pj4XlwFvXP@31PbYdI3N21hKRqWNGMgJHo4QzcFbXce@BxUU/IEEyiqsTim39/Cx/fS3iWX1jjOyIjHTX6x/Vag8ic1Giqv1wciTiDvi@J/N9a@s4GMxizixT3GXlm5yQtcnxrBKKDSplVbVPTo47bfvqYVgd9r52kknDX@W9Y85sibgPiHG8z/fmYO9eH@S7wPfxWq1fqbzB6qXzx8Lpaf7prkN7x8hA5QPGgWd1izgBRAb3vrAQn5uLIhIgio27XIBi6/BXkS0hinU6hARwVjFn3r9p7@cQGcj3o6MmrJ6huF8mYjGMTMl2mhAjp7fDCgmorkLOzAG@Pzn8Vdy7YEuUkZgze3uEYleXcFaLyDhEzmR@/6vAlgTjaIyPSU5gVA@oq4wz8R3GSPM0IScgPjMR5LjD3oFxBOYWu8/PTyPiDtUDMxL2nskonCkXImGIeyF3ihmZCyBbmp9Lwmma2tpEfIezaiFB99niMxiZD7U65AzhO9Wm/f0KRAZzBqpH6WQzGKS/KpgeVA/mkbh3@quwd@IEUFfn2m33/b0L@Qxxsa/Xy5KI@6icKajaRJUvOTOzPTW1CTgzPiYY9sL729urZKnjdJqI6ZXLrxcXyIHPiOnhX60xj7yOnROPPNk8wr96nM7RX52f24la1ePPOCNX57Nq4UwM62o4j4xjff0A831xb9eI@9jYKlaPD//CUNwxMsSBAd@LwGde8sfIljBnqhWVM4QzwN8PMrbaNBl1b6yLygd1FTjBDMYdcIbyHffef0eMxIzstHF1zEhV@WRGyr3nAvRXY3MzM5TvwDiIi30u@t/fkc@8PGtxx7NKOQMI/NiBvypx5no/mWR8v7o8tfjMckrb@5SGwJCRPcSZEbXp/JwYx8mjWL2ZukGWiqtvb50fA86sra4CigHjSMSJcXgnd0JQtV34V4GLIUbOztj4zPX1O9bVi/eeyEiuTftV6j1KlJF5xJn19TXOSMDIOe4OdgQC2//qTMt75/qx11XcO@X7AfYeyatEooRMbxtOE@Q7ntVAIIn5rjLS7V7XMvKt@/LiRaY3Pe7ElkTcbw7Sacr3C6ra2yVEMcb3wKK2OuD7@Poarr7@Cfjuw3yff5prT7jtnU2pqFdtPk1Q@XaQpW6dYGQAxZZzKaza@xh3RmCM@4roKLGuKgSe9DQb1K/2ypcy7sDfqbO5uyUUS1R3igX8q5vI9E5WsKNEHknVwxvz6H9Vrv74iH3T/R13w9xRXpw/AUbmTyDuzMUEByb@rlU@iAzs3TfLGSk6m4Ho5KErE/kOCPyD@E5c7BL5O8Sdeo8sMA5AsWT5qpaIVXYivPcN5DMruaXkEEsFpvctdYKZBV79Hiufu/5Z60PP9/nxQpWPEBhWB3xHnIG4n@9EItui1xZ1FVEsGY1gvnvc4@PAsIETLPqd@ft1BTAS62pRxV1mpOibBH@Hnm95P4XdAaw@O82ri7iLnJFIIFmq6uRL1GufHB/fwl/N3FFXRvkOOEMYOXJ1qKvYlREn8EO/ipHBugr9ag0j83Ul@DtUbcaZNEamnrigqn1awtU3AMWorvpJhZi2zip2NtDz9XxzBgLLfL@66sLqxYJV@bBqU@WDnLF1B2rvgMAeyWdIhei9zs48P2Pv0XoQOVOrvvcEJ5D4fnhYh76psXd1aXICWJ0jA6cJOcHW5MQEdQfL2DdBZHT@Dpzg5usTkQBXf36yqgfEPZ3CbjgRAw4MVXuLFBSITIDxnRnH1E5U/FXiM@@BV4WR0A03B9@axnH@dtZuad1Bam9v147vR3iadhN4moAtTW6GRFeGZxXVH9nzOfB3q2pTXUV8Jy6m4cxRQOKMYHqMkcEviZF2pgedfEXoBJ2zvKoeorOJQ@9xifl@BGxpdWVlHzhwZj4es@e7xBlC4Nl2S@liP1VSIc6fMCNP7jHfoTvg2oSrX0HvsUmMY201vby0tJhJEFsCFNsRjEPbOyBBZ3RkLJZqZiR1BwqBJYoh0@PuAHIGuNgs8kg8q6RxIIpR73HZZ4zkfvUhY2Kknu@Li7sqI7E7oG549F@1FJTCKfWrzDiaDeYEReSRkDNDbMkbZ5bq1Nlo3YHJI4WCAjySNY6dq@3TvFk9oOeblRip/1XHfpX/qmJLBhezkMCxehDDtqoHxJ1YasuNqze@sSsDxvEKf/UcdTGLv6PqlrgoiepRDJ2tHx6wggJ9Uwp6Pm94a3RGKi5m6@SPc@3GjaX@WJXvdH3tmDMyHSdtyUudvGPVBgS@/Rk4M47Gg2AclwnWlnDvG6dy7476DPXaS68YmclOq0V90zfxd6EToC52Qn3TwUENkWD3ErXUSOS0hH81e4j5znG39XyoLfUhI6GjfBFdmapNVaGgGF0ZdDY3GJnzIub7@WZhg1Y3uZjFlhyR4PumVhMK@TNp2FA9UHXjv7pbo79KKoT2VxWfMVmqQAKVkcgj6zWhdj5jvp@SyqyfVad8N@Pucq2gPvMhJhPep06nLdV91pauUH9/K3TzD/ec78CBRe8RjZ5dYL7nsogE0Df5Gd9lvlNns/H1KeceXtZSIWcw7td90jhe3qE2Yc6g/q6v7qgYSp0gNDEOPd8K6cBU@VTVRnxn1Y1VZlZ/DMahczFCYNGvzkNHafJIiwMPsSXRHbDG8dhpIkslnBnJUu35LuI@hxoHIjChWBOY3gfqkaylitVF5YO9X2qzA5yqSJwhxVCvq6x2oqa3QPg@7R0jnQBO0zAncEYxa3Xrr1q9tr/fMzUOUvchZ8pvrxIJ8k9HtxCZDKr7OBEqnQ/1q6wyz0S2JUayCsH9Kq0OfAY1jsb3v2d6zGdU76HXVcL3UbWJOhuofM2GiQSoQnDPJzSOBehXZ2a2UY@cQA0bNQ7Md211yEhSamtVZhyEBKcn9tmBdVahejiiGJ1VRjENCcRfve6/a/wd@9Us6cAQmSvshlkXUxgJe1@gbnh6OhzD6mGiGOI7TuJkR0ndsMwZTWXm1aXqBkwvixOhZehsqDbtCZ0A5x4hrnw9ntlMQVfmln0TohgxbKhNwCNp3mTgO/armw6dvHP1mH7mucfdHeIMYqTsKKmuYs7w6nt1WB1qU4QVQ/qrNM3CqQpkpKEtkR6J@f70NClmZWJ1ROCXEs@bCGceDjI8X8WujCITQqYHSIAaBzA95JHTXmZLSuPA1V9Gq8xSJzg8PLi7pl6bT5OmzwxrSw6aXruNcb9tur/q19dVYhzvPF9lTqB1lGXJxbTeQ3Q2agKKe2eNw1mfEVpqK39s6ASwd6oe55s0b5KMY59mlF7WUm2VT51VgZFKS2UUMzJSKeQSxTQNOzzl8UzImTyrzK9G3IEtXbMups@beFbGkaGZPOIM7X15H3vt@TjNbMI8VeGcAZYqFZTOrK6gAJ@57L5oU5XGYSaTZv09blUPiQR/1LCJcRASENOzKp9CYDGJc6yr1lnd9Ljd47KjBIYtVteQwIVxl/zd1lEq5UqqEKxhQ@UbxZZGdWXP54UCadiqrqIO/Dt/J5V5bHOwPGJGCTjDXIwVFGJLf4HAXPkY3zFnAl8fQoUQM5sHnskPa6kcGaOTV/l@lIPTZFeZLRQzkQBn8sg4uK4aGjbNPaCuYkaG85jvWVLI4TTRNAu6slGanpmR2mmS@F6Hv5pKjubvf6W6DZil9mg2DHEXPV@L56umgqLrkTJnhqe3XS3uHBnJOBxYqqkT2PQZYNjRCOf79@enNfGnSRxVD4UE/VKvQH@V5k1DHLgYZA5srj409@DJhFJqMe66@gMcOEeMA88q8Mg44Ux@KxQK/r/ljFRQ9Lm2xfRGxr33ii4R2LvsDkT1EAoK96tZ7iitfvUiDJUv5@y0GOo95AR0sjnArqz6TvOm5x5Ns4a7gz/91TWXfTLhaT883Dt0lNokzmIcwz6OeVb3UdMTTO/LUvehszGcFvaJf@vwgOfaCflXybe0bjFsxVIN5cqJpQ7rYg1Sakm5IkcXdMNFmTPAZ7jyTSNLjbo3UAcOBrDyAX/nfMcpopM@Y2akrSvDGaU159O0VNKWyFnkqKXyXJtdUYKLEcPmfD/b3lJ6JCm1SnUz8J3@qnJa/MVkAjnBr@q@0JZUvyp1MchIFzAO9otZfZPqDhxcImtrGal2AgILLwRGRlN//NokzkQxo2pDXVV9k1G1ITILYiYvfRzA9JhhY854Vd@kPFfS@/NnToD@Gfirc9EZr/KgEIrpU/NWa1xTmXWMtPDdnFGiF4KdRZm0L4V/1Um5UpxgBH8XziJ7ZPCsqo5Snx0IBOZ8p47SmppjZLQZpdQJpF9M1wmYEygeiYxjUno7A9jz4VybJ3GSLUHOWOr@b8qV0JaMSdzkZAjdaC7hHBX@SF/HwwpK85umKlxXkb9Lnx57DH9Vaolhw94tfOf56pNPzg4abvVXJQe2OhtEYEYxVvdxRrn8JxVCTECnCYHdqM9I/d3Cd20yYU3NnSdCPM3a@ORplpo8IwduSB1YMD3mkba5tqoe2lkdhQR/UK5Yn7FpS3rlo9OkVGZiHNANf9HqPuQEsPe2fWbzUZL6jME4mM@ES8OVD@KOfRO50cgFaPNxWLqYVptoAipqk@qbwmp2IKcqw7MDYNjAOKTTgmcH7vEaKlfQ2Vw8P4npbU54rqyZjdi7GXd7zkBX9mZz5yAS9GHvqP7IuA97O509huwcdYetuLPqJhBYxZ0UFIVi5qyMkUDObJROgL12/O/mq4SRUp/hyURm/w@zA9KWpI/D6PmIYcPqPwOrs4HIFM9sDhfhdZMZaTiL2EkHq3P1IN@SD2vT09OjBzHyzmnOJ/3Asmrz5Jm74TV0SlNXJibPXLV/QtyVYUaSU5pUCEd/JE0RkUfup6zZQen33kNDgiFOYDnp5JyP2RJx4BHzVchI1iN1D8oQimFkmAOj@kM4Y@8ODJY65HDRTpPun7FPzaHyFVAxfLq7RRVilJ8gkLX5CQAJfmhm0@9bcw88q7e3TbdwWvBM/vX09AHnTYc3dWfGMWICKvLdQoKJ1r10WgifHk388TQpPuNUV2mqkp73MZ@RjEMoV0ZnozMO8lwBRnLPN2KuTX0T68CzUbp3ECIfxwpW7X7/nRAY9fcW@bBVvmNGygloLtcY4fJG9yV1ZcyBbfnuwFLrdcBIyHel/uju@r3aRXwHnXSiO1B11VR/HLoDawKq5QzN@TpZbc5HTjqppSqNQ7mNLfel8Ol18UYGsKX7MdewTqAwktT9@i55rujeAbovdW3JZHrsJ3DwXFm@VGvuITy1e9YEVFd/fpuAmrMydOdUem/4V4EtiZsBQtOTkzgn1S1peZkd@bvQCSz1x1EncPCQmy4RoUeKuyqLdN8DOkr8qwNtEveOdyaM7uD3ykfqPlQ@3juvDjwS@9X2zC/9qmCplJHSLxayV22uTRMRy2M4VLWpsyFNr4tzbQdHV6zCaqfCd4Mt/UHT07zM1nzV9FxZPNKGYnyrYXtsbdXwEwivGynkNBsu8yTuTc3kNQTmumq4RBbSjJH6HSG1Onl/2ni/SXO94llFPnPidFeFOxsxKyP@rs/KjF5bzfmmXBoH7vZFbXLqykbqwDSzUdMsayJkegzNidAohi0rX2ZhPiXxfbhfnZ/CfhWqh3LSXbGTzn5WhbY0amqOs2HVrw559/XOZmT1kKsP3QwQTM@uQjzPO6kQpC11EcU0D4ptNsx34n5HManuA4o1bzhn3tCtwA4XpUKIaZbjbFihGEXGNXyatMmzoaBYqwt3jvSQWz5s6aTzmpGxmN7ImzBG71G/RFcUMj1i2IzvmsahvG5DtYlOk6UtaVXbcNcLhzp59/lO3OHBQoJ1MUSCyIbQ9AjfVc4Ihm3xd707wHsH7HUrYd@0PaxHmn5gi@mpnOFJnOiGuxIJnFSIUVqqpRPIyYS6tUbu@gZ0ZWpqzjcDAIFFZFh/F7XpV7@Y7IYt1ys5i9ixq/iMxVKZcZj5LvomPk2zhjtnlMubJv6WcvW7h1zduJP8nRy7I241NElBURq2VCHamvvSyBmeDftRQQEExroaovtNg8G3qqtiNixd3oamN3zjTqg/xVAwy/cogaUO@5bM3kNNb/HubYXZEvtn@K/q6o/hirJ7yH9R9xmB0etmz3fz3oGzHrlNfjE8q4NBgG7HajqB6mwkilm3NKUrajS@/7ezA1G1M/sm4xie8yEH5gkouRVY/VH3PYzuwN4NA77vN8rof48NczEHfDc5sPADC3wnTU90ZZqfgFf/830@VgyV/m4xPWOuParyWX0TTxHFTH56aorvr@qzYZvrFeuqulfWbeVHKLXca/@Fy5tcgCP@at68MyHZEs5XESMhMtTzzWtaquyGnSfPQgdGt4LQCdTk2Ymliow0/moo@A2RWaC7t89Dd4QctCV2RSWuOTJiNqzulTm6L7Wc0bsy545SmyIivouJ0H6AqnZqViiGRmcjuuGO3lEOs1RDhdCVWtMlYim1FBm@1YDaknxBgCZxiMDMxWh6a/k45F0V4ATHdMc/s7JPN9nR@zMzHZ5inNEYtl39Gav9iJ5Pu3sr/JHkJyhHI6fhTYg7@5bMOxN853nE6trdrNKQu37ozsRQd0A9n4y74DPPzjgz7LQQvXYBuzI8q9yVkftSMT3yR45yuFBtkrPhUQ4X0clbCDzKKW2yVNtsWNVVUT2024LKL0Z3EefnY5pvSXY22o0M4blycEUp7z6564FxcM4QRmbQp@f3L8TFLfwdjROgx5DvUc4Zaqfhzjk5GnHHX3cWiTvP/9b/LmaUrJDvDU3iHFQ3U2UWiqFS3SydQMN33dupqRB/ZnqLagI6dtcUd7NE1S5C5XPg7/g@wS/4rncH8sUMjS39diMD812blcFZlXdvhV8sAp08xv1zkVyAs3hHqNNpu9ElAmzJ5lDXJqANe9zV3ikjASO59/ivuoP/0dGlOnmlpb5qWuqvd4Rsd7MEAvMUkeZNhndfnzc53wH9hXEgzmh3hIBxdMw7cVfGnbgR3YGYr7K301IhdNWNZza2zqbyr3UCTRczXYD4loijf4ZVNycN@w8q82pIV5nxrLZaypdqKrW2ftXurrc7pa3JBDmlhVuB75qLfDcYB@uRAgkcJnF2776FBJQzlJFy7iFvNQhtCaq2cQtfdvIaW7Iqnx0J3t9eX2ekG02qbj/vPOdT73HkDm@QE6To1QlZ@YK5LO09K1kq9B6Tdi3V5tht1I2bAebcw34X0eHeQVSf@OOrQpjvc@0J9EJ4BtjJIxeTL8SIib/ykF/H@DbJsA5swxlW3SBnFCfQbtypu1l8f3X4vgcrVw7@d/stHuNeGU8R364u6NUJuul4lHW@I2TeDDB1YP1Wg5iaazcyhj0o1B1IDmzTsNGDwupPlG/HWu4c1t8NlzdP4opF6oaH5nzW1FzNtf/WrSAnceKVFemKop7vRmQkvRUFtYneikqRfyaG70JMaXqkTSG3ENjgBJZ/BlW3f3uamBOI21P/4w1TelVoNJ8xFEPdu2/4xcSLGbmNPPtnpA68HSf@PsavCvFdRPMGkuwOHJXa4Y6S9m6pzNiVucelYojefT6rvzgYj@GvqrmHcHnzJA69@6wYIieIyHdQoPIN3Y41tVTrHqVtEke3GvA2Cd5Vke8tyfcJLE/t0N1bJz8B4jvxyD/k@xC@0/sEpLrR7EDyyC/xEtWH9lft9@SNKaJwRZGfYGrYD2y6orRuWL06IXq@SnKXp4ij7g1Pxfis2m7H/oU/Mi3Pqrwnb3kMMe42fFc3qkkXs83KRtwrkxNQen9m1M0A6MrETRjbfW1Dn8G/OpyRo2bDhn/G4c4zv37Ap2nIKW27m@UwRRRcTHWU2hTRru7rkbFzMdtdc/MWvsOszOlmr5oi2l2vVeRi0rtv3BHi@00j7x2Y1UNpqYDv/NoHvZ1TqhT5LUD4q2vmyw3OtzStuP8QnxHvQlgvlTSzB5amh4zD3LtxN@tv9i61VNZneAKaapguEUvtlE4L6yaMzPelX1yAes5YXIwiszU8mXDYu@ll/uW@tnhvSfarmpeZXwATU8Ro0OZLHbqFz66oEr19mX8AttRkV1RyuK5Sr30gdAK6hW@@smJxMap8N@PDN5BUz8coVpSv9a1z35Qk1c12r0zdJuHXPhx92BaPdPR26hyYERjfvrT8kUp/l/539T6BfFVI9zIPvWnhXD2sm@yqs9G6YfsdIWPyrKs/pNTqbrT/pXqMUAxx3mT91REY6aADa6@XkcpM@C7uxEG@Wy8iJebnrNcPHDnBX7Il@YoW4ozt3R9Zm9Zw3qQrtUO@JTF5/sOtBpMDs/dn@7/UOKiulmLRaESfrwbEXUS7um/eqGa2JE@TevHuWcU99csLMQ5eCI0Dy5d5uKOs9Pg9Duzkn@8t96XSI1kHtu/ddIlYeuQo/4z9LUB6Acz53R@Hib@poIyNfp3y4d7sKM2uzOF9AvEmneV6Rd@SdOdwz6fNyoz3Cf5wi0cqV6RCaLdJ/q47UHOPQzkBTUNGWjeqtzZXpGNXrW67lSyUK@Ne2fCMUuL7vtV7YGcz@IsXHqHynQnGcXjP@nvtOi5u9lo3HRcd3p@x3uj6laXyX5WuKIfJBM@GuV915MBO7xiSLoZ7t15z@ts7E9Y0a9RrfVInsN6KUm4FzW38x7dzjFdW6J4NK4byXTebn8DQ30/Ffe2DXbqvTZzAE3Tb1J9nQ/1hP4ETSx3ubIiLHS5ar4Li7EC@acGvH4g3uoBxsJ8A4u7sMRx6O0dVbf3dH2NG@duLptzZ4Jt0xMXgr14mVL@KL1YfUM7oDnXd6/aXt6eQpWpsid/YLQCKicj4ee/kroe9r4m7KjQBxZzR1H2bj8PmYNQdLqKuJoWmN1OvT3q6@Mq5q/T9sB7P70DflM0CF0t3JpLesdulpj@6/fGzdRjMXJTWVh/Hz@KLT8e3vvDs5t3bRtcDKDb281O4/8w3G@/1jW6X3lty@Qf7t7D6dn0rG3K7w67SyqCw/pHfifZys/7NzOPkbHJ6ZewudtqIbPvClVA5c/GyltwrnC75jx/nfVD5eunXyt5EYtwV2/F/h7eax4W37PXkylOgs9iGXLyb@zhJ1GKbE@XxsbUUxD3x0V9YPj7KZqvzaajae95EYKmxE6m5qtXDt@AG1KY92NjJTjT3CZHp4STOfTkWc@1c3c9vzb3PvHkPJ1cm3KmLdmYQ/5pt9Lex5yu7nx5dK7AdqKu9yNGsvzrvu/K03ONFnGbV5z/6g82DzMb6@8TbcnsptvDt2567ea/tN7vJ1d3xTiUagYLw0b85e8W97weWoCTHz4DPAMZ5PC/lp/3Vn@Xvs8V88@RorntdnS9fpVrulYTr9tR/EqnlsqFgcB1o3NtZOx47XvA1G/16L9js7u2tXLgq0e@FO1@/2Otl86ue8vLlYqs1gHzda9wc5bA2XbmgehTX7053jt9yuexBKH2VSsFpSHhO3ZHaR@4deOTFRWplb7mb9w@it83wzHR6qpqaAC7mWlr8vv/6PAm9T2fXJo8nHlPt0sKD7262OX0zVfNU3eWxy5/Sd/HzrJ/vHb/mXg6fMhupVOseV/d/bR/l/vknOdn@v@5r9aUHrcF/AA)

Comment: What assembler did you use?

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
ṫ4;“'ṫṗḶ/÷!Ṗ»⁾Hi;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9qZWxsef//4bmrNDvigJwn4bmr4bmX4bi2L8O3IeG5lsK74oG@SGk7////SSdtIGEgU3RhY2stb3ZlcmZsb3ctZXI)

A monadic link taking the input as its argument and returning a Jelly string.

#### Explanation

```
ṫ4                | everything from 4th character on
  ;“'ṫṗḶ/÷!Ṗ»     | concatenate ", I’m Jelly!" to the end
             ⁾Hi; | concatenate "Hi" to the beginning
```

Comment: Hang on, Jelly has a built-in just for the word "Jelly"?

Comment: @connectyourcharger it’s a compressed dictionary word

Comment: Ah, that makes sense

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>30 28</s> 27 bytes

```perl6
{S/.../Hi/~", I'm Perl 6!"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcqxDsIgFIXhvU9x7FA1Udi6uetm4hOQCHiTAvVCY7Cpr46KcfvynzNqHvriMjqDQ5kvUgghjyRf7Q6ntcP5s6NftUsxgbEZyOu4xdwAUWWIzjRL@f4URg6WlXOam1@4TzomCn7/YEr/6tSTvK1OxPpadZu85VxpVHoD)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
x=>`Hi${x.slice(3)}, I'm JavaScript!`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/wtYuwSNTpbpCrzgnMzlVw1izVkfBUz1XwQuoMhisUjHhf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGEkg@MTexKjMvXUlT8z8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```
|x:&str|print!("Hi{}, I'm Rust!",&x[3..])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZzZWTWqKQpmCr8L@mwkqtuKSopqAoM69EUUPJI7O6VkfBUz1XIQioRVFJR60i2lhPL1bzvzVXmoaaEkgmozQvvahSSdOaq/Y/AA)

Answer (score 4):

### VBA (Excel), 27 <s>28</s> bytes

```vb
?"Hi"Mid([A1],4)", I'm VBA!
```

Input goes in cell A1 of the Active Sheet in Excel, run code in the Immediate Window

Takes advantage of the fact that `"SomeString"SomeValue` and `SomeValue"SomeString"` will implicitly concatenate, and that omitting the third argument from the `MID` function will take all characters from the end of the input - turning it into a "dump initial characters" function

(-1 byte thanks to Shaggy, but +1 when OP confirmed that all answers should end with an exclamation mark)
(-1 byte thanks to Taylor Scott reminding me that the final double-quote was optional)

Comment: Could you remove the space after `Hi` and replace `5` with `4`?

Comment: @Shaggy ...  Yes, yes I could.  No idea how I missed that, thank you

Comment: You can drop a byte by removing the very last `"` from this solution, and as you use evaluate notation (the square brackets) you should mark this solution as being Excel VBA, as that notation is only available in Excel

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 22 + 3 = 25 bytes

```
@echo Hi %*, %0 Batch!
```

+3 bytes for naming this file `I'm` (with the required `.bat` extension for Batch files). Invoke as `I'm hungry`, when it will echo `Hi hungry, I'm Batch!`.

Comment: program should receive `I'm` but here it's the name of the script don't know if it's valid, or unless it's the interpreter with the script in current path

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul The interpreter is `CMD`, so would that actually save me 2 bytes?

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>16</s>  15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḋa⁾Hi“'ṫṗḶ/÷!Ṗ»
```

A full program accepting a (Python formatted) string argument which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9qZWxsef//4biKYeKBvkhp4oCcJ@G5q@G5l@G4ti/DtyHhuZbCu////0knbSBhIHByb2dyYW1tZXI)**

#### How?

```
Ḋa⁾Hi“'ṫṗḶ/÷!Ṗ» - Link: list of characters    e.g. "I'm a programmer"
Ḋ               - dequeue                          "'m a programmer"
  ⁾Hi           - pair of characters               "Hi"
 a              - logical AND (vectorises)         "Hi a programmer"
     “'ṫṗḶ/÷!Ṗ» - list of characters               ", I'm Jelly!"
                -  - since this is a new leading constant chain the previous result
                -    is implicitly printed (with no trailing newline)
                - program result is implicitly printed (again with no trailing newline)
```

Note: `Ḋ⁾Hio...` works too.

Answer (score 4):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>28</strike> 25 bytes

```
$1="Hi",$0=$0", I'm AWK!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxdBWySNTSUfFwFbFQElHwVM9V8Ex3FtR6f9/EDNRoaAoP70oMTc3tQgA)

This program modifies the contents of field "$1" and "$0" in a range pattern. Because no actions are specified after the pattern, the default action `{print $0}` is executed.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

```
', I''m J!',~'Hi',3}.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1XUUPNXVcxW8FNV16tQ9MtV1jGv1Yv9rcqUmZ@QrpCmog2UTcxOrMvPS1VFFSzKLUlPQxBIVCory04sSc3NTi9T/AwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>23</s> 21 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*

```
',«#À„Hiš"05AB1E!"ªðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9vc2FiaWX//ycswqsjw4DigJ5IacWhIjA1QUIxRSEiwqrDsMO9//9JJ20gYSBwcm9ncmFtbWVy)

**Explanation**

```
',«                    # append ","
   #                   # split on spaces
    À                  # rotate left
     „Hiš              # prepend "Hi"
         "05AB1E!"ª    # append the language name
                   ðý  # join on spaces
```

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9vc2FiaWX//ycswqsjw4DigJ5IacWhIjA1QUIxRSEiwqrDsMO9//9JJ20gYSBwcm9ncmFtbWVy). And too bad the exclamation mark is there.. Since `•äƵí•hR` is 1 byte shorter than `"05AB1E"`. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Wow! I feel stupid that I didn't start with the ",". Yeah I tried `•äƵí•hR` as well, but as you say, it unfortunately doesn't save any here.

Comment: [Beat you by a byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219340/94066).

Answer (score 3):

## bash, 24 bytes

```
echo Hi ${@:2}, $1 bash!
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##DcsxCoAgGAbQq3yB0JJDjbU01hmkQfMnBc3QoCE7uzm@4SmZTHmMdYRIUsMhZwgB5rBtkw5IdIPz6kK7CVgs2DuPw9eB9VB1N0WHk8raekhcMRxRek/xBw)

Comment: replace `bash` with `$0` to save a couple of bytes

Comment: @roblogic, `$0` would print script name or running `bash -c 'echo Hi ${@:2}, $1 $0!' bash $@` but should count in size

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
^...
Hi
$
, I'm Retina!
```

-1 byte thanks to *@attinat*.
-2 bytes by porting [*@Adám*'s QuadR answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185912/52210), so make sure to upvote him!!

PS: [*@Neil* posted a shorter Retina answer in the new version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185914/52210), so I've changed this answer to Retina 0.8.2 explicitly.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP05PT4/LI5NLhUtHwVM9VyEILKf4/z@Ik5ibWJWZl84FYpdkFqWmgFkZpXnpRZVgZqJCQVF@elFibm5qEVSgsDS1uCQzP0@3vCizBC4aXJKYnK3rX5ZalJaTX66bWgQA)

**Explanation:**

Replace the first three characters with "Hi":

```
^...
Hi
```

And then append a trailing ", I'm Retina!" (by replacing the end of the string):

```
$
, I'm Retina!
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be like [this](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9P215DQU9bk8sjU8VQR8FTPVchCCyv@P8/iJOYm1iVmZfOBWKXZBalpoBZGaV56UWVYGaiQkFRfnpRYm5uahFUoLA0tbgkMz9Pt7woswQuGlySmJyt61@WWpSWk1@um1oEAA) instead?

Comment: or better, [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9PT09DT1uTyyNTxVBHwVM9VyEILK34/z@Ik5ibWJWZl84FYpdkFqWmgFkZpXnpRZVgZqJCQVF@elFibm5qEVSgsDS1uCQzP0@3vCizBC4aXJKYnK3rX5ZalJaTX66bWgQA)

Comment: @attinat Ah, of course, hadn't even noticed the incorrect output.. >.> And thanks for the -1!

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript (Node.js in TIO), 60 bytes

```
s=>"Hi"+s.slice(3)+", I'm J"+process.argv[0].slice(6,15)+"!"
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##LctBCoMwEADAr9i9mBANFqk3e65@QTyEbdRIdENW/H5qwfvMak7DGF04yp2@Nk1t4vYNHweKNXuHVtRSQZF1@Zb1oEIktMzaxPkcqvEmTfF8XeoBCWln8lZ7msUk4L@YwkIbRYcgZfoB)

Comment: `javascript` is shorter than `"+process.argv[0].slice(5,15)+"`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul yes, but `+process.argv[0].slice(5,15)+` is more fun ;-)

Comment: The consensus on language names is that we must use proper casing - `JavaScript`, not `javascript`.

Comment: @Shaggy, point taken.

Answer (score 3):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 22 bytes

```apl
^...
$
Hi
, I'm QuadR!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PchBCsIwEEbhfU4RQXBjco66EnUvDHYaB01ifycWe/log7h6H28s1KPWs/ferE0nZmt3m2gP331c1bqYIs2SglmsAu6briUFvBsH0layD@QAipHxG2Php0pOboLo/56ULje3fzGGe54c4wM)

This replaces:

`^...` three initial characters
and
`$` the end-of-line

with

`Hi`
and
`,I'm QuadR`
respectively

Comment: So you could exchange the middle two lines and change the language to Retina and still beat @KevinCruijssen's answer?

Comment: @Neil I guess so, but your's is still shorter. Tbf, QuadR is but a thin cover for the not-intended-for-golf `⎕R` APL operator.

Comment: Ah, but my answer only works for Retina 1, not Retina 0.8.2 though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
3L$`
Hi$', $` Retina!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8N/YRyWByyNTRV1HQSVBIQgspfj/v6d6rkJibmJVZl46F4hdklmUmgJmZZTmpRdVgpmJCgVF@elFibm5qUVQgcLS1OKSzPw83fKizBK4aHBJYnK2rn9ZalFaTn65bmoRAA) Link includes test cases. Does not work in Retina 0.8.2, so adapt @Adám's QuadR answer instead. Explanation: The pattern is empty, so it matches at every position in the input string. We only need the third (or fourth would work) match however. The substitution is then applied to that match. Within that substitution, `$'` refers to the rest of the string and `` $` `` refers the the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 3):

## [VSL](https://github.com/vsl-lang/VSL), 51 bytes

```swift
fn f(s:String){print("Hi "+s[from:4]+", I'm VSL!")}
```

Glad VSL can now participate in some golfs :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyvO@f8/LU8hTaPYKrikKDMvXbO6AEiVaCh5ZCooaRdHpxXl51qZxGor6Sh4qucqhAX7KCpp1v5PK81LVshNzMzT0FSo5lIAApARCkogNYm5iVVAk5Q00cRLMotSU4Citf8B) (doesn't have latest VSL so might not work just yet)

Comment: Are you doing much with Teascript these days? It was a cool project,..

Comment: @roblogic unfortunately not anymore. I ended up adding most of its better features (unicode shortcuts, compression) to Japt so now that's generally always the better choice

Answer (score 3):

## [Ed](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html), 30 bytes

I couldn't leave a [`sed` answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185917/41769) without an `ed` answer!

```
%s/I'm\(.*\)/Hi\1, I'm ed!
wq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S035/1@1WN9TPTdGQ08rRlPfIzPGUEcByFdITVHkKi/k@v8fxPFKTUvj@pdfUJKZn1f8X7cYAA)

Comment: I prepended a “#” to your post's first line to turn it into heading, so the [Leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17600/introducing-the-new-ppcg-leaderboard-widget) script be able to parse it and list it. Funny choice for the link, though I'm sure some readers would be happier with something more informative.

Comment: Thank you, manatwork. https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/ would be a reasonable place to go to learn more about `ed`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
f x="Hi"++drop 3x++", I'm Haskell"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwlbJI1NJWzulKL9AwbhCW1tJwVM9V8EDokLpf25iZp6CrUJmXklqUWJyiULaf5C0TWJKVmpySWZZqh0A)

Comment: The comma is required

Answer (score 3):

## Knight, 24 bytes

```hs
O++'Hi 'P", I'm Knight!"
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyJPKysnSGkgJ1BcIiwgSSdtIEtuaWdodCFcIiIsIlNjb3R0Il0=)

Comment: The input is supposed to be in the form `I'm <something>`, not just the word. You have to do something like `O++'Hi 'G=pP4Lp", I'm Knight!"` instead.

Comment: @AidenChow You can use `3` instead of `4` and omit the space after `Hi`.

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan True! (filler)

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 32 Bytes

```
read i;echo Hi${i:3}, I\'m Bash!
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyg1MUUh0zo1OSNfwSNTpTrTyrhWR8EzRj1XwQmoQPH/f08gMzE3sSozLx0A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 39 bytes

```
func[s][rejoin["Hi"at s 4", I'm Red!"]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYoxDsJADAR7XmHc0FBS8QJoaS0XVs5OjBQH@S4FfP4IKN3M7KaW/tBCfLArdFtjoMqU@lw8CG@O0qDCBc9wP82wPY/I3G1JlWHaFsJfl1k@HiPC35qnlp2nNcZ872LSkIFe6dHAoHL/Ag)

Comment: I think `Red[]rejoin["Hi"at read 4", I'm Red!"]` is a valid 38-byte full program.

Comment: @Wezl  I think `read` expects exactly one argument - `Reads from a file, URL, or other port`, in your case it would be `4`.

Comment: oh, but is there a shorter function that would work?

Comment: @Wezl Maybe `ìnput`, but it works only within the GUI console.

Comment: ok never mind, sorry.

Comment: @Wezl No problem!

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 43 bytes

```
"Hi"<>#~StringDrop~3<>", I'm Mathematica!"&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYuxDoIwFEV3vgJLgguNgys2DA46GE0YjcMLtqXBUnw@JGrk1yvGENzuufdcC1RKC2QK8Grl2cawVER9TmhqvUbX9MtUsCTczm24m9wZi/1hUOgYcaGy6BQvslfAvhZYeA5flvyQDMrzCGVba3yMpIDGCGGDTiNYK3Hqrq28kXE179DQ/5ATFBXf3yWqi@v4MAVv/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 45 bytes

```
"iH",,~~~>~# :1+#,_0"!39-egnufeB m'I ,">:#,_@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/XynTQ0lHp66uzq5OWcHKUFtZJ95ASdHYUjc1Pa80LdVJIVfdU0FHyc4KKOHw/7@neq5CYWlqcUlmfl5mXrpCTmZaqkJyRn5mcmoxAA)

Dissected:

```
"iH",,                                           Push then output constant "Hi"
      ~~~                                        Read "I'm" from output, which gets unused
         >~# :1+#,_                              Non-wrapping cat program
                   0"!39-egnufeB m'I ,"          Push null-terminated constant string to stack
                                       >:#,_@    Output string and exit
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 49 bytes

+3 Bytes: was not working
-3 Bytes: K&R style function.  thanks JohanduToit

This is similar to the answer from [Neil A.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185878/85341) but 
takes the input as commandline arguments instead of a function parameter.

```c
main(b,a)char**a;{printf("Hi%s, I'm C!",a[1]+3);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI0knUTM5I7FISyvRurqgKDOvJE1DySNTtVhHwVM9V8FZUUknMdowVttY07r2////ILGA1JLUon/JaTmJ6cX/dcsB)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>42</s> <s>41</s> <s>40</s> 37 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Spitemaster</sup>

```powershell
"Hi$($args|% s*g 3), I'm PowerShell!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V/JI1NFQyWxKL24RlWhWCtdwVhTR8FTPVchAKQwGKRQUel/LReXmkqaghJIwhEElJAEXBJTkLkIjUr/AQ)

There might be a cheaper automatic variable holding the PowerShell version hiding somewhere but I'm not sure. Answer takes the `s`ubstrin`g` after `I'm` to the end and builds a string with it.

Comment: You could save a byte by only skipping 3 characters and outputting `"Hi$_\`, I'm PowerShell!"`

Comment: @Spitemaster Oh yeah, I guess I could. Thanks

Comment: @Veskah You can output the working directory with `$pshome` but that prints something like `/opt/microsoft/powershell/6`

Comment: You could use the -f formatting operator for 33 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8kjU6HasFZHodqgViElMUVPSTdNJbEovVgvuCAns0RD8z9Qjad6rkJGaV56UaUSAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @GabrielMills [Breaks for multiple words](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8kjU6HasFZHodqgViElMUVPSTdNJbEovVgvuCAns0RD8z9Qjad6rkKiQlJmiUJSaXp6pRIA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Veskah ah, I hadn't caught that. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 44 bytes

```sql
SELECT STUFF(v,1,3,'Hi')+', I''m SQL!'FROM t
```

Input is taken via pre-existing table **t** with text field **v**, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

`STUFF` is shorter than variations using `SUBSTRING` or `RIGHT`.

Can handle multiple inputs (as separate rows in **t**), although that's not required.

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
ｊｊｊHiŗ, I'm Canvas!
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjRBJXVGRjRBJXVGRjRBSGkldTAxNTclMkMlMjBJJTI3bSUyMENhbnZhcyUyMQ__,i=SSUyN20lMjBhJTIwcHJvZ3JhbQ__,v=8)

[18 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=SGkldTIwNzgldUZGMzMldTI1MjQlMkMldUZGMEIldUZGMUJDYW52YXMlMjEldUZGMDklMjAldUZGMEE_,i=SSUyN20lMjBzaG9ydGVy,v=8) only handling single letter names

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 55 bytes

```
	INPUT "I'M" REM . X
	OUTPUT ="HI" X ", I'M SNOBOL"
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9PTLyA0REHJU91XSSHI1VdBTyGCi9M/NAQkaqvk4amkEKGgpKMAlFcI9vN38vdR4nL1c/n/HyTgEernHhQJAA)

Comment: [53 bytes.](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9PTLyA0REHJV0khyNVXQU8hgovTPzQEJGar5OGppBChoKSj4KnuqxDs5@/k76PE5ern8v8/SMDXI9TPPSgSAA "SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## GFortran, 73 bytes

As usual, Fortran string handling is clunky and annoying!

[try it online](https://tio.run/##Jcw9DoAgDEDh3VPgVDB1c0EnF39mTkAEtYmiqb0/mri9fMNbLxb2qd7WP3Jeds9@kcjaWuM6jj6A7g2gK26mJBXCRIDCdGqnm9YYBFQzwKnG4Z@UUMQUcqbPjuuhtCmSFw)

```fortran
character(99)S;read'(A)',S
print*,'Hi',trim(S(4:)),', I''m GFortran!'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 53 bytes

```powershell
Filter f{$_-replace"(...)(.*)",'Hi$2, $1 PowerShell'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RCoJAEEV/ZVg2tHAX6jV6jXoq8ANksVGXdl0b16TMbzcNi97OvXcYTuVapLpAY0TqCAfusfY17IAdAwvKqqcucxZ9kteEl5mLpszpMYdM@ZkUVORyUtYi/apbM/7UrhQtaf/Xx16lV3G6I2XGtWJctsNem/EEso4ngrAyKkUWSimXoVwtWRQcNN9EwNdwnsTjSTzov9YvWEAHPBkhg354Aw)

Probably could do more improvement on the regex.  Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

## Sinclair ZX80 BASIC, 92 tokenized BASIC bytes

As the Sinclair ZX80 character set only allows for upper-case and 'inversed' characters, and doesn't include a single-quote, `shifted-E` is substituted here. There is no exclamation mark in the ZX80 character set either - [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX80_character_set).

```
 1 INPUT A$
 2 FOR I=0 TO 2
 3 LET A$=TL$(A$)
 4 NEXT I
 5 PRINT "HI";A$;","
 6 PRINT "I'M SINCLAIR ZX80 BASIC"
```

How it works:

Line 1 takes the input as a string value to `A$`;
Line 2 - 4 creates a loop to remove the first three characters of the entered value;
Line 5 - 6 then outputs the ultimate Dad joke.

[image: ZX80 Dad Joke answer]

Comment: Can you replace print with a question mark?

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 122 bytes

```
2a2x1v7a8m1o3d4m9a1o3d3s1o1x1f5r3x1v2e1o1f0x1x2f0a0x1f0m9a2a4m1o9s3s1o2m9a1o2d3a1o3m8s1o3d4s1o3m9a5a1o9s4s1o9a9a7a1o3d7s1o
```

Uses a lot of arithmetic instructions to set the register to each of the character values in the dad-joke format.

Works for any input file terminated with the control character STX (U+0002).

**Explanation** (with `0x` instructions removed)

```
2a2x1v           # Set variable 1 equal to 2
7a8m1o           # Output "H"
3d4m9a1o         # Output "i"
3d3s1o           # Output a space
1x1f5r3x1v2e1o1f # Function 1
                 # Read the 5th byte of input, then remove it from the input
                 # This has the effect of skipping over the self-descriptor's "I'm "
                 # Jump to function 2 if the value of the byte is equal to variable 1
                 # Otherwise, output the byte and jump back to the start of function 1
1x2f0a           # Function 2
                 # Add 0 to the register
1f               # Call function 1
0m9a2a4m1o       # Output ","
9s3s1o           # Output a space
2m9a1o           # Output "I"
2d3a1o           # Output an apostrophe (')
3m8s1o           # Output "m"
3d4s1o           # Output a space
3m9a5a1o         # Output "n"
9s4s1o           # Output "a"
9a9a7a1o         # Output "z"
3d7s1o           # Output "!"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 21 bytes

```
["Hi"a@>3k"I'm Pip!"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/WskjUynRwc44W8lTPVchILNAUSn2////IE5GaV56USUA)

#### Explanation

Constructs a list containing:

- Literal string `"Hi"`
- The input, minus its first three characters (`a@>3`)
- A string containing a comma and a space (which happens to be the initial value of the variable `k`)
- Literal string `"I'm Pip!"`

By default, lists are concatenated together when they are output.

Alternately, we can reuse the `I'm` from the input for a different 21-byte solution:

```
["Hi"a@>3ka@<4"Pip!"]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-c`, 21 bytes

```sh
<<<"Hi${1:3}, I'm $0"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@G@XZmOj7qr@38bGRskjU6Xa0Mq4VkfBUz1XQcVA6b8rV1VxhoJusoKSioZNmqaSgorD//8gyaT8otQUAA) (includes wrapper script to run with `-c`)

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 36 bytes

```scala
{case s"$a $b"=>s"Hi $b, $a Scala!"}
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Vux1i8QkRwuKKp7DWEUrgQ)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript/Python (polyglot), <strike><sup>149</sup></strike> 141 bytes

```
a=1//2;import sys
eval(["print('Hi'+sys.argv[1][3:]+', I\\'m Python!')","console.log('Hi'+process.argv[2].slice(3)+`, I'm JavaScript!`)"][a])
```

### Example input (First arg)

```
I'm bored
```

### JavaScript output ([Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##Lc5PC4MgHMbx@15FeTGpFdVtY/dtp8GOJuRMmsP8iUrQq3fuz/V5@MD3xVfuhVM27A1MMkZ@apumO6rFgguZ3/xOrlwXFFmnTCjwWeEyrTV380pbRvsDK3GVXYYBL9ltC08wOSaoQgKMBy1rDfNPWQdC@r/sWO21ErLoSTkmnvA1pdy/KflIEKOckRjj53mAk9Mb))

```
Hi bored, I'm JavaScript!
```

### Python output ([Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##LcxPC4MgHMbx@16FeTExjOq2sfu202BHE3JOSrB@ohL06l37c32@fB6/pQmWLmd1buq6PdnZQ0gobvFgVuVKgX2wSyrJxRK2r1yFcRWNFN1RMlKha9@TGd2/LwWhuMIalgjOcAfjT/kA2sS/bCWPzmpTdpQNO9/xTa3qoYP1qRgolkJJmnP@lCcE83oD))

```
Hi bored, I'm Python!
```

### Explanation

- `a=1//2;import sys`:

  - What Python see: `a=1//2`= `0` (integer division/no-reminder), `;import sys`
  - What JavaScript see: `a=1` (the rest commented)
- `["print('Hi'+s`[...]`","console.log(`[...]`"]`: Array with the code in Python, and the code in JavaScript respectively.
- `[a]`: Select the index of it (Python:0', JavaScript:1)

Answer (score 2):

## [APOL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/APOL), 32 bytes

`+("Hi " +(V(i 4) ", I'm APOL!"))`

Answer (score 2):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 44 bytes

```bash
a:
I'm=>Hi
*=>\,\ I'm\ Lexurgy\!/_ $//_ $$
```

Ungolfed explanation:

```bash
a:
I'm => Hi               # Swap "I'm" to "Hi"
* => \,\ I'm\ Lexurgy\! # the tack on the joke...
         / _ $          # when at the end of a word...
              // _ $$   # but not in between words.
```

Comment: [lexurgy interpreter thing](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc) (copy paste code)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 33 bytes

```cs
n=>$"Hi{n.Substring(3)}, I'm C#!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BCoJAFEXX@RWjBc2AI0RL000QCUGRi9bT@NRBHes5JhV9u6XV6h4O3Htlw2Wj@k2r5aoxqHTmfiNMg14H4czZqqf24vb81XTJXi6J5hVZT22n960uVyXQSHsHgIIyYgeEL5g1OaEysFMaaEqPIJIRGWN@P5RFJR6fNWtgoxCSkfJWZ3gfMRVmTEEuWGcoqgrwJ64tNEbVmnfDxd/GRsiC72@AaVl3HPAN)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, <s>31</s> 21 bytes

10 bytes saved by taking on board Adam's comments. Thanks.

```
"Hi",3↓⎕,", I'm APL!"
```

Prompts for input string.

[Try it online! Courtesy of dzaima/APL](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/qHfeo7YJGv@VPDKVdIwftU0GCugo6Sh4qucqOAb4KCr91/wPYicqFBTlpxcl5uamFgEA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 21 bytes

```
{"Hi",3_x,", I'm K!"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlrJI1NJxzi@QkdJR8FTPVfBW1Gp9n@aghKInZibWJWZl670HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```
s=>"Hi"&s[3..s.len]&", I'm Nim!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/Z@ZW5BfVKJQXJqeWMTFVVCUn6xQklpcopFmpVBcUpSZl66gawdlaSrYcikAQWpyRr5CmoKSp3quQkZpXnpRpRIXF1jTf4ViWzslj0wlteJoYz29Yr2c1LxYNSUdBZBSv8xcRaX/mv8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 52 bytes

```
procedure d(s);return"Hi"||s[4:0]||", I'm Icon!";end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSFFo1jTuii1pLQoT8kjU6mmpjjaxMogtqZGSUfBUz1XwROoXlHJOjUvBUlTbmJmnoYmlwIQlBdllqRqpGgogRQn5iZWZealK2lqcoE0AAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haxe](https://haxe.org/), <s>57</s> 54 bytes

```
function(x:String)return'Hi${x.substr(3)}, I\'m Haxe!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc0xC8IwEIbhOf0VZxGagLi4Ke7t4OTqcoakDdgIl4tESn57vMX1e@B7Fyyu2RemBDcMEbZOJUYOFnyOlsM7wiq7NgLqgwQeru1PupzvTCHOhhxnisMY9ls5pvxMTPpk6gGmx7DCKJHd0JS6yAkTWqe97ieRJceZvr0xIrWr7Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
Hi✂Ｓ³Ｐ, I'm Charcoal!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJI1NJ05oLwgnOyUxO1fDMKygtCS4BiqRraOooGGsC5X1Lc0oyCyA6dBQ81XMVnKEGKQK1//8PEskozUsvquT6r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: `✂` is the `Slice` operator which normally takes four arguments, however the use of the `P` command to output the suffix allows Charcoal to deduce that the last two arguments were omitted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org), 36 bytes

```
#(str"Hi"(subs % 3)", I'm Clojure!")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <s>68</s> 59 bytes

```
function d(s)return(s:gsub("(I\'m)(.*)","Hi%2, %1 Lua"))end
```

Uses a pattern to swap in the I'm in the original and then returns the joke. Having chucks on a single line like this is [valid, but ugly](http://www.lua.org/pil/1.1.html).

Edit: More efficient use of gsub

Comment: Consider adding a short explanation to your answer. Code-only answers tend to get automatically flagged as low quality.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks; I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## **[Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 34 bytes**

```
"Hi${i.substring(3)}, I'm Kotlin!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYyxDoIwEIZ3nqI2JraJuLiROLhpHBx4gioFL9KrlqsECc9eC67ijd/3/Xe3VAOG0iMzClBI1ics3ggKAVlODrCS2R47tgv8AMseNo2/NBMXWzms2XFl2Gn6s@BhHD@ioxpFIfjolFHvGHMpkx@WwOlixt08Vq6bkSoCWzlljHazydPrhsBi2jqgP11O6npPzy/tytq26bccwgc)

## **[Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 26 bytes**

Is this a loop hole ?

```
"Hi${i.s(3)}, I'm Kotlin!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY2xDoIwEIZ3n6I2JraJuLiRMLhJHBx4gioFL9CrliJBwrPXQhMHE7zp7r7vv6u0rQFd0SJRApBxMqyIr2mRWQNY7hsGcYqWx2EmCWnaazP3DPjXzr0WDB4fsSeJoyfYDODzBz7uSLpV5Dx/W1M3hR7etTWynNGJCSXePkx5OPlDLRiZL7B7i6XpF6DwC10aoZQ0i8qzlY0FjVFnwP7xMituVXR5SVPUuouCOboP)

The 26 is definitely a loophole else I can golf it to *5* bytes with:

```
i.k()
```

which is meaningless.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYyxDoIwFEV3vqISE9tEXNxIHNw0Dg58QZWCL9BXLa0ECd9eWzBO4ptezrn3VsrUgK6wSCQHpIz0EfEXQGY0YLmpKEunl@xIfIBl39hLMwK6ZcOaHFeSnMadRfwt5xQ@LZbusSM7B2HJBX/32NRIcxqHLpf85XMxY9EPa0CLfMbdLJa6m5HcA1VqLqXQs5GHFY0BhUmrwfzJZYZfq@T8FLqoVZtMycG9AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 40 bytes

```forth
: f 3 -3 d+ ." Hi"type ." , I'm Forth!";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY4xTwMxDIV3fsUjCwOEod2odCMqEwMrS8g5d4FeEhyH6vjzR3JSaQWWLFv@nv3sIsuoB9fKsjzAYQu9RX@Le4W9VzInau0dnm4mPDbZtdpVYcKmLwktN3UF5i2jY6x67pCTsZTbJnQHVe9axg6veC9ZYGNPkIjgLR1mJPZBICMhFklFrrJa7cxkvn0YVDW7jBMWz9T/hWc8ljDw/I@fsDPS2K9X/SIObKaJuM7P489CWXwM@sheVnZxxOBFjP3Qz1/E7hCPehUsPw)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                 \ start a new word definition
  3 -3 d+           \ add 3 to the starting address and subtract 3 from the string length
  ." Hi"type        \ output "Hi" followed by all but the first 3 characters of the input string      
  ." , I'm Forth!"; \ output ", I'm Forth!" and end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 31 bytes

```
^I'm/Hi/[^!]$/$0, I'm ReRegex!/
```

This assumes input doesn't end on `!`.

[**TIO**](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/P85TPVffI1M/Ok4xVkVfxUBHASigEJQaBJJW1OcC8RIVCory04sSc3NTi/7/BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 30 bytes

```julia
s->"Hi$(s[4:end]), I'm Julia!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZpuUmp6Z979Y107JI1NFozjaxCo1LyVWU0fBUz1XwQukTFHpP1CIy6E4I79cIU1DCSRRklmUmqKk@R8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 37 bytes

```javascript
s=>`Hi${s.slice(3)}, I'm JavaScript!`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/2NYuwSNTpbpYrzgnMzlVw1izVkfBUz1XwQuoMhisUjHhf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGEkg@UaE8NbMoJV9JU/P/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 21 bytes

`++"Hi">z3", I'm Pyth!`

Try it [here](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2B%22Hi%22%3Ez3%22%2C+I%27m+Pyth%21&input=I%27m+awesome&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## k, 21 bytes

```
,[;", I'm k!"]"Hi",3_
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 35 bytes

```
iiil2="Hi "$5*?S$' $", "$" Runic!"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z8zMzPHyFbJI1NBScVUyz5YRV1BRUkHyFFSCAKpUFRy@P/fUz1XIaM0L72oEgA)

Spaces only need to be escaped if you want to use [an adjective or noun-phrase](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z8zMzPHyFbJI1NBScVUyz5YRV1BRUkHyFFSCAKpUFRy@P/fUz1XIT8vNUYhozQvvagyRiE3MQ8A) as your `<I'm!>`. Runic splits input on spaces and newlines and as the challenge specified input as either `an <adj>` or `<noun>` as single word tokens, I used this feature to avoid parsing and splitting input with code.

Comment: Nice one! Runic is a new language to me.

Comment: @connectyourcharger Its my own esolang. I did some interesting things with it (such as utilizing unicode combining characters to perform different behavior), though I want to rebuild the language spec from the ground up, as there's a few failure points that I didn't anticipate.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 37 bytes

```
Fn.new{|x|"Hi%(x[3..-1]), I'm Wren!"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uqaiRskjU1WjItpYT0/XMFZTR8FTPVchHKhcUan2f3BlcUlqrl55UWZJqgZIq15yYk6OhhJIjUtiipKm5n8A)

## Explanation

```
Fn.new{|x|                          } // New anonymous function
          "Hi                         // The hi section
             %(x[3..-1])              // THe input sliced, without the "I'm"
                        , I'm Wren!"  // THe third part, the remaining of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

```
3.$”ŒÞÿ, I'm 05AB1E!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fWE/lUcPco5MOzzu8X0fBUz1XwcDU0cnQVfH/fxAnozQvvagSAA)

```
3.$”ŒÞÿ, I'm 05AB1E!  # full program
   ”ŒÞÿ, I'm 05AB1E!  # "Hiÿ, I'm 05AB1E!"...
                      # (implicit) with ÿ replaced by...
                      # implicit input...
 .$                   # excluding the first...
3                     # literal...
 .$                   # chars
                      # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```
echo "Hi",stdin.readAll[3..^1],", I'm Nim!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/NTkjX0HJI1NJp7gkJTNPryg1McUxJyfaWE8vzjBWR0lHwVM9V8EvM1dR6f9/ELMkI1UhKbW4RCE5PyVVIT0/Jy21SCG1LLUIAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, 16 bytes

```
3ȯ‛Hi$`, I'm ₴ŀ!
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=%E1%B9%AA&code=3%C8%AF%E2%80%9BHi%24%60%2C%20I%27m%20%E2%82%B4%C5%80!&inputs=I%27m%20Dad&header=&footer=)

I'm assuming I don't need to include the flag, since the ruby answer doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5 (`-p`), 26 bytes

```
s/I'm(.*)/Hi$1, I'm Perl!/
```

No deep magic, just a straight regex substitution

Answer (score 1):

## [FerNANDo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FerNANDo), 381 bytes

Outputting language name as `ferNANDo`, as in esolang page title.

```
0 A S D F G H J K
0 Q W E R T Y U I
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
? a b c d e f g h
?
a b c d e f g h
? a b c d e f g h
?
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
A S D F G H J K
Q W E R T Y U I
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZA7DsIwEET7PcXraNcniJD4BSp@QpSBOFCQgKDi9EZyMDgOyNKuZtY7nnFl703RlFfnlCFrRkyYMmPOQpQlO8as2LBnSy4GxRBVUd9DVfnOPSsZBQeOlFgqTpwlkx7z407QbNVUojc8Tr2mTvs@u/sf5bZ3cMgVMVFO08H6zvl/bpJ/8SfxY5zLBzWPi7W35ws)

### How it works

```
# accepts I
0 A S D F G H J K
# accepts '
0 Q W E R T Y U I
# accepts m
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
# outputs H
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
# outputs i
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
# cat begins
? a b c d e f g h
?
a b c d e f g h
? a b c d e f g h
?
# cat ends
# outputs rest
# characters .
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
A S D F G H J K
Q W E R T Y U I
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 21 bytes

```
"Hi\(.[3:]), I'm jq!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/1/JIzNGQy/a2CpWU0fBUz1XIatQUQkoDGIm5iZWZealK3GBeSWZRakpUHZGaV56USWUk5ZYAmUlKhQU5acXJebmphbBhQpLU4tLMvPzdMuLMkuQxINLEpOzdf3LUovScvLLdYEyAA)

Answer (score 1):

## nroff, 34 bytes

Using a hack NOT to quote the input with quotation marks for usage to split an argument into words.

```
.de x
.shift
Hi \\$* I'm nroff!
..
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GavKL8tDQbG3VXPxf1paUlaboWN5X0UlIVKrj0ijMy00q4PDIVYmJUtBQ81XMVwIoVufT0oCqN9SrA4okKBUX56UWJubmpRVxcUMGSzKLUFDgvKR_EA9oC0bpgAYQGAA)

### Usage examples

```
.x I'm a programmer

.x I'm tired

.x I'm bored
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 15 bytes

```
3ȯ`HiΠ, I'm ₴ŀ!
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIzyK9gSGnOoCwgSSdtIOKCtMWAISIsIiIsIkknbSBmYXQiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 16.5 bytes

```
"Hi "`>4@", "$"Nibbles!"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWO5Q8MhWUEuxMHJR0FJRUlPwg0opKEGmoqgU30z3VcxUScxOrMvPSuUDsksyi1BQwK6M0L72oEsxMSywB04kKBUX56UWJubmpRVCBwtLU4pLM_Dzd8qLMErhocElicrauf1lqUVpOfrluahHEPgA)

### Explanation

```
"Hi "`>4@", "$"Nibbles!"
"Hi "                    Output "Hi "
     `>                  Drop the first
       4                  4 characters
        @                 from input
     `>                   and remember them
         ", "            Output ", "
             $           Output the remembered string
              "Nibbles!" Output "Nibbles!"
```

Comment: Finally I understand what "drop ( `> also take)" means in the Quick Ref!

Answer (score 0):

## AutoHotkey, 43 bytes

```
s := "I'm tired"
MsgBox % "Hi"SubStr(s,4)", I'm AutoHotkey!"
```

Not sure what's considered an output in AutoHotkey and I guess input string is not counted, so in that case the second line is 43 bytes.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Do you really need spaces around the operators?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Note, though, that we don't allow input to be assigned to a pre-defined variable.

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```
f(s)=>"Hi${s.substring(3)}, I'm Dart!";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFBa8JAEIXv/oppELoLiQg9Bj21UE899BhymGo2LrqbOjtRVPLb02kaaSiNl2Hm8b3H7OwGidvWqKAXy@jVTq9hFuqPwGR9qZ50E8Pq0cGzUA9R2jq0XunrBOCIBFwEDrCATGaALPom0eFFrFEMknabhiF5PKDZUrHp2a4fJbe1L@ncoz/DKGuQe1C6UQrhk6qS0LmCbusOpDu@Qy0Pt5VPTmR5YP6j30lAeGdc75K3Y0FmX52S35R/LibWPJ1I7Q4@MxW94HqrFHc/AbK09ayM4myea52K1kht2i8)

- -1 bytes thanks to [Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink)

Comment: Use `substring(3)` to allow you to remove the space before it and save a byte.

Answer (score 0):

**AutoIt, 45**

```
Msgbox(0,0,"Hi "&$cmdLine[2]&", I'm AutoIt")
```

Grabs the second word from the command line and puts it in a popup. (Must be compiled to exe)

Comment: What happens if there's more than two words, such as with the test case for `I'm a programmer`? I don't have the language installed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), <s>20</s> 19 characters

```
<G>*=Hi*, $1 Gema\!
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ echo -n "I'm amazing" | gema '<G>*=Hi*, $1 Gema\!'
Hi amazing, I'm Gema!

bash-4.4$ echo -n "I'm a programmer" | gema '<G>*=Hi*, $1 Gema\!'
Hi a programmer, I'm Gema!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/38bdTsvWI1NLR0HFUMEdKBSj@P@/p3quQmJuYlVmXjoA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rexx (Regina)](http://www.rexx.org/), 35 bytes

```
say"Hi"substr(arg(1),4)", I'm Rexx"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0qtqPj/vzixUskjU6m4NKm4pEgjsShdw1BTx0RTSUfBUz1XIQioRun///8gdmJuYlVmXjoA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), 30 bytes

```
00000000: 56d8 8100 d3d0 80a0 5d20 8081 253c 5881  VØ..ÓÐ. ] ..%<X.
00000010: 01c8 69ac a0c9 a7ed a0c2 e5e1 ee21       .Èi¬ É§í Âåáî!
```

Original JavaScript:

```
`Hi${a.slice(3)}, I'm Bean!`
```

The program takes the first line of raw input implicitly in `a`, removing the first three characters, and outputs the template above using that string.

[Demo](https://patrickroberts.github.io/bean/#h=VtiBANPQgKBdIICBJTxYgQHIaaygyaftoMLl4e4h&i=SSdtIHRpcmVk)

---

### Test Suite

```
00000000: 53d0 80d3 d080 a078 2080 8840 a05d 56d8  SÐ.ÓÐ. x ..@ ]VØ
00000010: 8100 d3d0 80a0 5d20 8081 253c 5881 0120  ..ÓÐ. ] ..%<X.. 
00000020: 807b 2381 02c8 69ac a0c9 a7ed a0c2 e5e1  .{#..Èi¬ É§í Âåá
00000030: ee21 0a                                  î!.
```

Original JavaScript:

```
_.map(a=>`Hi${a.slice(3)}, I'm Bean!`).join('\n')
```

The test suite takes all the lines of raw input implicitly in `_`, applies the first program to each line using `map()`, then outputs each result per line.

[Demo](https://patrickroberts.github.io/bean/#h=U9CA09CAoHgggIhAoF1W2IEA09CAoF0ggIElPFiBASCAeyOBAshprKDJp+2gwuXh7iEK&i=SSdtIGFtYXppbmcKSSdtIHRpcmVkCkknbSBodW5ncnkKSSdtIGZhdApJJ20gYSBwcm9ncmFtbWVyCkknbSBhIHF1ZXN0aW9uLXdyaXRlcgpJJ20gYSBTdGFjay1PdmVyZmxvdy1lcg==)

Answer (score 0):

## [아희 (Aheui)](https://github.com/aheui/pyaheui), 319 bytes

```
밦밚따밬다발빠받밠따따빠따따밟밢밙다다다분
뭏떠벓벑떠떠벐벌벋떠떠벉더너벅번뻐떠뻐떠벊
맣＠섹뵗솬밯삭밧타뿌싿삳빠맣박밯빠싸주마붗
반밚따따두쪼＠썽선처손＠＠＠오섣멓서차소빠
성멓뻐섣멓＠＠＠＠＠＠희＠먛＠셔멓섣멓멓멓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7BSsNAFLznK3rz5If4GT0EzEHF2tKr1G2IJsWURhttxcUUUyXF54rFYKQfNK/4CXG3awvDY968ecM0D92OV9egZ9A9EgIVCGegKUoJmoCkETXKLaFH0BPoztgslsLB4hq3EmoENTTE8Bgqggq36yUGCUQA1YcK8B0b0U515SDPfivJosTnmP0C9Ma9BShfX5xjFXG44t6HqZBnoBt91ZzDL84q5AGWYweU/vfXGMb8Wpm4wQ8LySplP9arBaczFhleRiymTHP2I53lsHjXku5jbzv3DuuHQk/MJyain2z@jdOirg/2jhrNxmnHPWt7J8f73ZbXdlt/)

Prints `아희`(official Korean name of the language) instead of `Aheui`, so the code is quite long.

Answer (score 0):

## [Assembly (gcc, x64, Linux)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 315 bytes

```
h:.int 26952
s:.int 32
g:.asciz ", I'm GNU Assembler!\n"
.globl main
main:
mov %rdi, %r13
mov %rsi, %r14
lea h, %rdi
mov $0, %rax
call printf
mov $2, %r15
l:
lea s, %rdi
mov $0, %rax
call printf
mov (%r14, %r15, 8), %rdi
mov $0, %rax
call printf
inc %r15
cmp %r15, %r13
jg l
lea g, %rdi
mov $0, %rax
call printf
ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZAxD8IgEIV3fsXZaNQEG22tUTYn4@Lm5oIUKQZoA41R/zy20L0uL3l59927HHWO67v6rARj3lcklaaFbHcoMuSiyTMkSEodk19IMJznGk6XKxwjyO3kZhKUClXfFWgqDeqFIF2/YGZLiTvd5IN10W6R4hQqHAZCNF33hr4Ro0pBY7viRwyyQBRIkQC5f6BF3xE5DPvlGCINix1MNwMUbn4KUKFUjG2wvPXed6/x1LfS8tI3thaWas3tDw)

Ungolfed:

```
.section .bss

.section .data

hi:
.asciz  "Hi"

space:
.asciz  " "

imgnuasm:
.asciz  ", I'm GNU Assembler!\n"

badArgumentCount:
.asciz  "Requires at least two arguments\n"


.section .text
.globl main
main:

cmpq $3, %rdi # must have at least two arguments
jl .error

movq %rdi, %r13 # save argc
movq %rsi, %r14 # save argv

leaq hi, %rdi
movq $0, %rax   #%rax holds how many xmm regs to be used in x86-64
call printf

movq $2, %r15 # because (%r14, %r15(==0), 8) is the program path and (%r14, %r15(==1), 8) is "I'm"

.loopbegin:

  leaq space, %rdi
  movq $0, %rax
  call printf

  movq (%r14, %r15, 8), %rdi #(%r14, %r15, 8)
  movq $0, %rax
  call printf

  incq %r15
  cmp %r15, %r13
  jg .loopbegin


  leaq imgnuasm, %rdi
  movq $0, %rax
  call printf

  jmp .done

.error:
  leaq badArgumentCount, %rdi
  movq $0, %rax #%rax holds how many xmm regs to be used in x86-64
  call printf

.done:
  movq $0, %rax # return 0 (success)
  ret
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# .NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 94 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.Write($"Hi {a[0].Substring(4)}, I'm C#");}}
```

[Try Online](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS5O/v8/OSexuFghoLq4JLEkM1mhLD8zRcE3MTNPo7ikKDMvPTo2UbM6uLK4JDVXzzk/rzg/J1UvvCizJFVDRckjU6E6MdogVi@4NAmiWsNEs1ZHwVM9V8FZWUnTurb2////IF5JanEJAA)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure - 36 Bytes

`#(str"Hi "(subs %4)", I'm Clojure!")`

Trivial solution is trivial, probably has room for improvement

Answer (score 0):

## VBScript, 51 bytes

```
Msgbox "Hi "&Wscript.Arguments(1)&", I'm VBScript!"
```

Test like:

```
ScriptFile.vbs I'm tired
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 47 bytes

```
Input Str1
"Hi"+sub(Str1,4,length(Str1)-3)+", I'm TI-Basic!
```

Output is stored in `Ans` and displayed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem) (don't break loop when items are insufficient), <s>46</s> 38 bytes, filename only.

It's been a while. As usual, `\0001` is not such a string but a character 0x01.

```
.z.im.a_iH.w.i.c\0001.+.a.s!mexP m'I ,.v.p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pTp7X@LIsv/nU7QRhQwkAXRGR4yz6KDDGRWP4p3ZI05@MWkkCgmbDooP7lffW9WdN87snr3sypCuR1fXq6u682Sx0Z@rK/qN6@lsJEmrZDqnE21yH9LJVKOTG23qM3fusolGXE@1fYeSM8CAh5AG04DCtyatAt0htcJZQBk8EZUc@JOpFbo3Y0oe3XBEvHutzDiR51CHsCkdukPXBhTf4wT7TyFVZ54bEntkBZYNfPn4qU/YGIQknh8QbzYekyH8GLpj6lkTylEuwoBaE9UPXAr8HdLVe1yib4Ebwnzk5kkj/alFD63HZ@qhfIeuZ43JbOpYIdVIs95saPUtbaNBLvsH1Y@Iceza1GMAPADeoftAcUUT32PkPzTwyQMQaKitWxqSs95F9/v4ibAZKMRldEwZI9R7cAPfm4BIEgMklc6k2cRi96Re39oiq7CeEH42my1iMb4moXOJzqd@EJLjA7N9fGwcSOHTlOI0tu8NyZ7u0Aedq6G5t94g6@sCboNwlue8BY/4nbX7Xwy5VIkx1WnCFEGAnpAqpRccqu4sxA91IcdcLk@7382L/mejWa9vwCJQ7i9n6uX3ZBrUxfHv5kHv/Lxz0DcaEdLR6eWfq@Tssk9@712ek7PvnRNyAb8OOuRL57wjHXaPO6ftk45R1p41d6JZpvtFe9RczR7U6/WGVtUsja1M6PyMTMqDcrlLatqDNi1LB73Tfue0b0j467B7ZJSl/c5R9/RFIoRcXnTM/QOj3sKH/fNO@6t53Oudmd@@dE7N7unF5eFh96CL5AKlvd8775v7572vAEdMo5EZ7x4fd47ax0DY7xx1zpFmUYZV2SNq37vebeqV7hCpwBm8cEjW2GDgEbkUL1Emrwi9DeiUqH8QtUMG@AyfcuXH69WPweBaGQwq9dc6/s//6krl6kdd3b5@LSllIoUj6iEJtUc@OUVjJzEDIZaIQRp7602ON4ewakhDV/rnkumvWeHeb73W8Q@@MqIp5bxoFzxw/0Ii0J8/80KQyb8NrImE3jJHoqxccimys5wZTsZaxPGzy7oBpDkshjzaRLXFpI7vUUkEiwi0pVh5fSXcaQS4olSitfPoPYgeHDcIJ1MIpJf@ydnn7vkOBocA2RajMLHAkHEFlXJZiYApqQ5f0WCrVdHfQNBS8LtlMEwtfq3pydStFmWWHT3w/Mi1DSKU4lVUUkbukFwRNSB8/bMAsoE/IdeQK3DYLgy3SGzS5OND9mgTj6ghcTaJekrg6yFHlqLTMaM54sqUIbXqk6nr1GjoTmhtak9ntQf2DHaEhKwIL3xruhmfKQ8OA7AOI/VGc2Pz/Yet7Y@kfDXw3l2XC3jcq7UiseWOieqRzWYBwGAfKTP9h/ZuUNEGL9uDxUAp6YOGXmRrPd6jTJahNhubW5vbGx82t0k5h/JiVY1SvbXonH5@4S5KrEUGA4JA/EgXjkzLLykKQ7VWSnWllSFDE4NvGrJ1Yzt0eDty7@7HE8@f/hGwcPbwOH96bu8ffO4cHn3p/uvr8clp7@zf5xf9y//59v33/6TqMuUM02MDAvU2HFVi7rkZ/aDiQkZ0d41GveVWq8pLbp0IvwP4HcA3W3cAz4HTAGWzGxYGyRw1GKzwFSrvjpVaIztnTETkrJiL6GeiRiVOAeKzQ/aSSNRLfB4Z98KiIHEC/AUmVDizwCP1OP4xjUSujSlOFtlihwzBk8BnQh@2VY8G4MfEIgjyAyt44hlQTtJfyreBj4q0kCR7TC3PBDG4EBWhW557VFJ6aUCiIaVPEnd4a0rKZdL53u2TL5dnBPYj8u9LeDjrnnVI@/j8hPQ75yeIG0yIOoQFxmzlhIH6t@h5ni41QL6YA9YQYs2KHO3t6K3MDtxpKHHW@ZX89TxSYg2R52EXl/f2skJLULVMQYORVrJ5vhFtWtks0UiyxFJyQHvn8kM2LawSP7i1PPeZkrELmynUiOCnsLMLYEBt/5ZDH6yxi7a@hxpRSpPA517f2Pwgoj8tQuAzZkAV1Ri4U0ycq0ajeW3gj@36tSFP5TysIWBbHwHmF2D1CLYNMC8Pq7@PYBsAc3OwjwCSzfzQR4H9YQtAdmGWiNM2cmIF2HYE@wCwh4IE0aq2cFXDAixa1QdcFS3w3Ix4Ar0cFGCRnNso52Me1oy0sY3amBdg0XzbON9TARbJ@RHlfM6rZSsSEzVmFUT5ELEEceWwsLxIzC0Uc1KARWJ@QDGdHGwTNVzND@HMam5oA7FW8kOo/lJ@CKdeS4aEP/InnjFjd4S27cH1Z8yIvPyK@@d1TBaPVqtiHDcvKS4dKgmxAezX10t1LDNg8uxmgDsBp1WNZov/EN@qqiyn9qEcB9uaM/Dk2ttCJRsBrrNUT8YXyepwe01LoMpP5/27ky7KcVZ4HLn2iPhDgnsqbAGUQW6fWCEMYnP7SWBR7VYjj2Q@n2Pm9@OfjwIKRZclSLHx48Q1XloRplt6WyfYlLm30OVSMpwFAAkEIfNJG1TsYLMM1DcBZh1iZdKOR1k4fjDqIvHoP65QzOuSHmuDT4aCgkUFbtakXB0tj87D1FH0H1ZKDjaPZjDqWSNzQrktt/gmUc8ZJEu2t0w1lK01G9WeiiZwVTVr8ESonJ0brcQwluOQsXUDRSZ/FoPdk26/3e@eHpGjXr9HLuChcwJtwgX51oVG97B3fNz7huD2t6/k4rR7dtbp7whS7jctIe6qWANnb0Bumc9l5QW@FzEQS9tfY2ialkXmMHjqB25UKfj47UFJMXdZiB0k5yVoFpkluZ4butZ4/ARlkBgB94ACA/5G/iPwCX0VyKNVcC9Fd4IGn3OFAAV/ImPfh0KF6SW9phcwueMhaopHOOZvEab1aM0fnyyBbfse8J3l8Zle@@1dyhoJrJjgJqDW/TJ7ThDP0N5BZeBGP6YhhaU67nAIq4SQj2quVdLb73@LI0CwwaWDBh9RH3FIZPZfYRtZXvADF6FecCuKZ1DiHAlqZTK1glB41tsBJHyzWo19EerXCmTeGv7HWSq5YCKymEcW8@XC6m3WqppjjXoB3r/9fe5JRIAqsL7z2Bgr0Oiwh6FmrSl02MABx0GhTIq7HCGZYJrIxXR9UXRwPYGVdPD0@PEms744qWb5TGdsVMnSKsuU0GlNSzrkWajxVqC2DJ8qijKdhXiuUZn60I0LIsDzSzrI9BdI3hISHj3e0iKeWxLi4VEYckkhZgqJSVOgXWQPiGGOMStgIDCGPZR02ENpwGg6NizpmfYKAwwc3@Q7GDZafIZo9Mq9TshoSQePCXxcX4Zb8IZ8mSZL6CDBjn0STQ1BZcI8TkVelxXlDUfnTpGMJy4a87IGFcEO2@U8w0Ej5hj591tMi64f822X9CiWP8mtKP/QGBjmlxv6I2pNC5aecBwOiBQyDPxJ9BwjOSWdp6pEM9WV0poqVIO2qCh7RlOxAtiwJuAXNtcSR04CEDg6YFqe9oa@D@HAI62SHIqVeXEU5SXcbDIRBlHFwxG2@hSfS5QE49IRpWLd@EFooqIFH0V0xbypfMlMO/NsPG2HcsD1IswXFlr2/ZXrGFCf1sXUotPKnr6lPBYJk4zXcVY1lmzyzBCqagnm1arrAHMpe4ZQBydn3LEzhQHaJJZHbdTAywsCxcd9qTzJVA7FTYOYaE8kV6//u/mqfD5Q3IIUOs9VNEa2g27xpliSYLuC3C1ODZMzS2jLyyNXm85pmbQ1@I/4RHt8vmO@dqfNtWftUbOINifaE7Huqa85MOBoVLPi8wtxqFCay/mlz5NFi4NMPC8AsXKykt3d8uHl6UG/2zu9KEuJqbh/VCbsNtM8E3h8lZEFHkmIhkGcybaQN1SdkWKuicsIKjkzBqoiI4sRyPUTViN1KD0cOqdOjAIe5rnT2Vhc7iRyROH5Ep18JDNAWblIsYRBl5AyGNxwpps6by3BqlavDdPN4mIOKDKrqWpCkWUcvomcoKqNLHKcwU23Zt4JzaKvmehsJnhbTKU34TFzVGbeGQlr002q3eyY8dbc6lvIBbhh3kXFBrchBgP8M5mBm0YB8ogNh1ghv7CAFJgJ5XR1Ii/GunAd9G0eXBkNpPkzxovDL69UjoP2SsDcRiCZ68PXHYrH@BUer1V5OQfj1hg6Hw68eQLJGf1jRj2bRtCbGTZRTzdUXERaNr@jA2K8bZjhRWTWYcTmjjJkjo/kAXzWfGxDTFfKOViy5aN1bUEFuRfsmvYyMdfN90oL2zQooWMTu@8MtZGWfdwvbNjZTXs3Pl8FWeAx4xcxu@hslE9cayjVzW3O3mJsxvXTvjjodmMjJyLH9YsZJMLyvtyceQC6mQ1T/wuMZPAqbaPjBPoGKDZukK4I2GNhNAafgXFlFxrDPHK0/AxpRlg@R2KR7JT54HUZm1o25VgRp8rHXcBZXzfxDHpTeX2FeDM2mgvuL7c@35gJw1NHyE/CzhV5zZFr66BvQMppLDEy2q6GGg/SQG5hKKdl4QpYdH09I1ErXjFfKGdhRGfU3FMMY3NDiAcOkmmlo5GYIj3lyU6X0zSsdXP79fX91m7swGL8zUvJzAYn8r6smTv8yMHySLRg@Be8TU7aCt6bpnSrxJl50Cy5Q7DfLaTxANuH1GgK93Ve4IQjcElG8GbeD7Mcel/bvxPwKJYH5CzfWj5kX272VwneEPFezXFv3ZAXU@jDKEMrMdbmduoX77daOdNlPT@ABprA5CqGVTLJslg5x@VXlJ7jot9Y48LGmi284tCLy7lPcmyO2BbWDpmAE2Ega481qATg76mGCtSeI4NkbsxiKpmYY4uFvI4mcoaFhTSZiEmrbf5dM3l/WzMZxUchX8rK4N@Jy/IhPGDNOllcUy/ZauVX1@mF1MF34ZXo/HshFVwuqa13m/9wGrFMg0@TjIk15wczy5zLSmJlTr4bUbyB@1TE3fs57nMRd8XIIkdb8@PoibjEmsAeFp2LuHimGBtyh59NjSDExpSRsTtx8b0W6N5uKR5DRnHMasCJsim1xdkQ5PvDgNL9i88tUp9vHYoPFnB47DKx5oQ32ADbrosPwmBXkaKTFZzU5YcFYmoC9eGYgruQ497pEQ976qSzR@eiQLFnkI0muYHwxHdnTtq/73dgo/qK71@cX5B@j3zuHHQ/dwhYsP@lc44jACL7B5lgSpsq05/ybHxXM@@TmBKvcqTB7EaWhXpqycTublySRcj3kBwwKUB9BPjmffGsEkAs3i14Bb7GBvKaDX@MvOIl0mCwMhiU4J93Ogzc2DIXEOW8Sz3uzoCpAZzsjPc5qe7eyM0Q2f4UQzpdfnSTmKZnUe/eKz@NHmBh4BWCQpJGn6ukGvX5rSLqyhLqu5@hqnLu8DZHpBaIBB2vonfrhYP@/GxqI6Va5Kb8X/mqtHadm/Snpo6t/Q4ARmHCJQU/08BXHffBZeBt8hKPgsf8ymkyMmdXJvRVkj@Zrm7e7ZjuGrBUCjvaQko6tJ90cN3Tbr8snZ4bRuMlvfY3oTx2zOgACCpJPBlfANae0YRNLwuM40WnnmPrSnoHAE2/kj2qX4gOUxwpVavZIyd@PSAO3xcSCoTdbtm/CYEJYf4ssKG95Y1vZQcbyA0l@/pYdH1eaJs5HhC98frRS3119Z2@IBt7eOSA6SeaKr5Jd6Lr5egCnWfQIb7CN36SKtEtiTjagjYB@tD/1zsuhbdbHsQLLsW3WzK79H/zRstP32X564vq5VdY3nh55a3XVvJvrfzyfRXxpsryiyriFRVx268Ni1fwyatZ//AiPjn3QJeNJhLWjV8KExXrP@SuYEqONMc7qYTJxL0dQXtJb8HX@FuqvLqXuIpyb01wQnBoHj/gfNAugzyojokV4lt3qBjRw2JTG@n4BN@ViF@ybJ8fmSft77lAgRDi696sf/ygyCR@c/FEN5qtE9XYxlsL0S/iri9HOoeGVYq6SEYgOeydRMZiLYZXHdILMxCwkFI7Mn5DMLcCqNbVLnmO7ff8Z7c8IZArqfN/)

### With comments

```
XX.Z
.A.zXX.Z
  # push(getchar())
  .A.iXX.Z
  # constant 'm' charcode
  .AXXm.Z
# break loop if pop==pop
.A.aXX.Z
# "Hi" and dummy
.AXX_iH.Z
# dummy is popped before entering loop
.A.wXX.Z
  # keep pushing until EOF (-1) is met
  .A.i.c\0001.+.aXX.Z
# discard final EOF
.A.sXX.Z
# ", I'm Pxem!"
# reverse stack before printing each item
.A!mexP m'I ,.v.p
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL), <s>356</s> 352 bytes.

Assumes adjective and noun has <100 characters.

```
DO;1<-#3DO;2<-#99DOWRITEIN;1+;2DO;3<-#2DO;3SUB#1<-#29DO;3SUB#2<-#1118DO;4<-#1DO;4SUB#1<-#127DO;6<-#1DO;6SUB#1<-#117DO;5<-#13DO;5SUB#1<-#16DO;5SUB#2<-#368DO;5SUB#3<-#368DO;5SUB#4<-#274DO;5SUB#5<-#103DO;5SUB#6<-#376DO;5SUB#7<-#217DO;5SUB#8<-#374DO;5SUB#9<-#356DO;5SUB#10<-#374DO;5SUB#11<-#375DO;5SUB#12<-#1353DO;5SUB#13<-#276DOREADOUT;3+;2+;4+;6+;1+;6+;5
```

[Copy and paste to try it online!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

### With comments

```
DONOTE ;1 for "I'm", ;2 for rest of input
DO;1<-#3
DO;2<-#99
DOWRITEIN;1+;2
DONOTE ;3 for "Hi"
DO;3<-#2DO;3SUB#1<-#29DO;3SUB#2<-#1118
DONOTE ;4 for ","
DO;4<-#1DO;4SUB#1<-#127
DONOTE ;6 for " "
DO;6<-#1DO;6SUB#1<-#117
DONOTE ;5 for "CLC-INTERCAL!"
DO;5<-#13DO;5SUB#1<-#16DO;5SUB#2<-#368DO;5SUB#3<-#368DO;5SUB#4<-#274DO;5SUB#5<-#103DO;5SUB#6<-#376DO;5SUB#7<-#217DO;5SUB#8<-#374DO;5SUB#9<-#356DO;5SUB#10<-#374DO;5SUB#11<-#375DO;5SUB#12<-#1353DO;5SUB#13<-#276
DONOTE concatenate those strings
DOREADOUT;3+;2+;4+;6+;1+;6+;5
```

Comment: Shall I ;7<-"C"? Would it shorten the code?

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3 (34 Bytes)

```py
lambda m:"Hi%s, I'm Python!"%m[3:]
```

#### Python 3 (35 Bytes)

```py
lambda m:"Hi"+m[3:]+", I'm Python!"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 46 bytes

```
s=input()
print("Hi "+s[4:]+", I'm Python 3!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9g2M6@gtERDk6ugKDOvREPJI1NBSbs42sQqVltJR8FTPVchAKxWwVhRSfP/f5BAYm5iVWZeOgA)

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal (ISO standard 10206, “Extended Pascal”), 103 characters

```pascal
program d(input,output);var s:string(99);begin readLn(s);writeLn('Hi',subStr(s,4),', I''m Pascal!')end.
```

### FreePascal, 83 characters

The FPC (FreePascal Compiler) in its *default configuration* (specifically `{$mode FPC}`), discards and doesn’t need a `program` header (the `program d(input,output);`).
Instead a `program` *always* has the `text` files `input` and `output` at its disposal.
Furthermore `string` is shorthand for `string[255]`.
However, the `subStr` `function` is not (yet) supported (as of FPC version 3.2.0) and `copy` will necessarily require a length specification (can only be omitted in `{$mode Delphi}`).
Thus we can condense the above `program` to:

```pascal
var s:string;begin readLn(s);writeLn('Hi',s[4..length(s)],', I''m FreePascal!')end.
```

```pascal
var s:string;begin readLn(s);delete(s,1,3);writeLn('Hi',s,', I''m FreePascal!')end.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `KJ`, \$ 22 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 18.11 bytes

```
3Zx", I'm Thunno!"s"Hi
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_WbSSt5dS7IKlpSVpuhbbjKMqlHQUPNVzFULA0opKxUoemRBJqJoFq0HSibmJVZl56RAhAA)

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 23 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 18.93 bytes

```
3Zx"Hi%s, I'm Thunno!"$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbbjaMqlDwyVYt1FDzVcxVCwJKKSioQWaiiBatBcom5iVWZeekQIQA)

##### Explanation

```python
               # Implicit input
3Zx            # Remove first three characters
   "..."       # Push the string literal
        s"Hi  "# Swap and push "Hi"
               # Implicit output of joined stack

           # Implicit input
3Zx        # Remove first three characters
   "..."   # Push the string literal
        $  # Replace "%s" with ^^
           # Implicit output
```