# What will you bring for Thanksgiving?

Tags: code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity, polyglot

[Thanksgiving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanksgiving_(United_States)) in the United States is coming up on November 24th. Many people will have a large dinner with their families, traditionally including turkey and many side dishes. This typically means the family members must coordinate who's going to bring each of the various dishes. In this challenge, the goal is to **write a [polyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)) that outputs a different dish in each language it's run in.**

### Menu

(Selected from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanksgiving_dinner). In case it's not obvious, each line is one item.)

```
turkey
stuffing
dressing
cranberry sauce
mashed potatoes
gravy
winter squash
sweet potatoes
corn
green beans
green bean casserole
mac and cheese
macaroni and cheese
salad
rolls
biscuits
corn bread
pumpkin pie
apple pie
mincemeat pie
sweet potato pie
pecan pie
apple cider
sweet tea
```

### Rules

- Each submission must run in **at least 3 languages**, each of which must output a **different** item from the menu. You may not use multiple versions of the same language (e.g. Python 2 and Python 3 cannot be used in the same answer).
- Each entry must have the same bytes in each language's encoding. For example, `ɱ` is byte `0x1D` in [Jelly's encoding](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), which corresponds to `¢` in [05AB1E's encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).
- Different languages may use different output methods, but **entries must be full programs in all languages**, and follow one of our [default allowed IO methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42545).
- No programs may take input, but any of the programs may print to STDERR or throw runtime/compile time errors and warnings as long as the correct output is still printed to STDOUT or a file.
- **Case and whitespace do not matter.** For example, an output of `GreenbeAN      S` would still count as `green beans`.
- As the central dish of every<sup>1</sup> American Thanksgiving meal is turkey, **one language must output `turkey`** (ignoring case and whitespace).

### Scoring

**The submission that produces unique valid outputs in the most languages wins.** In case of a tie, the shortest of the tied entries in bytes wins.

<sup>1. Yes, [turkey is not the only main dish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanksgiving_dinner#Alternatives_to_turkey), but we're going to pretend it is.</sup>

Comment: Two related challenges: [1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/94810/42545), [2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7261/42545)

Comment: _Case and whitespace do not matter_ So can we _remove_ whitespace? Say output `cornbread`

Comment: @LuisMendo Yup.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65641/8478)

Comment: "turkey is not the only main dish" But it *is* the most traditional.

Comment: Would an answer involving different dialects of a language count? Like shell scripts (bash, fish, cmd, etc.), or the various dialects of ECMAScript (JavaScript, ActionScript, etc.)?

Comment: Well, I'll bring nothing, because I don't live in USA. XD

Comment: Can we output extraneous null chars? (0x00)

Comment: Also, can we use BF derivatives with BF?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Yes, you can use different dialects.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I'll allow the null char as whitespace. And yes, you may use different "dialects" of BF.

Comment: Is it ok if my BF program takes input, but then deletes it, so that it will produce the same output even no matter the input?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Submissions should be run with no input, so as long as it works with empty input, yes.

Comment: So this is basically asking us to code a [Turducken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turducken).

Answer (score 32):

### Pyke, Pyth, Python 2, Foo, Brain****, GolfScript, Actually, <><, Gol<><, Seriously, Befunge, Fission, Haystack, 13 languages, 546 bytes

When I saw [the other <s>10</s> <s>11</s> 12 language answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101196/32686), I had to add an extra <s>one</s> <s>two</s> 3. I'm also seriously considering dropping Pyth if only to save on bytes. (at the moment 162 of them)

```
#\ s[\g\r\a\v\y)w.q)\r\o\l\l\ssp00/;oooooooo'stuffing;oooooo~'`turkey'
print'corn'#))))))))))))))))))))))))]+[--------->++<]>+w.q++[->+++<]>++w.q+++++++++++w.q-----------w.q----------------;))!+f'!n'!i'!s'!s'!e'!r'!d'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))L
'bread'#)))\é'i'n'o'r'a+++++))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))\♀1X'c'a'm++++'e's'e'e'h'c'd'n'a++++++++)+.&\�0\ó))))))))))))))))))
#\25*8*0+c25*6*9+c25*6*7+c25*6*5+c25*7*8+c25*8*0+c25*7*3+c25*6*9+c|000000
# ,,,,,,,,@0>00000000\#"biscuits"aetteews"
```

---

Pyke: [Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%23%5C+s%5B%5Cg%5Cr%5Ca%5Cv%5Cy%29w.q%29%5Cr%5Co%5Cl%5Cl%5Cssp00%2F%3Boooooooo%27stuffing%3Boooooo%7E%27%60turkey%27%0Aprint%27corn%27%23%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%5D%2B%5B---------%3E%2B%2B%3C%5D%3E%2Bw.q%2B%2B%5B-%3E%2B%2B%2B%3C%5D%3E%2B%2Bw.q%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2Bw.q-----------w.q----------------%3B%29%29%21%2Bf%27%21n%27%21i%27%21s%27%21s%27%21e%27%21r%27%21d%27%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29L%0A%27bread%27%23%29%29%29%5C%C3%A9%27i%27n%27o%27r%27a%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%5C%E2%99%801X%27c%27a%27m%2B%2B%2B%2B%27e%27s%27e%27e%27h%27c%27d%27n%27a%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%29%2B.%26%5C%EF%BF%BD0%5C%C3%B3%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%0A%23%5C25%2a8%2a0%2Bc25%2a6%2a9%2Bc25%2a6%2a7%2Bc25%2a6%2a5%2Bc25%2a7%2a8%2Bc25%2a8%2a0%2Bc25%2a7%2a3%2Bc25%2a6%2a9%2Bc%7C000000%0A%23+%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%400%3E00000000%5C%23%22biscuits%22aetteews%22&warnings=0) `rolls`

Relevent line of code:

```
#s[\g\r\a  \v\y)w.q)\r\o\l\l\ssp00/;oooooooo'stuffing;oooooo~'`turkey'

#s[\g\r\a  \v\y)w.q) - effectively a comment because # doesn't do anything with an empty stack
\r\o\l\l\ss - sum("r", "o", "l", "l", "s")
p - print(^)
00/ - raise a ZeroDivisionError to stop running code
```

---

Pyth: [Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23%5C+s%5B%5Cg%5Cr%5Ca%5Cv%5Cy%29w.q%29%5Cr%5Co%5Cl%5Cl%5Cssp00%2F%3Boooooooo%27stuffing%3Boooooo%7E%27%60turkey%27%0Aprint%27corn%27%23%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%5D%2B%5B---------%3E%2B%2B%3C%5D%3E%2Bw.q%2B%2B%5B-%3E%2B%2B%2B%3C%5D%3E%2B%2Bw.q%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2Bw.q-----------w.q----------------%3B%29%29%21%2Bf%27%21n%27%21i%27%21s%27%21s%27%21e%27%21r%27%21d%27%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29L%0A%27bread%27%23%29%29%29%5C%C3%A9%27i%27n%27o%27r%27a%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%5C%E2%99%801X%27c%27a%27m%2B%2B%2B%2B%27e%27s%27e%27e%27h%27c%27d%27n%27a%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%29%2B.%26%5C%EF%BF%BD0%5C%C3%B3%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%0A%23%5C25%2a8%2a0%2Bc25%2a6%2a9%2Bc25%2a6%2a7%2Bc25%2a6%2a5%2Bc25%2a7%2a8%2Bc25%2a8%2a0%2Bc25%2a7%2a3%2Bc25%2a6%2a9%2Bc%7C000000000%0A%23+%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%400%3E00000000%5C%23%22biscuits%22aetteews%22&debug=0) `gravy`

Relevent line of code:

```
#s[\g\r\a  \v\y)w.q)\r\o\l\l\ssp00/;oooooooo'stuffing;oooooo~'`turkey'

#...) - while True:
s[\g\r\a  \v\y) - sum(["g", "r", "a", "v", "y"])
w - input()
.q - quit
```

All the `)`'s are for Pyth to make it compile without erroring on no input.

---

Python 2: `corn`

Line 1 is a whole comment

Line 2 prints "corn" and then has a comment

Line 3 has a string literal and then a comment

Line 4 onwards are comments

---

Foo: [Try It Online!](http://foo.tryitonline.net/#code=I1wgc1tcZ1xyXGFcdlx5KXcucSlcclxvXGxcbFxzc3AwMC87b29vb29vb28nc3R1ZmZpbmc7b29vb29vfidgdHVya2V5JwpwcmludCdjb3JuJyMpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSldK1stLS0tLS0tLS0-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&input=) `biscuits`

Foo prints out anything enclosed in double quotes (`"`). In this case I was careful to only include languages that could cope with other forms of string input (Special case for Befunge). If there was any text after the final `"`, that would be printed too.

---

Brain****: [Try It Online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=I1wgc1tcZ1xyXGFcdlx5KXcucSlcclxvXGxcbFxzc3AwMC87b29vb29vb28nc3R1ZmZpbmc7b29vb29vfidgdHVya2V5JwpwcmludCdjb3JuJyMpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSldK1stLS0tLS0tLS0-Kys8XT4rdy5xKytbLT4rKys8XT4rK3cucSsrKysrKysrKysrdy5xLS0tLS0tLS0tLS13LnEtLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tOykpIStmJyFuJyFpJyFzJyFzJyFlJyFyJyFkJykpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSlMCidicmVhZCcjKSkpXMOpJ2knbidvJ3InYSsrKysrKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpXOKZgDFYJ2MnYSdtKysrKydlJ3MnZSdlJ2gnYydkJ24nYSsrKysrKysrKSsuJlzvv70wXMOzKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpCiNcMjUqOCowK2MyNSo2KjkrYzI1KjYqNytjMjUqNio1K2MyNSo3KjgrYzI1KjgqMCtjMjUqNyozK2MyNSo2KjkrY3wwMDAwMDAwMDAKIyAsLCwsLCwsLEAwPjAwMDAwMDAwXCMiYmlzY3VpdHMiYWV0dGVld3Mi&input=) `salad`

I copied the output of constant string generator. I had to escape all `.` characters with `.q` so it would play with Pyth and `w.` so it would play with Pyke. I added some extra `-` characters so the cells would get to the right points before printing at another `.` character in the 3rd line

---

GolfScript: [Try It Online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=I1wgc1tcZ1xyXGFcdlx5KXcucSlcclxvXGxcbFxzc3AwMC87b29vb29vb28nc3R1ZmZpbmc7b29vb29vfidgdHVya2V5JwpwcmludCdjb3JuJyMpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSldK1stLS0tLS0tLS0-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&input=) `cornbread`

In GolfScript, `#` is a comment until end of line.

What GolfScript interpreter sees:

```
#comment
print'corn'#comment
'bread'#comment
```

In GolfScript, for whatever reason, `print` takes a string and prints it without a newline. Just having `bread` is enough to print it as well.

---

Actually: [Try It Online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=I1wgc1tcZ1xyXGFcdlx5KXcucSlcclxvXGxcbFxzc3AwMC87b29vb29vb28nc3R1ZmZpbmc7b29vb29vfidgdHVya2V5JwpwcmludCdjb3JuJyMpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSldK1stLS0tLS0tLS0-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&input=) `macandcheese`

Relevant line:

```
'bread'#)))\é'i'n'o'r'a+++++))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))\♀1X'c'a'm++++'e's'e'e'h'c'd'n'a++++++++)+.&\�0\ó))))))))))))))))))

é - clears the stack of whatever junk was on it before.
'i'n'o'r'a+++++ - create string "aroni"
) - rotate entire stack (effectively comments as stack is only 1 long)
♀1X - pop stack (now empty)
'c'a'm++++ - constructs the string "mac"
'e's'e'e'h'c'd'n'a++++++++ - constructs the string "andcheese"
) - rotate stack (reverse)
+ - "mac" + "andcheese"
� - quit
```

---

<><: [Copy+Paste only](https://fishlanguage.com/playground) `turkey`
[image: Animation of output]

---

Gol<><: [Try It Online!](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/?code=%23s%5B%5Cs%5Cw%5Ce%5Ce%5Ct%5Cp%5Co%5Ct%5Ca%5Ct%5Co%5Cp%5Ci%5Ce%29w.q%22biscuits%22%29%5Cr%5Co%5Cl%5Cl%5Cssp00%2F%3Boooooooo%27stuffing%3Boooooo%7e%27%60turkey%27%0Aprint%27corn%27%23%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%5D%2B%5B---------%3E%2B%2B%3C%5D%3E%2Bw.q%2B%2B%5B-%3E%2B%2B%2B%3C%5D%3E%2B%2Bw.q%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2Bw.q-----------w.q%2B%2B%2Bw.q%3B%5Co%3B%0A%27bread%27%23%29%29%29%5C%C3%A9%27i%27n%27o%27r%27a%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%5C%E2%99%801X%27c%27a%27m%2B%2B%2B%2B%27e%27s%27e%27e%27h%27c%27d%27n%27a%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%29%2B%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29&input=&debug=true&symbolic=true) `stuffing`

As <>< except `` ` `` skips the first `'` and only outputs enough characters to print `stuffing`

---

Seriously: [Try It Online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=I1wgc1tcZ1xyXGFcdlx5KXcucSlcclxvXGxcbFxzc3AwMC87b29vb29vb28nc3R1ZmZpbmc7b29vb29vfidgdHVya2V5JwpwcmludCdjb3JuJyMpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSldK1stLS0tLS0tLS0-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&input=) `macaroniandcheese`

Relevant line:

```
'bread'#)))\é'i'n'o'r'a+++++))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))\♀1X'c'a'm++++'e's'e'e'h'c'd'n'a++++++++)+.&\�0\ó))))))))))))))))))
é - clears the stack of whatever junk was on it before.
'i'n'o'r'a+++++ - create string "aroni"
) - rotate entire stack (effectively comments as stack is only 1 long)
♀1X - no-op
'c'a'm++++ - constructs the string "mac" + "aroni"
'e's'e'e'h'c'd'n'a++++++++ - constructs the string "andcheese"
) - rotate stack (reverse)
+ - "macaroni" + "andcheese"
. - print stack
0\ó - exit
```

---

Befunge: [Try It Online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=I1wgc1tcZ1xyXGFcdlx5KXcucSlcclxvXGxcbFxzc3AwMC87b29vb29vb28nc3R1ZmZpbmc7b29vb29vfidgdHVya2V5JwpwcmludCdjb3JuJyMpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSldK1stLS0tLS0tLS0-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&input=) `sweettea`

Code that is looked at

```
#s[\g\r\a  \v - |
            ) - | - Directing the stack pointer to the correct place
            é - |
# ,,,,,,,,@0>00000000\#"biscuits"aetteews"

            >                              - change direction of travel
             00000000\#"biscuits           - a load of no-ops `#` skips the opening `"`
                                "aetteews" - add the chars to the stack in reverse order
  ,,,,,,,,@                                - output 8 chars from the stack and exit.
```

---

Fission: [Try It Online!](http://fission.tryitonline.net/#code=I1wgc1tcZ1xyXGFcdlx5KXcucSlcclxvXGxcbFxzc3AwMC87b29vb29vb28nc3R1ZmZpbmc7b29vb29vfidgdHVya2V5JwpwcmludCdjb3JuJyMpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSkpKSldK1stLS0tLS0tLS0-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&input=) `dressing`

Code looked at:

```
;))!+f'!n'!i'!s'!s'!e'!r'!d'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))L
```

Of which are used:

```
;!+f'!n'!i'!s'!s'!e'!r'!d'L
                          L - start an atom going left
                      !d'   - create the character `d` and print it
                              ...
;                           - exit
```

---

[Haystack (2015)](https://github.com/kade-robertson/haystack): `PECANPIE` (with EXTRA newlines!)

```
#\
 r
 b
 \25*8*0+c25*6*9+c25*6*7+c25*6*5+c25*7*8+c25*8*0+c25*7*3+c25*6*9+c
```

Of which do something functional:

```
  25*8*0+c25*6*9+c25*6*7+c25*6*5+c25*7*8+c25*8*0+c25*7*3+c25*6*9+c
```

I construct each upper case ascii codepoint for the letters in `PECANPIE`  in uppercase because they're all below 100. I then print them all out as characters.

Comment: Wow! Never seen a Pyth/Python polyglot (I guess comments make it easier)

Comment: You can remove some spaces and probably make it shorter (`macaroni and cheese` can be output as `macaroniandcheese`)

Comment: @Artyer spaces removed

Comment: @Artyer this ain't no codegolf

Comment: @Flp.Tkc Oops. I got confused by all the byte counts. But until there is a 7 language solution:  "In case of a tie, the shortest of the tied entries in bytes wins."

Comment: What does it output for Seriously? Also, an explanation would be handy

Comment: @KritixiLithos explanation for all added

Comment: Wait, GolfScript outputs `cornrolls`? That wasn't on the menu...

Comment: @ETHproductions that's fixed now - how did you spot that?

Comment: Just looking through the explanations and I noticed `cornrolls` as one of the output. Great job fitting all these languages together!

Comment: All right then, competition's on! :)

Comment: @muddyfish perhaps, if you want to expand this answer in SILOS print (ingredient) will work and not be broken by the other languages. However, are these languages tolerant of having excess garbage at the end.

Answer (score 10):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [Dip](https://github.com/mcparadip/Dip), [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 4 languages, <s>36</s> 34 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @DrMcMoylex!*

```
"turkey"e#"corn"??"gravy"p&Ssalad
```

Original 36 byte code:

```
"turkey"e#"corn"??"gravy"p&ddisalad
```

After the `&` and before the `d` there is an `<ESC>`, which is 1 byte. So the code with the zero-width characters revealed looks like this:

```
"turkey"e#"corn"??"gravy"p&Ssalad
```

#### CJam

(`<ESC>` is not shown)

```
"turkey"e#"corn"??"gravy"p&Ssalad
"turkey"                           e# push this string
        e#"corn"??"gravy"p&Ssalad  e# comment
                                   e# implicit output
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=InR1cmtleSJlIyJjb3JuIj8_ImdyYXZ5InAmG1NzYWxhZA&input=) outputs `turkey`

#### 05AB1E

(`<ESC>` is not shown)

```
"turkey"e#"corn"??"gravy"p&Ssalad
"turkey"                           # push this string
                                   # STACK: ["turkey"]
        e                          # calculates nPr for the last two values in the stack
                                   # since there is only one value, this evaluates to nothing
                                   # as a result, "turkey" is popped
                                   # STACK: []
         #                         # if true end, since this is false, the program doesn't end
          "corn"?                  # push this string and print it without newlines
                                   # STACK: []
                 ?                 # prints nothing, since there is nothing in stack
                  "gravy"p&Ssalad  # nothing happens here since the stack is already printed using a command and there is NO implicit print now, I think
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=InR1cmtleSJlIyJjb3JuIj8_ImdyYXZ5InAmG1NzYWxhZA&input=) outputs: `corn`

#### V

(`<ESC>` is shown)

```
"turkey"e#"corn"??"gravy"p&<ESC>Ssalad
"turkey"e#"corn"??"gravy"p&             Code that writes a newline followed by `rn"??"gravy"p&Ssalad`
                           <ESC>        Enters normal mode
                                S       Deletes line and enters insert mode
                                 salad  Writes salad
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=InR1cmtleSJlIyJjb3JuIj8_ImdyYXZ5InAmG1NzYWxhZA&input=) outputs a newline followed by `salad`

#### Dip

(`<ESC>` is not shown)

```
"turkey"e#"corn"??"gravy"p&Ssalad
"turkey"                           push this string
                                   STACK: ["turkey"]
        e                          not in the language's database
         #                         push str("turkey") --> "turkey"
                                   STACK: ["turkey"]
          "corn"                   push this string
                                   STACK: ["turkey","corn"]
                ?                  pop "corn", if it is the boolean True (which it isn't) execute the following,
                                   but since it is false, nothing until the next ? gets executed
                                   STACK: ["turkey"]
                 ?                 if-statement end
                                   STACK: ["turkey"]
                  "gravy"          push this string
                                   STACK: ["turkey","gravy"]
                         p&        print turkey and end program
                           Ssalad  irrelevant since program has ended
```

Outputs `gravy`

> Note: You cannot run `python3 dip.py` and then type in code for this due to the Escape character literal. It appears as `^[`, which makes the Dip interpreter get confused and it thinks that `[` is a command, and it results in an error.

The best way to run this is to edit the source file, change the last line in `dip.py`

```
main(input(">>> "), stack.Stack())
```

to

```
main("\"turkey\"e#\"corn\"??\"gravy\"p&Ssalad", stack.Stack())
exit()
```

Be sure to include the escape character literal!. Now the code as it is is passed into the interpreter so that it can understand it (`"` have to be escaped like `\"` so). Now if you run it from the command-line, it interprets the actual code and outputs `gravy`.

Comment: @ETHproductions I did not see that, anyways working on it...

Comment: @ETHproductions Done! Now it works in three languages!

Comment: Cool, nice one!

Comment: +1 for `pop "corn"` in the explanation

Comment: A nitpick and a golfing tip: it's called "normal mode" not escape mode, and since whitespace is irrelevant, you could change `ddi` to `S`

Comment: @DrMcMoylex Thanks! I have updated my answer :)

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL) / [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/) / [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) / [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/): 4 languages, <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
'TURKEY'%"rolls"#];"corn""bread"s
```

- In MATL this [outputs](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J1RVUktFWSclInJvbGxzIiNdOyJjb3JuIiJicmVhZCJz&input=) `TURKEY`.
- In Golfscript it [outputs](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=J1RVUktFWSclInJvbGxzIiNdOyJjb3JuIiJicmVhZCJz&input=) `rolls`.
- In 05AB1E it [outputs](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=J1RVUktFWSclInJvbGxzIiNdOyJjb3JuIiJicmVhZCJz&input=) `corn`.
- In CJam it [outputs](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=J1RVUktFWSclInJvbGxzIiNdOyJjb3JuIiJicmVhZCJz&input=) `cornbread`.

Comment: Any particular reason for the capitalization of `tUrKEY`?

Comment: @Ethproductions That's so they're valid statements in CJam and it doesn't error out prematurely in that language

Comment: Actually it can be all caps. After all, turkey is the most important dish :-)

Answer (score 7):

## ferNANDo / ><> / Gol><> / 05AB1E / 2sable, 5 languages, 178 bytes

```
!v"`"v"!
     <;ooooo"salad"
"<;oooooooo"dressing
1 0
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
")\"corn""ab"û"aba"Qi"rolls"
```

- [ferNANDo](http://fernando.tryitonline.net/#code=IXYiYCJ2IiEKICAgICA8O29vb29vInNhbGFkIgoiPDtvb29vb29vbyJkcmVzc2luZwoxIDAKMCAxIDEgMSAwIDEgMCAwCjAgMSAxIDEgMCAxIDAgMQowIDEgMSAxIDAgMCAxIDAKMCAxIDEgMCAxIDAgMSAxCjAgMSAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMQowIDEgMSAxIDEgMCAwIDEKIilcImNvcm4iImFiIsO7ImFiYSJRaSJyb2xscyI&input=): `turkey`
- [><>](https://fishlanguage.com/playground): `salad`
- [Gol><>](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/?code=%21v%22%60%22v%22%21%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3Booooo%22salad%22%0A%22%3C%3Boooooooo%22dressing%0A1%200%0A0%201%201%201%200%201%200%200%0A0%201%201%201%200%201%200%201%0A0%201%201%201%200%200%201%200%0A0%201%201%200%201%200%201%201%0A0%201%201%200%200%201%200%201%0A0%201%201%201%201%200%200%201%0A%22%29%5C%22corn%22%22ab%22%C3%BB%22aba%22Qi%22rolls%22&input=): `dressing`
- [05AB1E](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IXYiYCJ2IiEKICAgICA8O29vb29vInNhbGFkIgoiPDtvb29vb29vbyJkcmVzc2luZwoxIDAKMCAxIDEgMSAwIDEgMCAwCjAgMSAxIDEgMCAxIDAgMQowIDEgMSAxIDAgMCAxIDAKMCAxIDEgMCAxIDAgMSAxCjAgMSAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMQowIDEgMSAxIDEgMCAwIDEKIilcImNvcm4iImFiIsO7ImFiYSJRaSJyb2xscyI&input=): `rolls`
- [2sable](http://2sable.tryitonline.net/#code=IXYiYCJ2IiEKICAgICA8O29vb29vInNhbGFkIgoiPDtvb29vb29vbyJkcmVzc2luZwoxIDAKMCAxIDEgMSAwIDEgMCAwCjAgMSAxIDEgMCAxIDAgMQowIDEgMSAxIDAgMCAxIDAKMCAxIDEgMCAxIDAgMSAxCjAgMSAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMQowIDEgMSAxIDEgMCAwIDEKIilcImNvcm4iImFiIsO7ImFiYSJRaSJyb2xscyI&input=): `corn`

Answer (score 7):

## C, sh, Python 3, Nim, Julia, Brainf**k -- 6 languages, <s>211</s> 209 bytes

```
#define println(x) main(){puts("turkey");}/*
#[
#=
a=''''
echo gravy
'''
println=lambda x:print("biscuits")
# ]#proc println[T](s:T)=echo"rolls"#--[----->+<]>---.++++++++++++.+++.----.
# =##*/
println("salad")
```

Languages to menu items:

- C outputs `turkey`
- sh outputs `gravy`
- Python 3 outputs `biscuits`
- Nim outputs `rolls`
- Julia outputs `salad`
- Brainf**k outputs `corn`

*Added Julia thanks to @kvill!*

Comment: Julia is possible to squeeze in, for the same bytecount. You can drop the C `#include` (works in `gcc`). Rename `puts` `println` everywhere except in `main()`, add julia's multiline comment opener `#=` above `a='''` and change `#*/` to `# =##*/`.

Comment: You can golf this further by removing the `exit` and joining the single quote to the previous line (`a=''''`). `sh` will issue warnings but this is allowed AFAIU. And oh, `println[T](s:T)=echo"rolls"` works for Nim. Nice answer with all my favorite languages combined!

Answer (score 7):

## [Befunge-98](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), Python 2, [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [Foo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), [Haystack (the 2015 version)](https://github.com/kade-robertson/haystack), [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/index.html), BF, [Fission](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fission), [Minkolang 0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/tree/v1), [Axo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Axo): 14 languages,  381 bytes

#### **This is a collaborative answer with [BlueEyedBeast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32686/blueeyedbeast)**

I decided to do a 2D approach to this question... Yes, there are **7** 2D esolangs!

I have taken inspiration for additional languages to add by BlueEyedBeast's answer (Foo, GolfScript)

`<ESC>` is the character literal for [Escape](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1b/index.htm).

```
#>!>\'n\'r\'o\'c\,,,,,@'s'a'l'a'dJ,é'g'n+'i+'s+'s+'e+'r+'d+.ó[-]+[----->+++<]>.+++++++++++.+++[->+++<]>++.+[--->+<]>.+++H'turkey'~;oooooooo'sweettea.0-5++++++++fffffffff''`'
#   >99*d1+c3-c89*4+dcc99*2+c!|$l9D3-O93++dOO8+O1+O1-O5+OO1+O95++O.
# >'p'()'u'()'m'()'p'()'k'()'i'()'n'()'p'()'i'()'e'()\
print'biscuits';'pecanpie'#"stuffing"R'c!'o!'r!'n!'b!'r!'e!'a!'d!*<ESC>ddddddSapplepie
```

#### Befunge-98

```
#?!>                                nothing important
  'n                                push 'n'
                                    STACK: [110]
    \                               swap top two stack values (TBH, I'm not really sure what happens in this case)
                                    STACK: [110, 0]
     'r\'o\'c\                      repeat the same for other characters
                                    STACK: [110 114 111 99 0]
              ,,,,,                 output the next 5 top stack values, "corn"
                   @                end program
                                    rest of the code is irrelevant
                                    since program has already stopped
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#RYzNSsNAFIX3fQU3mVY4mtsEayw0VIILF@JmoC6TgunMpAyNk5AfRBDfx7WP0AerM6HRjzuHe@69c06zhCUZTIYmQ5VBZHPHA1rkKO2Tz/PjN/YwBE1oh1KEhiApPP6kwZbSwJEQ0f02Cekf16fjwtl0uDtfPaHrm4P6wNe6OoP2XamuU3l4EyzHlGIEeMVk5nleEse@XJCIArGK/TuSQtjJLQn2eVnGj1HA44hIcr4ivrAV8CVx18U2lIc2I0GNq2v0Tt6cDPbgRDsxf7PBKivZpG606bDTreh112KNWonc1FphNm27vii02U83EAwVQ8NgGHZDoxhyBsn8Cznwktd1qezH0@kX) outputs `corn`

#### ><>

Commands are shown in the order they appear

```
                                    enter from the left, direction = right
#                                   mirror, now the direction will change to left
                                    and it wraps around and comes to the right
                                    and reads code from the right to the left
'`'                                 push this
   ' ... 5-0.aetteews'              push this too
                      oooooooo      outputs the top 5 characters of the stack
                              ;     end program
```

[Try it online!](https://fishlanguage.com/playground) (Copy and Paste only) outputs `sweettea`

#### V

```
             ...<ESC>                 writes stuff over three lines and enters normal mode
                     ddddddS          deletes 3 lines, delete another line and enter insert mode
                            applepie  writes "applepie"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#RYzNSsNAFIX3fQU3mVY4mtsEayw0VIILF@JmoC6TgunMpAyNk5AfRBDfx7WP0AerM6HRjzuHe@69c06zhCUZTIYmQ5VBZHPHA1rkKO2Tz/PjN/YwBE1oh1KEhiApPP6kwZbSwJEQ0f02Cekf16fjwtl0uDtfPaHrm4P6wNe6OoP2XamuU3l4EyzHlGIEeMVk5nleEse@XJCIArGK/TuSQtjJLQn2eVnGj1HA44hIcr4ivrAV8CVx18U2lIc2I0GNq2v0Tt6cDPbgRDsxf7PBKivZpG606bDTreh112KNWonc1FphNm27vii02U83EAwVQ8NgGHZDoxhyBsn8Cznwktd1qezH0@kX) outputs `applepie` (it might take ˜20 seconds for it to run)

#### Python 2

```
                                    # first two lines are comments
print"biscuits";                    # prints "biscuits" and ends statement
                'pecanpie'          # dangling (and ignored) string literal
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/languages/python) (Copy and Paste only) outputs `biscuits`

#### 05AB1E

```
#>!>                                # does nothing important
\'n\                                # push 'n' and delete it
     'r\'o\'c\                      # repeat for other characters
              ,,,,,                 # prints 5 times (since there is nothing in stack,
                                    #                 prints nothing)
                   @                # push the index of the top of stack
                    's'a'l'a'd      # push these characters
                              J,    # join them and print them out
                                    # the rest of the code does not matter
                                    # since there is no implicit print
                                    # because we used the print statement
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Iz4hPlwnblwnclwnb1wnY1wsLCwsLEAncydhJ2wnYSdkSizDqSdnJ24rJ2krJ3MrJ3MrJ2UrJ3IrJ2QrLsOzWy1dK1stLS0tLT4rKys8XT4uKysrKysrKysrKysuKysrWy0-KysrPF0-KysuK1stLS0-KzxdPi4rKytIJ3R1cmtleSd-O29vb29vb29vJ3N3ZWV0dGVhLjAtNSsrKysrKysrZmZmZmZmZmZmJydgJwojICAgPjk5KmQxK2MzLWM4OSo0K2RjYzk5KjIrYyF8JGw5RDMtTzkzKytkT084K08xK08xLU81K09PMStPOTUrK08uCiMgPidwJygpJ3UnKCknbScoKSdwJygpJ2snKCknaScoKSduJygpJ3AnKCknaScoKSdlJygpXApwcmludCdiaXNjdWl0cyc7J3BlY2FucGllJyMic3R1ZmZpbmciUidjISdvISdyISduISdiISdyISdlISdhISdkISobZGRkZGRkU2FwcGxlcGll&input=&debug=on) outputs `salad`

#### Gol><>

Commands are shown in the order they appear

```
                                    enter from the left, direction = right
#                                   mirror, now the direction changes to left
                                    and it wraps around and comes to the right
                                    and reads code from the right to the left
 '                                  starting parsing strings
  `                                 escape next character
   '                                gets escaped
    "                               stop string parsing
     fffffffff                      pushes 15, 8 times
           ++++++++                 adds up the numbers, resulting in 135
                 5-                 subtract 4 from it, 130
                   0                pushes 0
                    0               jumps to (130, 0)

#\'n\'r\'o\'c\,,,,,@'r'o'l'l'sJ, ... H'turkey'~;oooooooo"sweettea.0-5++++++++fffffffff""`"
                                              ^
                                       we are here now

                     ˜              removes value at top of stack, '"'
                      "yekrut"      push this string
                              H     Output stack as characters and halt program
```

[Try it online!](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/?code=%23%3E%21%3E%5C'n%5C'r%5C'o%5C'c%5C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%40's'a'l'a'dJ%2C%C3%A9'g'n%2B'i%2B's%2B's%2B'e%2B'r%2B'd%2B.%C3%B3%5B-%5D%2B%5B-----%3E%2B%2B%2B%3C%5D%3E.%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B.%2B%2B%2B%5B-%3E%2B%2B%2B%3C%5D%3E%2B%2B.%2B%5B---%3E%2B%3C%5D%3E.%2B%2B%2BH'turkey'%7e%3Boooooooo'sweettea.0-5%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2Bfffffffff''%60'%0A%23%20%20%20%3E99%2ad1%2Bc3-c89%2a4%2Bdcc99%2a2%2Bc%21%7C%24l9D3-O93%2B%2BdOO8%2BO1%2BO1-O5%2BOO1%2BO95%2B%2BO.%0A%23%20%3E'p'%28%29'u'%28%29'm'%28%29'p'%28%29'k'%28%29'i'%28%29'n'%28%29'p'%28%29'i'%28%29'e'%28%29%5C%0Aprint'biscuits'%3B'pecanpie'%23%22stuffing%22R'c%21'o%21'r%21'n%21'b%21'r%21'e%21'a%21'd%21%2a%1BddddddSapplepie&input=) outputs `turkey`

#### Foo

Foo outputs anything in double quotes, that is why I have been careful to not use any double quotes in the other languages. Since `"stuffing"` is in double quotes, it will be printed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/foo#RYzNSsNAFIX3fQU3mVY4mtsEayw0VIILF@JmoC6TgunMpAyNk5AfRBDfx7WP0AerM6HRjzuHe@69c06zhCUZTIYmQ5VBZHPHA1rkKO2Tz/PjN/YwBE1oh1KEhiApPP6kwZbSwJEQ0f02Cekf16fjwtl0uDtfPaHrm4P6wNe6OoP2XamuU3l4EyzHlGIEeMVk5nleEse@XJCIArGK/TuSQtjJLQn2eVnGj1HA44hIcr4ivrAV8CVx18U2lIc2I0GNq2v0Tt6cDPbgRDsxf7PBKivZpG606bDTreh112KNWonc1FphNm27vii02U83EAwVQ8NgGHZDoxhyBsn8Cznwktd1qezH0@kX) outputs `stuffing` and then has an error

#### Haystack (2015)

This uses Haystack's 2015 (not 2016) interpreter since the newer version is invalid. The interpreter for this is `haystack.py` and **not** `haystack_new.py`

Commands are shown in the order they appear

```
#                                 ignored
 \                                reflection (now it moves downwards)
  >                               set direction to right
   99*d1+c                        Output 'R'
          3-c                     Output 'O'
             89*4+dcc             Outputs 'L', newline, 'L'
                     99*2+c!|     Outputs 'S' and ends the program
                                  Note: '!' is ignored by the interpreter
```

This program outputs

```
R
O
L
L
S
```

and a newline after this output (hey, whitespace doesn't matter!)

#### GolfScript

```
                                    first 2 lines are comments
print'biscuits';                    pushes "biscuits" to the stack and discards it
                'pecanpie'          push this
                          #...      comment
                                    implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#RYzNSsNAFIX3fQU3mVY4mtsEayw0VIILF@JmoC6TgunMpAyNk5AfRBDfx7WP0AerM6HRjzuHe@69c06zhCUZTIYmQ5VBZHPHA1rkKO2Tz/PjN/YwBE1oh1KEhiApPP6kwZbSwJEQ0f02Cekf16fjwtl0uDtfPaHrm4P6wNe6OoP2XamuU3l4EyzHlGIEeMVk5nleEse@XJCIArGK/TuSQtjJLQn2eVnGj1HA44hIcr4ivrAV8CVx18U2lIc2I0GNq2v0Tt6cDPbgRDsxf7PBKivZpG606bDTreh112KNWonc1FphNm27vii02U83EAwVQ8NgGHZDoxhyBsn8Cznwktd1qezH0@kX) outputs `pecanpie`

#### BF

I used https://copy.sh/brainfuck/text.html to convert text into BF. Although there are a lot of `,` input statements, the BF code runs independent of it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#RYzNSsNAFIX3fQU3mVY4mtsEayw0VIILF@JmoC6TgunMpAyNk5AfRBDfx7WP0AerM6HRjzuHe@69c06zhCUZTIYmQ5VBZHPHA1rkKO2Tz/PjN/YwBE1oh1KEhiApPP6kwZbSwJEQ0f02Cekf16fjwtl0uDtfPaHrm4P6wNe6OoP2XamuU3l4EyzHlGIEeMVk5nleEse@XJCIArGK/TuSQtjJLQn2eVnGj1HA44hIcr4ivrAV8CVx18U2lIc2I0GNq2v0Tt6cDPbgRDsxf7PBKivZpG606bDTreh112KNWonc1FphNm27vii02U83EAwVQ8NgGHZDoxhyBsn8Cznwktd1qezH0@kX) outputs `gravy`

#### Fission

For a Fission program to begin, an atom has to be spawned. We see this happening the the third line:

```
..."stuffing"                                Blah blah blah
             R                               Spawns an atom with direction right
              'c                             Gives the atom the mass of 'c''s ASCII value
                !                            Print the atom's mass
                 'o!'r!'n!'b!'r!'e!'a!'d!    Do the same for other characters
                                         *   Destroy atom, end program
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#RYzNSsNAFIX3fQU3mVY4mtsEayw0VIILF@JmoC6TgunMpAyNk5AfRBDfx7WP0AerM6HRjzuHe@69c06zhCUZTIYmQ5VBZHPHA1rkKO2Tz/PjN/YwBE1oh1KEhiApPP6kwZbSwJEQ0f02Cekf16fjwtl0uDtfPaHrm4P6wNe6OoP2XamuU3l4EyzHlGIEeMVk5nleEse@XJCIArGK/TuSQtjJLQn2eVnGj1HA44hIcr4ivrAV8CVx18U2lIc2I0GNq2v0Tt6cDPbgRDsxf7PBKivZpG606bDTreh112KNWonc1FphNm27vii02U83EAwVQ8NgGHZDoxhyBsn8Cznwktd1qezH0@kX) outputs `cornbread`

#### Minkolang v0.15

```
#                                Doesn't really do anything
 \                               Reflect, moves downwards
  >                              Changes direction to right
    ... !|                       Does stuff in stack, '!' ignores the '|'
          $l9D3 ... ++O          Uses ASCII character codes to print "applecider"
                       .         Ends program
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#RYzNSsNAFIX3fQU3mVY4mtsEayw0VIILF@JmoC6TgunMpAyNk5AfRBDfx7WP0AerM6HRjzuHe@69c06zhCUZTIYmQ5VBZHPHA1rkKO2Tz/PjN/YwBE1oh1KEhiApPP6kwZbSwJEQ0f02Cekf16fjwtl0uDtfPaHrm4P6wNe6OoP2XamuU3l4EyzHlGIEeMVk5nleEse@XJCIArGK/TuSQtjJLQn2eVnGj1HA44hIcr4ivrAV8CVx18U2lIc2I0GNq2v0Tt6cDPbgRDsxf7PBKivZpG606bDTreh112KNWonc1FphNm27vii02U83EAwVQ8NgGHZDoxhyBsn8Cznwktd1qezH0@kX) outputs `applecider`

#### Seriously

```
é                          - clear stack
 'g'n+'i+'s+'s+'e+'r+'d+   - load chars onto stack
                        .  - print stack
                         ó - exit
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/seriously#RYzNSsNAFIX3fQU3mVY4mtsEayw0VIILF@JmoC6TgunMpAyNk5AfRBDfx7WP0AerM6HRjzuHe@69c06zhCUZTIYmQ5VBZHPHA1rkKO2Tz/PjN/YwBE1oh1KEhiApPP6kwZbSwJEQ0f02Cekf16fjwtl0uDtfPaHrm4P6wNe6OoP2XamuU3l4EyzHlGIEeMVk5nleEse@XJCIArGK/TuSQtjJLQn2eVnGj1HA44hIcr4ivrAV8CVx18U2lIc2I0GNq2v0Tt6cDPbgRDsxf7PBKivZpG606bDTreh112KNWonc1FphNm27vii02U83EAwVQ8NgGHZDoxhyBsn8Cznwktd1qezH0@kX) outputs `dressing`

#### Axo

(Commands are shown the order they are encountered)

```
#>                                          blah blah
  !                                         rotate direction 90 degrees clockwise

  >                                         go right
   'p'()                                    push char and output
        'u'() ... 'e'()                     repeat for other characters
                       \                    end program
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/axo#RYzNSsNAFIX3fQU3mVY4mtsEayw0VIILF@JmoC6TgunMpAyNk5AfRBDfx7WP0AerM6HRjzuHe@69c06zhCUZTIYmQ5VBZHPHA1rkKO2Tz/PjN/YwBE1oh1KEhiApPP6kwZbSwJEQ0f02Cekf16fjwtl0uDtfPaHrm4P6wNe6OoP2XamuU3l4EyzHlGIEeMVk5nleEse@XJCIArGK/TuSQtjJLQn2eVnGj1HA44hIcr4ivrAV8CVx18U2lIc2I0GNq2v0Tt6cDPbgRDsxf7PBKivZpG606bDTreh112KNWonc1FphNm27vii02U83EAwVQ8NgGHZDoxhyBsn8Cznwktd1qezH0@kX) outputs `pumpkinpie`

Comment: This is pretty awesome :)

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks! I put a lot of effort into it :)

Comment: Just a little nitpick: the ! In the befunge code takes a 0 from the top of the stack and pushes 1. Therefore, the stack contents when the program starts printing is [110 114 111 99 1]. The character for ASCII value 1 isn't visible (start of heading), so it doesn't visually affect the result. +1

Comment: @MistahFiggins I could just change it to `$,,,,` instead to not output the `1` (without changing the bytecount), but then I would have to change all the permalinks... :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), Python and Brainfuck

This is my first polyglot, so don't go too hard on me...
For those whining about byte count, it's 77 bytes, but that's only relevant for the tiebreaker.

```py
"`turkey`"
print('gravy')
#++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>-.++++++++++++.+++.----.
```

Pushy prints **'turkey'** with a leading newline (as well as a message to `STDERR`):

```
"        % Print current stack: just a newline as stack is empty
`turkey` % Push to stack
"        % Print the stack: 'turkey'
p        % Primality check on 'y' (121): pushes 0
r        % Integer root of 0: throws error and exits
```

Python prints **'gravy'**, as the first and last lines are treated as comments.

Brainfuck ignores all other characters and except for those on the final line, which create and print the word **'corn'**.

Comment: What's the byte count?

Comment: Also, can't you use Python 2 to remove the parenthesis and save 2 bytes?

Comment: @KritixiLithos this isn't codegolf....

Comment: “In case of a tie, the shortest of the tied entries in bytes wins.” It's not entirely codegolf, but you still need the bytecount.

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg true, but this has no chance of getting to the tiebreaker anyway

Answer (score 4):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), [BF](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BF), [oOo CODE](http://esolangs.org/wiki/OOo_CODE), [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), [Befunge-93](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge) ([Quirkster](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html) implementation), [Ouroboros](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ouroboros), [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////): 7 languages, 175 bytes

```
/'//bisCuItS/`f(>-[--[<]>+>-]<.++++++++++++.+++.----.O@,,,,,,"tuRkey"
"saLaD"1/ooooo;1(
>"YVaRg"^(OoooOoOOoooOoooOOoooOOoOooOooOooOOoOooOooOooOOoOOoOoOOoOOoOOoOOo`OO"sTUfFINg"
```

#### Pip

[Try it online](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=LycvL3R1cmtleS9gQCwsLCwiY29ybiIKLyJ5dmFyZyJsPyE7bzcxLmAic2FsYWQi&input=)

A bunch of expressions that get silently discarded (most of which generate warnings, if warnings are enabled), with the expression `"sTufFINg"` at the end which gets printed.

```
/ '/ / b      Invert the string "/" and divide it by nil
i s           Two different variables
Cu            Chr(nil)
It            If 10:
S / `...` OO   Invert a Pattern literal and swap it with undefined variable OO
"sTufFINg"    Autoprint this last expression
```

#### BF

[Try it online](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LycvL3R1cmtleS9gNTEoLS1bLS0tLS0-KzxdPi0tLS4rKysrKysrKysrKysuKysrLi0tLS0uQCwsLCwsInNhbGFkIgoicm9sbHMiMS9vb29vbzsxKAo-Inl2YXJnIl4oYCJzdHVmZmluZyI&input=)

Everything except `>-[--[<]>+>-]<.++++++++++++.+++.----.,,,,` is comments. This code generates `99` (the character code for `c`) via the shortest method listed on [esolangs.org](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#90), then modifies it for `o`, `r`, and `n`. The `,,,,` tries to input four characters, but that doesn't affect anything.

#### oOo CODE

Everything except letters is ignored. Grouping the letters into threes, the codes reads like this:

```
bis CuI tSf Otu Rke ysa LaD ooo ooY VaR gOo ... OsT UfF INg
```

and translates to this BF code ([try it](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=aWBbXmEtel0KCk0hYC4uLgptYF4KOworYCguKik7KC4pCiQxJDEkMjsKVGBsCi4rCiQuJgpUYGRgXz48W11cLSsuLArCtgo&input=LycvL2Jpc0N1SXRTL2BmKD4tWy0tWzxdPis-LV08LisrKysrKysrKysrKy4rKysuLS0tLS5PQCwsLCwsLCJ0dVJrZXkiCiJzYUxhRCIxL29vb29vOzEoCj4iWVZhUmciXihPb29vT29PT29vb09vb29PT29vb09Pb09vb09vb09vb09Pb09vb09vb09vb09Pb09Pb09vT09vT09vT09vT09vYE9PInNUVWZGSU5nIg) using [Martin's Retina translator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74411/16766)):

```
>+[-->+><+[<]>-]>.---.---..+++++++.
```

which [outputs `rolls`](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=PitbLS0-Kz48K1s8XT4tXT4uLS0tLi0tLS4uKysrKysrKy4&input=). (And, interestingly enough, is shorter than the above BF for outputting `corn`, even with a `><` no-op added to make the capitalization line up correctly.)

#### ><>

[Run ><> code here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)

The important part of the code:

```
/
        /ooooo;
>"YVaRg"^
```

The IP gets reflected upward, wraps around, and gets sent rightward. `"YVaRg"` pushes the character codes of `gRaVY`. `ooooo` outputs five letters and `;` terminates the program.

#### Befunge-93

The code depends on undefined behavior and probably only works in [this implementation](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html).

The important part of the code:

```
/'                        @,,,,,,"tuRkey"
```

`/` is division. The stack is empty, so the JavaScript implementation I'm using divides `0` by `0` and pushes `NaN`.

`'` is an unrecognized character. The implementation I'm using, conveniently, treats unrecognized characters as Reflect commands. (For a less implementation-dependent version, one possible replacement would be `1_`.) So the IP goes left again, divides `NaN` by `0` (getting `NaN`), and wraps to the other end of the line.

Now `"yekRut"` (moving RTL) pushes the character codes of `tuRkey` and `,,,,,,` outputs them. Finally, `@` terminates the program.

#### Ouroboros

[Try it here](http://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/)

Each line of the code is a "snake" that executes independently.

**Snake 1**

Since there are no output instructions, the only important part of the code is `f(`: `f` pushes `15` and `(` swallows that many characters from the end of the snake. The code is now considered to end after `.O`. Execution continues until the end of the snake and loops back to the beginning. Each time through, the snake gets shorter, until eventually the `(` is swallowed. Since the IP just got eaten, the snake halts execution.

**Snake 2**

`"saLaD"` pushes its character codes last-to-first; `1/` divides the charcode of `r` by `1`, leaving it unchanged, and `ooooo` outputs five characters. `;` drops an item (no-op because the stack is already empty). `1(` swallows the instruction pointer and halts.

**Snake 3**

`"YVaRg"` pushes some charcodes; then `(` swallows a number of characters equal to the top of the stack, which happens to be `89`, the character code of `Y`. Eating 89 characters is enough to swallow the IP and halt execution.

#### ///

[Try it online](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=aTpnSm5mOnthOnhXI2kmJy9ORSBZUE9pYS46eVEnXD9QT2l5YX1XI2lJJ1xRIFlQT2lPUE9pRUl5UScve3A6VmZZMHM6VmZJeVEnL1dwTmkmWXZpUjpYcHsrK3k_cHN9fUUgT3k&input=LycvL3R1cmtleS9gQCwsLCwiY29ybiIKLyJ5dmFyZyJsPyE7bzcxLmAic2FsYWQi&args=LXI) using [my Pip implementation of ///](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95651/16766)

`/'//` deletes all single quotes from the rest of the program (which does nothing because there aren't any). Next, `bisCuItS` outputs as-is. Finally, the rest of the code is an incomplete substitution--there's only two of the three requisite slashes--so it does nothing.

Comment: I like the abuse of the "case doesn't matter" rule to make it work in oOo CODE :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Cubix, Pushy, Brainfuck, V, Python 2 - 5 languages, <s>89</s> 85 bytes

My second ever polyglot - not very golfed, but it works:

```
"`turkey`";print'salad'#;"nroc"w!@o;"-[--";;;;{{->+<]>---.---.---..+++++++.␛ddgigravy
```

<sub>(note that `␛` represents the literal escape byte, `x1B`)</sub>

- Cubix prints `corn`
- Pushy prints `turkey`
- Brainfuck prints `ROLLS`
- V prints `gravy`
- Python prints `salad`

---

### Cubix

[**Test the program online!**](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ImB0dXJrZXlgIjtwcmludCdzYWxhZCcjOyJucm9jInchQG87Ii1bLS0iOzs7O3t7LT4rPF0+LS0tLi0tLS4tLS0uLisrKysrKysuG2RkZ2lncmF2eQ==&input=&speed=20)

Cubix is a language by the challenge author, ETHproductions. The Cubix Interpreter reads the code like this:

```
        " ` t u
        r k e y
        ` " ; p
        r i n t
' s a l a d ' # ; " n r o c " w
! @ o ; " - [ - - " ; ; ; ; { {
- > + < ] > - - - . - - - . - -
- . . + + + + + + + . d d g i ␛
        g r a v
        y . . .
        . . . .
        . . . .
```

The code is executed like so:

- `'salad` - does some irrelevant XOR operations on stack, results in `115, 0, 0`
- `'#;` - push the charcode of `#`, then pop it again (no-op)
- `"nroc"` - push the charcodes for "corn"
- `w` - moves the IP to loop on the next line below:

  - `!@o;` - print and pop last item (terminate if item is 0)
  - `"-[--";;;;` - push these chars and delete them (no-op)
  - `{{` - no-op

---

### Pushy

[**Test the program online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@6@UUFJalJ1amaBkXVCUmVeiXpyYk5iirmytlFeUn6xUruiQb62kG62rq2QNBNXVunbaNrF2urq6ejCspw0BetIpKemZ6UWJZZX//wMA)

Pushy is my own language, and it runs the code like this:

```
"          \ Print stack. Empty, so prints newline.
`turkey`   \ Push this string
"          \ Print this string
;          \ "End loop": Ignored as there is no loop in progress.
pr         \ Irrelevant stack operations
i          \ "interrupt": exit program.
```

---

### Brainfuck

[**Test the program online!**](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=ImB0dXJrZXlgIjtwcmludCdzYWxhZCcjOyJucm9jInchQG87Ii1bLS0iOzs7O3t7LT4rPF0-LS0tLi0tLS4tLS0uLisrKysrKysuG2RkZ2lncmF2eQ&input=)

Brainfuck ignores all characters that are not in its list of instructions, resulting in:

```
-[--->+<]>---.---.---..+++++++.
```

Which prints `ROLLS`. Note that this requires an interpreter with wrapping cells, such as the one provided.

---

### V (Vim language)

[**Test the program online!**](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=ImB0dXJrZXlgIjtwcmludCdzYWxhZCcjOyJucm9jInchQG87Ii1bLS0iOzs7O3t7LT4rPF0-LS0tLi0tLS4tLS0uLisrKysrKysuG2RkZ2lncmF2eQ&input=)

V was created by DJMcMayhem, one of our top code-golfers.

V is a program-based version of the text editor Vim. Most characters before the `ESC` get written into the "file", but `␛ddgigravy` deletes all of that and inserts "gravy" instead. The content of the file at the end of the program is printed.

---

### Python 2

[**Test the program online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@6@UUFJalJ1amaBkXVCUmVeiXpyYk5iirmytlFeUn6xUruiQb62kG62rq2QNBNXVunbaNrF2urq6ejCspw0BetIpKemZ6UWJZZX//wMA)

Python is one of my favorite practical languages. Because `#` is a comment in Python, most of the program is ignored. The code is read like this:

```py
"`turkey`";            # Unused string literal
print'salad'           # Print statement
#...                   # Comment (everything else is ignored)
```

---

Comment: Minor nitpick: `'salad'#` actually pushes the charcode of `s`, 0, 0, and the charcode of `#`, then `;` pops and leaves the stack at `115,0,0`.

Comment: @ETHproductions yeah, you're right, doesn't affect the program either way really but I'll fix up the description

Answer (score 2):

### Python/QBasic/[Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 3 languages, 41 bytes

More languages possibly TBA.

```
1#print"corn":end
print("turkey");"salad"
```

**Python**

`1` is just an expression that gets discarded. `#` starts a comment. `print("turkey")` does what it says, and `"salad"` is another expression that gets discarded.

**QBasic**

`1#` is a (double-precision) line number. `print"corn"` does what it says. `end` terminates the program. The second line is syntactically valid but never executed.

**Pip**

Most everything is expressions that get discarded. `"corn":e` tries to assign to a literal string, which fails silently (unless warnings are enabled). `"salad"` is the last expression in the program and therefore is printed.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, JavaScript and BrainF*ck, 178 Bytes

*First time I've ever tried a Polyglot - not going to lie, I'm in over my head here...*

Golfed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><?php echo "turkey";?></body><script>function A(){alert("stuffing");}//`--[----->+<]>-++.+++++++++++.-----------------.-----------.+++.`
</script></html>
```

*(I didn't dare to write a Thanksgiving food in the HTML code and count that as another language...)*

**Explanation:**

The code needs to be saved into a .php file for the PHP and JavaScript parts.

**PHP:**

When ran on a PHP server, the PHP part of the code is read:

```
<?php echo "turkey";?>
```

This outputs:

[image]

**JavaScript:**

You can call the JavaScript `A()` function from the browser console:

```
function A(){alert("stuffing");}
```

This outputs:

[image]

**Brainf*cK**

The Brainf*ck part is nicely hidden in the comments in the JavaScript section, so it is ignored by the PHP and JavaScript parts:

```
--[----->+<]>-++.+++++++++++.-----------------.-----------.+++.
```

When the whole file pasted into an [IDE](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/), this outputs:

[image]

I couldn't have done the Brainf*ck part without [this](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/text.html) text-to-BF website. I originally got it to generate code for "corn" and then in an attempt to learn something about this crazy language, I converted it to "gravy"...or rather "graVY"...

Answer (score 1):

## Python, Clojure, Javascript, Ruby: 4 languages, 113 bytes

```
1;''''/*
#_(
puts("turkey")
__END__
);'''
1;1//2;'''
1;*/alert("gravy")/*
(print "salad");'''
#_
print "corn";#*/
```

Thanks to @Sp3000 for most of the code. Surprisingly, I didn't even have to do anything to his original, I just had to prepend the Ruby code.

Answer (score 1):

### ///, SQL and JavaScript

```
/*//turkey/\*/select('corn')
--a;function select(){alert('salad')}
```

Same construction as with that other holiday-oriented polyglot:

**///**

```
/*//turkey/../..   Simply prints 'turkey', does no replaces, stops execution because the second /// block is incomplete
```

**SQL**

```
/*//turkey/\*/    //turkey/\ is seen as a block comment
                  That last \ was added to set apart the following */, completing the block
select('corn')    SQL Select statement, yielding 'corn'
--a;...           Seen by SQL as a comment, ignored
```

**Javascript**

```
/*//turkey/\*/    //turkey/\ is seen as a block comment
select('corn')    Function call to the function 'select', defined below
--a;              Decrement a, effectively a NOP
function select(){alert('salad')}
                  Defines the function select(), giving us 'salad'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure / Common Lisp / PicoLisp, 39 bytes

```
(print(if '()'turkey(if""'rolls'corn)))
```

Lisp family here. `'()` evaluates to true in Clojure so it proceeds to outputing a symbol `turkey`. PicoLisp and Common Lisp goes into false branch; `""` is true in Common Lisp and thus it prints symbol `rolls`, empty string is false in PicoLisp and so it goes to printing `corn` symbol.

Check it online:

https://ideone.com/OD65LB - Clojure

https://ideone.com/M1H5gf – Common Lisp

https://ideone.com/B4x3ns – PicoLisp

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, Underload, ><>, 39 bytes

```
'v;"(Turkey)S";"Gravy""
 >'nroC'oooo;";
```

#### What CJam sees

- `'v;`: A character literal that is immediately discarded
- `"(Turkey)S";`: A string literal that is immediately discarded
- `"Gravy"`: Pushes the string `Gravy` to the stack
- `"\n'nroC'oooo;";`: A string literal that is immediately discarded.

At the end of execution, the stack is output, which means that "Gravy" is printed.

#### What Underload sees

- `'v;"`: Some invalid commands that are ignored
- `(Turkey)S`: Pushes the string "Turkey" and outputs it
- `";"Gr`: Some invalid commands that are ignored
- `a`: This causes a segfault on the TIO interpreter since the stack is empty. Execution is terminated.

#### What ><> sees

- `'v;"(Turkey)S";"Gravy""` pushes a bunch of characters to the stack (which are ignored). The IP then wraps back around.
- `v` sends the IP downwards.
- `>'nroC'oooo` pushes the characters in the string "Corn" and outputs them.
- `;` terminates execution. All other characters are ignored.